# Why only top users on the 10 million page?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

First of all, congratulations to all of us for making the 10 million mark. To explain what I am talking about here's the picture:

[image]

I can see [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) and other top users. Wouldn't it make more sense to have random pictures pop up?

After all, it's all of us who got it to the 10 million mark.

Comment: Not all contributions are equal. Most users have never asked a question.

Comment: A *vast majority* of the contributions to the site do come from the top users, either now or from times past. It's tough to represent the ~250K users in total that have >= 200 rep, though.

Comment: Why is it so important to have your face in there?  Take pride in doing it just because, not because you need some sort of accolade.

Comment: Apparently the image is dynamic, because my avatar is in a different position then when I just looked for it. Although strangely the number displayed is not, I had the same number!

Comment: Hah! I didn't even notice this. Nice.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question. "You designed something to convey [thing], are you sure it's doing what you thought it would?" Don't put vanity into things where the OP didn't. There aren't very many ways to say "But isn't this about all of us?", which is pretty much the root of the observation (I had it as well).

Comment: @TimPost Couldn't agree more.

Comment: I didn’t notice the avatars at all… I thought it was some kind of background noise to make the thing prettier…

Comment: The only thing that confused me was to find myself twice in there. Then I realized it's `background-repeat: repeat;` :-)

Comment: @meagar, but end of the day it's a contribution. every great achievement is a team work and not a one man army work. As said, you can't clap in one hand.

Comment: Oh, I had not even realized there were users hidden in the background of this image! Looking more closely, I see 400 squares, for 2x200 users (thanks to Slaks for his easy to spot mini-picture which helped me realize the repetition)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Every single user that has done *something* to make the site better than it was when they found it should be feeling *really* good right now. Maybe you've answered thousands upon thousands of questions, maybe you asked a question that drew thousands of other programmers here after it circulated on Twitter. Maybe you suggested an edit that resulted in someone *truly* learning something from an answer instead of struggling to understand it.

The page goes out of its way to thank *everyone* that cared enough to help get Stack Overflow to this point. Do those people that have spent the *most* significant amount of time deserve some *extra* thanks as we hit this point?

Yes. The image doesn't hope to diminish what *you* have done, it just goes out of its way to pay some extra thanks to them, and they have earned it, through hundreds upon hundreds upon hundreds of hours of going out of their way to help people.

If we rotated random avatars from folks that have actually contributed, I can't even guess at what percentage would actually be seen, but I'm certain it's quite small. It would be nice to do, but I hate putting something up where people stare at it waiting to see themselves and fall asleep at their desk 14 hours later. But I *most decidedly do not* want to give the impression that this is just about our top users. It's not, it's about everyone that has contributed.

#### That's why we're doing more here, on meta :)

Over the next two weeks, I will be opening some discussion posts with the [10m-questions-milestone](/questions/tagged/10m-questions-milestone) tag attached inviting *all* of you to reflect upon the interesting experiences you've had on the site. We'll probably also paint some pictures, elect a manager to be sabotaged [Cutthroat Kitchen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutthroat_Kitchen) style, re-write some *really* bad songs from the 80s and whatever else we cook up.

Each one of these 'mini' events will see something cool sent to everyone that participated in them in good faith, along with something *really* cool for the people that came up with the neatest ideas. There will *probably* be around six events, maybe more. *Everyone* is welcome to keep an eye on meta and have some fun as these take place.

tl;dr; Stack Overflow is just massive, we will do our *very* best to ensure that anyone passionate about the site has a chance to celebrate together, *all of us* that made this happen.

Comment: I'm hitting 100k on this day itself in short period of time. Is there any gift (t-shirt) for me?

Comment: Oh I'm completely up for some Cutthroat Kitchen sabotages. Maybe Jeremy Banks ♦ will be forced to moderate with only the tools he can make from a sheet of aluminum foil?

Comment: @Trobbins I will open it up to moderators too, not fully fleshed out yet - but the mod or manager will have to accept the challenge first, and agree to provide evidence that it was fulfilled.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yep. Email me (my email is in my profile) so I can be sure you get something :)

Comment: Thanks Tim. Really looking forward to the 'mini' events.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks Tim, emailed you. I'm waiting for the t-shirt.

Comment: I'm just starting to get involved in the community. I was only posting questions in here! Congratulations for hitting 100k. I'm still aiming for 100. ;-)

Comment: @Mymozaaa Keep an eye on meta, there will be plenty of things for you to do while you share in this :)

Comment: Was hoping for someone to edit this clips so it went ['stackoverflooooooooow!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfoR8SbFhy8)

Comment: @TimPost shouldn't all the "discussion posts" be featured on meta? The [first one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey) isn't.

Comment: @Nateowami Tim actually already posted a comment in that question about _why_ it's not featured. You can find said comment [here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey#comment236922_303045)

Comment: @Kendra Ah, thanks, sorry I missed that.