# How Did Stack Overflow Help You?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

As we continue the [celebration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302938/why-only-top-users-on-the-10-million-page/302944#302944) of [10 million questions](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) on Stack Overflow, **we want to give away more stuff!**

We’ve already received some [awesome stories](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey) about users going above and beyond for others, but before we give away more swag we need something from you.

We want some stories about how Stack Overflow has helped you or how it made you a better programmer. It could be that your participation:

- changed your career
- helped you succeed in school
- or some other way it helped you

As an example, I’ll use my own experience:

> I was working on a project that needed to convert an Microsoft Access application written from VBA to a Winforms C# application with a SQL Server backend. I had never touched either of those programming languages before, so I turned to Stack Overflow.
>
> I was able to solve most of my problems using either existing questions and answers, or from the help of the users. Through my use of the site, I learned that I loved SQL and loved answering those questions, but realized quickly I had a lot to learn. I used the site to strengthen my SQL skills which eventually lead to several database developer jobs and ultimately changed my career path. Without Stack Overflow, I wouldn’t have had the same exposure to SQL. The site helped advanced my career and everyday I’m grateful for finding it.

I’ll stop gushing and get to the good stuff.

### What swag can we get?

- A Stack Overflow branded ruled notebook, with a pocket in the back and quality, acid-free paper (actual brand will depend on availability)
- A Stack Overflow T-shirt (Men's or Women's cut) along with some stickers
- Pens & retractable sharpies
- A mug or BPA-free water bottle (Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange) depending on availability

### Rules:

- Answers must be at least two paragraphs. You need to tell the story, with as much detail as you can with an emphasis on how the site helped you.
- Submission deadline is September 11, 2015
- Allow 6 - 8 weeks for delivery after the submission deadline

Comment: Can we answer both questions? (i.e. the awesome experience one and this)

Comment: @BhargavRao This is different from the previous question posted by Tim. This is more about how Stack Overflow helped you, not necessarily how another user helped you.

Comment: Yep. I understood. But do we get swag for answering both the questions?

Comment: @BhargavRao As long as you make an effort to answer the question in the way we are asking and you're not solely trying to get free stuff... then yes.

Comment: @BhargavRao, Shh you're asking too many questions. ;)

Comment: @Trobbins I had 10,000,000 more questions. If I ask them all then we can have a 10m-milestone for meta also! :D

Comment: Don't ask me, ask You!

Comment: SO gives my life meaning so I already posted an answer earlier today, I'm just curious how this actually works. You said *What swag **can** we get?* does this mean that only some people will get the 'swag'? How does it work exactly?

Comment: @TimCastelijns By sharing a good faith story about how SO helped you, you will receive some swag.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks for the answer. Normally I don't care much for swag, but I can make an exception for this

Comment: Are stories from other SE sites welcome?

Comment: @Anko This is a celebration of Stack Overflow, so the story should be about how Stack Overflow helped you.

Comment: Ugh, can I just post a link to [this?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267818/stack-overflow-helped-me-with-my-problem-on-which-network-can-i-share-my-succes/267821#267821), though it's about how we help others, not how SO helped me.

Comment: @gunr2171 Of course it's about helping others, but being active on the site also has benefits to careers, etc. I personally learned a lot by answering questions on the site which in turn resulted in job offers. I wouldn't have received those without the site, so yes it helped me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could write a book, or at least several essays, about how Stack Overflow has helped me.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar We are only asking for at least 2 paragraphs. :)

Comment: @bluefeet If I had more time, I'd have written a shorter `<del>letter</del>` answer.

Comment: After this celebration can we just get a store to buy SO shirts, etc. please?

Comment: I don't know how to write this in two paragraphs, so I'm posting this as a comment. Whenever I got stuck technically, I just google it and almost every search result  are of stackoverflow, but in case (Keeping in mind that I sometimes really have some abnormal questions) the top results are not from stackoverflow. I explicitly add Stackoverflow at the end of my search query.

Comment: @TylerH I read that permanently offering merchandise would be too much of an administrative hassle, so they won't do that

Comment: How are the winners picked?

Comment: @DavidG If a good faith answer that follows the rules (2+ paragraphs) with a story about how SO helped you, then yay you'll get swag.

Comment: @bluefeet Wowzer! That's super generous of you guys. Lets hope you don't get 100k answers and bankrupt yourself!

Comment: This is going to be the best Christmas ever! :)

Comment: I would like to hear the same story from staffs or moderators of sof as well :) Why did you participated in sow and how have you experienced or learnt from the career.

Comment: The deadline is today. Is the cutoff 11:59 PM UTC? Was the cutoff at midnight on September 11?

Comment: @McAdam331 When it hits September 12 you will no longer be entered.

Comment: The email went out today (September 18, 2015) regarding the swag. If you posted an answer but didn't receive an email (we got at least one undeliverable), post a comment or shoot me an email and we'll investigate.

Comment: @bluefeet I have received the mails for both "Lets share..." and this post... Both links taking me to same form... is it ok? I will be filling the same form again...

Comment: @GNKeshava Yes that should be fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is no longer accepting answers.

Comment: @enderland People could still post answers they just might not get swag.

Comment: @bluefeet: My swag hasn't arrived. Got the email, and filled the form, said 6-8weeks delivery. Is it all gone? :-(

Comment: @scheien We had a few issues [check out this MSE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/what-happened-to-that-contest-swag-i-was-promised) for updates.

Answer (score 68):

As a Stack Overflow user, I have learned a lot. Let me start with my story:

> When I joined my first company as an `Android Trainee`, I was trained under their training program which went for ***just*** 10-12 days only. Thereafter, I was assigned to a project. As I had never been into programming in my college days, it was difficult for me to grasp concepts and deliver codes for the project. Moreover, you need to learn how a project must be managed, along with CI/CD.
>
> Whenever I used to get stuck, I used to google for finding relevant contents and guess what? Most of the times it forwarded me to our own ***Stack Overflow***.
>
> My project manager used to tell me, "*Don't worry if you're not able to find something relevant; try Stack Overflow. It'll give you a perfect suggestion*". Then I thought of joining this forum; and then the journey began...

Stack Overflow helped me in various ways. Android development, self development and knowing people from around the world (Thanks to [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com)). I am an active  user of chat SO where I keep sharing and helping other users.

It's really nice to see people from all over the world come and share their knowledge on a single platform. We have our room's [Facebook page](https://awww.facebook.com/javaandandroidera) as well where we keep posting about Android and Java updates. We have more than 300 followers of this page now. That's all because of Stack Overflow.

At last, I would like to say

> This site has given us a lot! Let's get together to make it better. :)

Comment: +1 .. and I am totally agree with your words @TheLittleNaruto. When I started my career as a Developer, Stack is best way to get quick solution of problem .. and best thing is people share code with instead of suggestion :p ..

Comment: @Simmant I want to make your comment perfect "People share knowledge instead of information".

Comment: I started as a student asking questions on my final project in 2011, when the community could afford to be more patient with discussions, overly specific requests etc. I worry a student in 2015 will be driven away with the stricter policies that evolved since then, and hence I am an avid reader of "we are scaring users away" posts on meta.

Comment: @KetanAhir correct (y) :)

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I am fully agree with you.! I can simply say "Thanks SO"

Comment: Great answer, TLN!

Comment: Thank you! :) @McAdam331

Comment: Yeah Agreed @TheLittleNaruto :)

Answer (score 38):

*TL;DR: Stack Overflow was a key resource on my quest to transition from a student networker to a professional programmer.*

I've mentioned before that I started my journey as a networker, not a programmer. Through college, my focus was purely on networking, though I did intend to go back after a short break from school for programming. Instead, I interviewed with a company that was looking for programmers (They had told the school they wanted networkers too. Oh well.) and through soley my drive and commitment to learn, and the one C# class I had opted to take as an extra course, I got hired on in a foreign field to me.

The team I got hired on to has been great- They're smart programmers, and they're good guys. However, they aren't the "teaching" type- Rather, they believe in a trial-by-fire method of learning. I was dumped into this strange new world with an internet connection as my weapon and a search engine as my main guide.

Whenever I hit a snag, my supervisor would give me hints in the right direction but made it clear he thought I would learn more by researching the issues myself, rather than by having him tell me how to fix it. He was right.

As I got familiar with Java, the language all our apps were using at that time, one of the more experienced guys on the team started on a new <s>project</s> quest, and <s>pulled me on board</s> chose me for his party. This new <s>project</s> quest was a VB.Net website, and I was to help with the front-end of the site.

As I started to teach myself jQuery and HTML, I hit fewer snags, though the ones I hit were slightly harder for me to find. (My Google-Fu was under leveled at that point.) As I continued to try to research, one <s>website</s> mystical land of sages consistently appeared in my Google results: Stack Overflow. Time and again, this amazing land would appear before me and present me with guidance in the right direction.

One day, however, I failed in my quest to understand why my code did not behave as I expected. I had entered the realm of Regular Expressions, and it was like a maze to a newcomer such as myself. Why could I not get my string to match my regex? It all certainly looked right!

Ah, but I had misunderstood the map given me by the wise Google. I could not compare my string the way I had thought, but instead had to test the string against the regex. As I corrected my code, I realized how I should have searched for my answer, and tested that theory. Sure enough, my new search phrase turned up results other than my Stack Overflow question. I kept in mind how I had phrased the search so I could <s>improve</s> level up my Google-Fu and more easily find answers to my future problems.

As time has gone on, I have learned, mostly by browsing, tricks and tips to apply to my coding. I have learned of <s>things</s> magics I did not know even existed, and how to apply those properly to projects I could use them in. I have slayed countless bugs thanks to the weapons given to me by the great sages of Stack Overflow. Thanks to these ever-present weapons, I have become a true professional programmer and not just the coding wanderer I had started as.

Stack Overflow has helped me <s>progress</s> level my skills farther and faster than I ever thought possible. Without Stack Overflow, I might have taken far more time to find several solutions to several problems. In fact, with some guidance and tricks from the [Regex Reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) and the [Learning Regex question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) I have become the regex expert on my team. I owe Stack Overflow and the sages therein a good deal for the level I'm at now, and don't know what I'd do without this amazing resource to aid me on future quests.

Comment: I admit, when I started writing this, I didn't intend to make so many "adventuring hero" type comments... I think I've been playing too many RPG games again.

Comment: Speaking of programming and RPGs, have you played CodeCombat? It's a programming RPG, and I love it and think it's a very well executed concept. :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I'm looking that up on my lunch break and will likely try it out tonight, then. Thanks for that suggestion. =)

Comment: www.regexr.com is my best friend for regular expressions.

Comment: @Luminous Wish I'd have known about that one when I was still learning them. =) I'm to the point now that minus a typo here or there, I can usually write a regex for what I need without a site like that. Looks like a super helpful site, though, so I'll be passing that one around the office and bookmarking it myself. (Never hurts to have a sanity check!)

Comment: As I'm one of the top three regex answerers, my very best friend is regex101.com which helps me to earn 100k within 1.6 years. Because this is  one of the famous regex testing site which has three separate regex engines for php, javascript, python languages.

Answer (score 34):

During my interview, the interviewer asked me ["why ~True in Python prints -2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881362/why-does-true-result-in-2/21881463#21881463)? Well.. It's my most voted answer.

[image: Really..]

First I wanted to answer it without telling him that I actually know this question, but then I decided to show him my answer in Stack Overflow. He was really impressed, and then we went through some of my posts and I talked about how I use Stack Overflow to improve my programming skills.

Everyday I learn something new through reading more posts here. Sometimes I find myself investigating questions that I came across just because I was curious about, I challenge myself to find a solution for that problem. By doing this, I do research, I try new things, I dive into other fields and not only that I'm helping the original poster, but I'm *learning new things*.

SO has become part of my daily routine, and I decided to publish a [post on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140812110219-142144287-why-stack-overflow-is-part-of-my-daily-routine?trk=prof-post) about this.

<sup>I'm now the official Stack Overflow consultant in the company :)</sup>

Comment: It happened to me too! I was asked one of my answers. (He had actually upvoted it). :)

Comment: This is a very interesting and inspiring post, thank you :D

Answer (score 30):

Back in 2011 I was implementing a C# server application, I worked with WCF and other cool and fancy techniques. I got stuck at some point and started googling. I found often a strange site where you had to pay for answers which where partial visible in the Google results. That was so disturbing for me, and there was that site called Stack Overflow. I found very concentrated answers there to many different topics. From that point on I preferred all search results on this site.

Then I added a Android app to my project, and I was wondering why my app had constantly 4 KB memory usage on the device even when I did not store anything. I googled a lot and did not find a answer, so I registered and asked my first question: *[How does Android calculate cache and data size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7771635/995926)*. There I finally got an answer which could not been answered by all people I knew at that point.

From that date on I was almost daily on Stack Overflow. I guess I was less than three weeks offline from that date. Since that date I wrote 890 answers and asked 119 more questions.

[image]

The coolest feature of Stack Overflow is in my opinion the chat. You meet so many different people there from around the world. In comparison to other chats there are almost no dead rooms and you can read the full history of the chat at all times, so you can easily join a conversation. I am daily in the chat on working days where I help countless people. In the chat I hang around new technologies are often discussed, so you are up to date regarding the newest APIs and features.

I got all my jobs since my registration via Stack Overflow Careers. I love the idea to show what you have done based on tags. That makes it easier for getting a fast overview over my skills. Just thank you Stack Overflow for all!

Recently I wrote a small letter to you. I hope that I'll get some stickers from you guys soon :-)

Stack Overflow just rocks!

Comment: Nice one @rekire

Answer (score 25):

Stack Overflow…

1. Gave me an outlet to share my programming knowledge with other users (I'm currently at 128k and counting).
2. Got me both my last job and this job. :-)
3. Helped me learn a lot of the skills needed for this job.

To expand on each of these items:

I was one of the first users on Stack Overflow (#13). I was between jobs at the time, and needed to hone my programming skills. I was spending a lot of time practising Scheme coding, like writing [a pure-Scheme MD5 implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093199/a-pure-scheme-implementation-r5rs-of-sha256#comment37160861_24093199). So when Stack Overflow was announced, I was only too ready to sign up and answer programming questions!

As a very early user, I got to know other early users. One of the top users back in those days was [Mike Virata-Stone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122) (back then known as Mike Stone). He came to the #stackoverflow IRC channel asking for a second opinion of a candidate he interviewed that day, and I happened to mention that I was looking for a job. Shortly after, [I got a job at On-Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36868/13) (where he still works today), where I worked for 6½ years.

When I first joined On-Site, the code base was pretty much totally in Java. Since [Java was one of my areas of expertise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/java?userid=13), I was able to do my job without needing outside help. So most of my time on Stack Overflow was for answering questions, not searching for or asking questions. Later on, Ruby was added on as a primary technology (the code base is, these days, about 50/50 Java and Ruby), and I learnt Ruby on the job.

Anyway, I love helping people with programming problems, so I continued building rep on Stack Overflow. [This eventually got the attention of Stack Exchange](http://dyscour.se/post/126015669320/how-did-you-get-a-job-at-stack-exchange), and I started working here earlier this year. The Stack Exchange codebase is primarily in C#, so I am learning that (and PowerShell) on the job. I love learning new things, and so, now, I get to use Stack Overflow in a new way: searching for answers! (I still haven't had the occasion to ask a work-related question yet. Maybe one day I will.)

Comment: I wish "they gave me my dream job" could be my answer. :)

Comment: @Trobbins Wait till you get to 25k rep; you may be able to say that then. :-) (Actually, I was at 60k rep when SE first wrote me, but we do have people in our team with much less rep, so, no pressure. ;-))

Comment: thanks for the encouragement ;) I suppose I'll have to continue working with a corporate agile-waterfall mishmash until then!

Comment: The fact that you have 127k rep and somehow have no gold badges confuses me.

Comment: @DaveZych You're looking at the meta, which has separate badges from the main site. [On the main site](http://stackoverflow.com/users/13), I have 26 gold badges.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young for some reason I don't think I never noticed meta showed different badges. That's a confusing mix of normal rep and meta badges.

Answer (score 19):

In Late 2012, I had been out of the programming workforce for four years. Yes, I have a degree from a good school, but if you don't program more than a few hundred lines of code from Nov 2008 to Oct 2012, you get rusty. Not only do you get rusty on what you did know, but you also get rusty on what's come out since you stopped programming. I managed to talk a small company into taking a chance on me, mostly because I am smart and I did go to a good school, but honestly I was probably quite out of my depth when I started my current job.

Stack Overflow saved me. This site is such a good repository of knowledge, I learned about so many different techniques and technologies. It really helped me get up to speed on things I now use every day and feel comfortable writing answers here that, in my opinion, explain things better than the documentation often does. I'd like to go over a few posts that really helped me:

- [How to write generic method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13302767/1768232)

  - This is my first favorited question. I understood the basics of generics, how to specify them in a class, but I had no idea about how to specify type parameters in a method signature itself, e.g. `public <T> T doSomething(T input);`
- [Managing constructors with many parameters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/222214/1768232)

  - As I began to write ugly code, I found that my constructors were getting extremely unwieldy. This is the question that first taught me about Google Guice and got me on the path to understanding Dependency Injection. Two years later, I'm now on the top users list for the [guice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guice) tag.
- [Micro-benchmarking for regular expression using Caliper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12209914/1768232)

  - This question taught me about [Google Caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper/wiki) and micro-benchmarking, a tool that I would use to optimize many parts of my code later on. It eventually helped me (along with a profiler) to micro-optimize code that I probably never would have realized was slowing my system down.
- [Making a mistake with | (or) in regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13090230/1768232)

  - The difference between `grep`, `egrep` and `fgrep`.

Other things I learned on Stack Overflow that I don't have a proper "favorite" question to point to, but I know I learned here:

- How to write [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) code properly, in a thread-safe way. Prior to Stack Overflow, I always had problems with screens being unresponsive and/or not updating.
- What MVC and MVP really are, and how to keep concerns separated in UI programming.
- How to use an asynchronous I/O library to do server client communication without using raw Java sockets.
- How to encapsulate API calls to third-party libraries.
- How to use mocks when testing code, and [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) in general
- How to write multi-threaded code properly, using queues, immutable objects, and avoiding poll waiting.

This isn't Stack Overflow, but I also learned a ton of stuff from some questions on *[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)*, my other most frequented Stack Exchange site, that I'd like to mention here too; especially their chatroom [The Whiteboard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard). These also helped my career greatly as a programmer:

- [This is where I learned about commit early, commit often](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/230624/88986)

  - Prior to this question, I was scared a bit of really taking advantage of version control. After this question, I really began to use it better.
- [I really began to understand the Law of Demeter after this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/232442/88986), and how to keep my code less coupled.
- [How use wrapper classes and write DTOs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/271548/88986)

Stack Overflow made it possible for me to retrain myself and get current in many new technologies. I went from being an out of practice, untrained novice to being, in my opinion, a senior level programmer. My small company has hired a recent college graduate to work directly for me two months ago. I got my gold Java badge a few weeks ago, and I should hit 20,000 reputation points any day now.

Thanks Stack Overflow! I couldn't have done it without you.

Comment: +1 for the Programmers references in addition to the SO references.

Answer (score 17):

I am happy to share my story about Stack Overflow from my iOS beginning career to the current level.

Stack Overflow really helped me in my iOS development career for the past 3.5 years. I regularly visit Stack Overflow and spend hours reading questions and their answers to sort out my problems. I also look for those questions for which I can give the best possible solution. But the main thing is that I learned those answers from different sources on Stack Overflow questions.

In another way Stack Overflow also helps me how to find a query on Google, how to ask queries to other developers on this platform with the help of relevant tags, images and well-formatted text. Using Stack Overflow I also learned the iOS development coding style, format and structure which boost my iOS application in speed and quality.

My usage history on Stack Overflow (previous questions and answers) also helps me to compare myself with present and past activities on this platform. This way I can measure my improvements and identify my mistakes, so I can improve myself much better.

In some interviews companies also ask candidates whether they have a Stack Overflow account or not and if yes how they use them. So Stack Overflow is also useful for getting job opportunities.

So I would like to say thank you to Stack Overflow for providing me wonderful knowledge and opportunity to become a successful iOS developer. Now I can proudly say that I am a user of Stack Overflow with 29K reputation.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I started on Stack Overflow very young. In fact, odds are I was probably a few months shy of being able to legally say yes to the T&C. Then again, I didn't read it, so I didn't know.

Stack Overflow has helped me solve many, many, many of my problems, without actually have to reach out to other people each and every time. As I start out with any new technology, I always have an ever ready plethora of questions and answers ready, waiting for me to hit my first (hundred) errors.

More than that, Stack Overflow has helped me grow as a person. The [Android chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) serves as a reasonably decent chronicle of my life, and I've made some really close friends from the years of hanging out in there. In fact, in the coming days, I will be meeting many of them in person for the first time, after knowing them through Room 15 for months, if not years.

I have learnt to deal with all kinds of people, while answering and performing mod(ish) tasks on the Android tag, which is a bit like a busy fish market where the fish keep dying, the fishermen don't know why, and the ocean just keeps churning out the next version of fish.

Running for the moderator elections repeatedly has given me a great insight into pitching for community leadership, dealing with questions well, and a whole range of other personal development skills.

Stack Overflow is a site without which teaching myself to code in various languages, use various frameworks, and engage in projects, all starting nine years ago, would have been nearly impossible. Nothing else on the Internet rivals the information we have here, and I'm happier than ever to have contributed to one tag significantly among the thousands we have here.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of having to wade through totally useless confusing MSDN articles (wonder why they can't have somebody write them who has English as a first language) if I have a problem, I formulate it into a question, Google it, and virtually every time Stack Overflow is the top of the list of results. I click, scroll down to the first green tick, bingo! Solved.

If that first answer *isn't* the solution then that nearly always means I have the wrong question.

Over the past 8 years or however long it's been going, I scientifically estimate Stack Overflow has saved me a ton of time and freed me up to do more interesting things.

Comment: Revising the question is so true, and one of the great lessons I've learned as well

Answer (score 12):

First, an amusing anecdote: in my last 1/1 with my boss, he asked me rather out of the blue, "Have you heard about Stack Overflow? It's a good resource for IT-related questions." "Yes, yes I have." :D

> helped you succeed in school

My first questions here were from graduate school. Dealing with linker errors on Linux as a <s>student</s> complete idiot was painful. Now, I'm just less of an idiot. But it was helpful to find an online community where I could learn (and read crazy amounts of useful information, ignoring my first posts here).

> changed your career

It absolutely has. Even though [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) is a, ah, less than desirable tag for most folks, it's been a huge use in my career. There is "I recorded a macro in VBA!" and there is "I use VBA and do (mostly) object-oriented programming!" VBA. Stack Overflow has contributed to not only my questions, but allowed me to research other people's needs/questions.

It's far easier to learn by teaching than "just" doing. Both have their place, but when you are forced to explain to someone you *must* understand it better than you do just to copy/paste a solution.

This part of Stack Overflow has exploded my ability to work with coworkers. The skills required to be good at Stack Exchange translate very well into a career. Indirectly, Stack Overflow also got me <s>hooked</s> into other sites here too.

Plus, Stack Exchange has a great community. It's a great opportunity to bounce ideas off other talented people.

Answer (score 12):

### Learning through Teaching

As several people have already mentioned, the most important and rewarding thing that I've gotten from Stack Overflow is the chance to learn by answering other people's questions. I've learned a lot by asking questions, but I've always found that I don't fully understand something until I've explained it to someone else.

I'm a geologist by background. I don't have any formal training in computer science. The bulk of what I know about programming and software development I owe to Stack Overflow.

I've putzed around with writing simple odds and ends since the first time I came across a school computer in 8th grade.  I was even paid to do web development back in the early 00's. (Tip: don't let a 20-year old who's never owned a computer write his own PHP-based CMS for your website.  Who needs https?? I'll just write a bit of js to obfuscate the login form and give the admin page a funny name... I have no idea how that stuff was never hacked and defaced...) In grad school, I wrote abominations of stitched-together csh, awk, Fortran, and Matlab.  Later on in grad school, I managed to make even Python completely unreadable.

However, I'd never learned much beyond the immediate bit I needed to get the job done.  Stack Overflow was started about the time I was beginning to want to learn to do more than make "copy-pasta".

It took a couple of years, but I eventually began participating instead of just lurking and reading other people's questions and answers. Once I started answering questions, the rate at which I was learning skyrocketed.  There were many questions I knew the immediate answer to, but didn't know exactly why.  I made a point of digging in until I could give a complete answer, and learned a ton every time.

Because I was more confident in what I was doing, I started to build larger and more complex side-projects.  In the process, I learned how to be an at least occasionally-competent software engineer. Starting a few months ago, I've managed to wind up in a software development role at work. I would never have had the background or confidence to do that without Stack Overflow.

### Learning More than Programming

I've learned to be a far better developer over the past five years on Stack Overflow.  However, it's not just about learning programming, or even proper software engineering.  The best and most valuable things I've learned from SO are more general methods that can be applied to many problems.

One particular category stands out: I apply machine learning methods regularly now, but I was very intimidated and confused by them initially. That changed when I had some time one Christmas break to really dig in in answering a [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4502656/325565).  It's the question I've learned the most answering by far, and it started me down a path that's been very useful as well as fun.

### A specific example: Eigenpaws

[image: Largest 9 Eigenpaws]

Over a few months in the fall of 2010, [Ivo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77595/ivo-flipse) asked [a series of fantastic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77595/ivo-flipse?tab=questions&sort=newest) (bottom 10-15 questions in the list) relating to analyzing "puppy paws" on a pressure plate.  His initial question about [peak detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3684484/325565) spiraled into a wonderful series of semi-related questions as he built his application.

Because Ivo's questions were clearly-stated and exceptionally fun (puppies, anyone?), they received a lot of attention and very good answers.  I answered a few of them.  [One of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4092160/325565) wound up being very popular, mostly because it had [animations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CRA6.gif).  However, the focus of this story is on one of Ivo's later questions.  He asked about ways to [identify individual pawprints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4502656/325565) (e.g. left front, right hind, etc).

I felt very invested in answering [this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4502656/325565).  It was partly because it was a follow-up to a question where my answer had been very popular.  Mostly, though, it was just a fun problem!  Furthermore, Ivo happened to ask it right as I was leaving on a trip to visit my wife's (girlfriend at the time) family.  I had a long train ride and several days of "down-time" to dig into the problem in more detail at night.

### Why Isn't This Working?

In a nutshell, I had figured out how to correctly classify paws based on the temporal and spatial order they contacted the sensor in.  However, this method only worked for a subset of them (dogs that were walking). I needed another method to classify the rest of the dataset.

I knew enough about classification problems to know I could use this subset as training data in a supervised classification problem.  I thought it would be identical to the land-use coverage classification methods I was used to, where a simple distance is a good metric.  Get a mean vector for each of the four types of paws and then classify things based on their distance to the nearest of the four mean vectors.  The fact that the "vectors" are 20x20 images should be irrelevant. They're just 400-dimensional vectors, right?

I was completely flummoxed when it failed miserably.

I couldn't understand why distance wouldn't be a good comparison of similarity.  In the past, I'd compared plenty of images by subtracting them and summing the differences.  It worked pretty well.  Why was this so different??

A bit of googling about image classification led me to the concept of "eigenfaces".  A bit more reading led me to the "curse of dimensionality".  I started to understand that I'd need to reduce the dimensionality of the problem to something more manageable.

I tried to implement things using `scikit-learn` and a few other frameworks, but I couldn't understand the terminology at all.  Regardless, I wanted to understand what I was doing.  The math behind eigenfaces looked pretty familiar and easier to understand (at the time) than a machine learning framework.

I decided to implement my own "eigenpaw" algorithm.  I was amazed when it actually [worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4543848/325565)!

### Long-term Result

What I learned when answering that question gave me the background and motivation to begin picking up machine learning methods.  Not too long after, I became less intimidated by some of the frameworks like `scikit-learn` and began to use them regularly.  Overall, it's been an incredibly useful addition to my "toolkit".  I don't think I would have picked up those methods without doing the research to answer that question.  Thank you Ivo, and thank you SO!

Comment: _"There were many questions I knew the immediate answer to, but didn't know exactly why. I made a point of digging in until I could give a complete answer, and learned a ton every time."_ I feel like that _all_ the time! :-)

Answer (score 11):

I started my career in a job where I'd have roughly 11 hours of meetings jammed into an 8 hour day. This type of environment made getting work done difficult. Of course there were deadlines that were impossible (unless, of course, someone with a bigger stick comes along and rearranges your priorities each morning). When I started my career, there was no Stack Overflow. If I had questions, I had the random web forum, listservs, or if I was lucky, the older person in the next cube who was hanging on until retirement (thank you experienced coworker!).

Looking at my [reputation chart](https://stackexchange.com/users/63984/andy?tab=reputation), it seems I joined in late 2009 and then took over 18 months to get 100 rep. I think that's a great testament to how helpful Stack Overflow is. I didn't have to ask every question I had, because someone else had done so and received an answer that was useful. I escaped my job of meetings to another position - to a technology I'd never used. I spent countless hours browsing Stack Overflow (and official documentation and tutorials) learning this new technology. Without Stack Overflow, I would not have had the practical [examples](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303868/189134) (a very conveniently timed answer, if I do say so myself) that I needed.

Over the years, I've gone from lurking to answering questions. I've found that providing answers was rewarding, because it gives me a short break from "real work" and allows me to learn new things. There has been countless occasions where I've read a question and thought "That should be possible...but I have no idea how to do that" and then spend a bit figuring out a solution. I learn something, someone else learns something and if I'm lucky I get to use that new knowledge later.

Stack Overflow has helped my pick up new technologies, provided a way to expand my knowledge and given me a way to share some of my experience with others.

Answer (score 11):

**Everything I needed to know about programming I learned on Stack Overflow.**

Perhaps my story is becoming more common as SO ages, but I've picked up most of my programming knowledge on SO. I could say that I'm "self taught", but that wouldn't really be true. Most of the practices and techniques I use everyday I learned here.

I've subsequently started taking college courses in programming, gotta get that paper you know, but so far most of the material I've seen in class I've already been exposed to on SO.

Some of the things Stack Overflow has taught me:

- Devour the documentation
- The fundamentals of the languages I use
- [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) (the article not the snarky comment)
- [An appreciation for rubber ducks](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)
- Largely how to communicate online
- To [hate fun](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)
- To avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
- [Why tables shouldn't be used for layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html), and [why people still do it](https://web.archive.org/web/20130420073730/http://giveupandusetables.com/)
- [Stacking contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148007/which-css-properties-create-a-stacking-context)
- About [magical weaponized ponies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/217863)
- When [duty calls](https://xkcd.com/386/), you don't have to answer
- [To find my center](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D%20center)

  ...and the list goes on...

---

I started out making stuff on the web when my boss at the time delegated the company's website to me simply because I was of the appropriate generation. It was assumed that because I wasn't a senior citizen that I should know how to build websites...

I didn't have any experience building sites, I'd never even heard of CSS, but there I was rebuilding/updating a website on a hateful content management system.

I mention that the CMS was hateful because that was really what got me under the surface and into the code. I was plugging away just trying to update content when, as things usually happen, I had to center an image. And of course, being a hateful CMS, the button that was supposed to center things didn't work.

That sent me under the hood to try to figure out why it didn't work. Which in turn led to a google search, which led to the strange and wonderful world of Stack Overflow. As mentioned above [I found my center here.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D%20center) Perhaps more importantly I found new and [interesting problems to solve](https://xkcd.com/356/) and an obsession was born.

Thanks again Stack Overflow.

Comment: The failure of "helpful" technologies like CMSes is a frequent reason for people to poke under the hood and can really be a blessing in disguise. I also loved your bulleted list of lessons learned. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 11):

> **TL;DR:** Stack Overflow provides a feel-good atmosphere for procrastination for PhD students looking to learn and share their knowledge.

## An Unlikely Aid but A Good Source of Release

I am currently studying for my PhD and recently have left the honeymoon phase and am entering the hard slog. As such, my use of Stack Overflow has increased in the past few months. Stack Overflow has provided me with an unlikely source of procrastination that also helps me feel good. Procrastinating on Stack Overflow for me takes two different avenues. On the one hand I can read various questions and answers and learn new things and improve my knowledge, while on the other I can answer questions and pass on my knowledge to others.

### Non-Guilty Procrastination

The vast array of useful material on Stack Overflow has provided me with endless hours of reading and learning. As a PhD student I am well used to reading academic papers and advanced books. Stack Overflow is different; questions and answers are written by real people looking to help each other out. It is a much easier environment to read and learn in. This makes it an easy outlet for procrastination and most importantly a non-guilty outlet. As I am still learning and improving my knowledge by procrastinating on Stack Overflow, I don't feel guilty after having wasted an hour *or two :(*. However, that's not the most important aspect Stack Overflow has contributed to me.

### A Feel-good Outlet

The most important benefit to me in recent months is the feel-good outlet provided by the Stack Overflow reputation system and its kind and thankful community. As a PhD student I am used to teaching others and passing on my knowledge. Stack Overflow allows me to augment this and with its reputation system provides (near) instant gratification in the form of upvotes and accepts. This adds a feel good atmosphere to my procrastination and helps me to keep going with my studies.

As well as this, I've found the vast majority of my encounters on Stack Overflow with the community to be enlightening and very interesting. The community at large is really nice and I've particularly found this with the [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) and [Octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave) community after being invited to their chatroom.

All this will continue to encourage me to contribute and keep coming back to Stack Overflow. I'm glad I found it and I'm looking forward to using it even further and gaining more from it in the future.

Answer (score 11):

Stack Overflow has helped me in a countless number of ways, but I will limit this to the three I've considered most valuable:

**Stack Overflow helped me understand the value of learning through teaching.**
When I answer a question on Stack Overflow, I am doing so much more than helping someone else learn. I am also helping myself. This comes in many forms:

- I see a really good question, and I want to know the answer, so I do my own research and effort to get it, and come back and share it with the other person.
- I see a question I think I know the answer to, and I share it. Sometimes a commenter comes along and says "there's a better way" or "this isn't really right, you should do..." Assuming it's done in a constructive way, I really appreciate these comments because I know I'm not perfect, and instead of being shamed, many in the community reach out to help me improve.
- By convincing myself to pass on my knowledge to someone else, I am forced to stay up to date and involved in the topics I am passionate about.

**Stack Overflow helped me find new friends.**
I am an active member of the room-15 Android chat where I have met a countless number of incredible people. The people in that room have helped motivate me to do more in Android, leading up to the publishing of my first application, and more recently starting a blog on Android. They provide a comfortable environment for passionate Android developers to go and offer help, seek help, or just share pictures of cats. Through this I have built friendships that last outside the chatroom, and have even called with some members on [Hangouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Hangouts), or met up in person at a hackathon.

**Stack Overflow made me a better person.** Beyond making me a better programmer, my experience on Stack Overflow has instilled in me values that I see carry over into my everyday life. For example: I don't think less of someone just because they asked a trivial question. In fact, seeing someone take the effort to come here and learn is great. I have learned to appreciate someone's eagerness to learn, regardless of whether they're learning how to write a "Hello, World!" application, or if they're trying to configure some complicated network. I think this lesson can apply to skills beyond programming.

These are just a few things that come to mind, and are very important to me. I can go on and on about how Stack Overflow made me a better developer, or helped me write more complex MySQL queries, but I think we all know that. I have always viewed the primary goal of the site to be a place for people to learn programming skills. I never thought I would learn so much more than that.

Comment: Very nicely done!

Comment: Very nice McAd :)

Answer (score 10):

Stack has helped me in the obvious ways of finding good answers to dumb questions, but more importantly it helped me get a new job and it did this in 2 ways.

First, I was able to show my potential employers my SO profile and show them real, concrete examples of what I know. Along with that, it displays thousands of interactions with other programmers, my ability to explain things, and examples of writing and usage of the English language. My SO profile has been such an incredibly useful tool for things like this because there is so much information a potential employer can see outside of the 1 hour, high pressure interview.

More importantly, it has humbled me and helped me get out of the *I graduated college, therefore I know everything* mode of thinking to *I know very little. I can share the little I know with the world and help someone. I have a lot to learn and can always learn something from someone*. Seeing how people are so willing to help strangers on the internet is very humbling as well, and is so vastly different than the usual, trolling-and-youtube-comment style conversations that happen on the web. It's great to see the "people" side of the internet and know that out in the cloud there are some good hearted human beings.

These 2 realizations have further fueled the programming passion and have helped me in my career more than anything else.

Answer (score 9):

Though I have a Bachelor's degree in Information Technology, my current line of work doesn't require any programming skills. I work as a Business Analyst and my day job is to capture requirements from users and prepare the functional specifications. Specifying how each screen in the application should look like is one of the key part of the document. As each member in my team used their own preferred tool for specifying screen details, there was a distinct lack of consistency in terms of the output.

As part of a process improvement plan, I wanted to create a tool which would be used by all members of the team in order to produce a standardized output. Something like JSFiddle with built-in templates containing default styles used by my organization. Given that I had technical background, I thought it would be relatively easy for me. But only after starting the work did I realize that I had completely lost touch even with the basic things. At each step, I had multiple questions and whenever I searched, the best result was naturally from Stack Overflow.

Slowly but surely, I regained my touch and after a few months of part-time coding (a lot of searching and learning on SO), I completed the tool. It received very positive feedback from my colleagues and seniors. I am indebted to Stack Overflow and the various users who had asked/answered questions that I too had (because I never had the need to ask even a single question).

It is at this point that I realized a few things:

1. I should give back something to this great community which had helped me so much.
2. Debugging technical problems could help me better understand technical constraints and avoid writing requirements that are impossible/too troublesome to implement.
3. By writing answers that other fellow SO users (who are primarily programmers, developers) can understand would help improve my document writing skills also.

Over the last couple of years I have seen a vast improvement in the way I have written specifications. Developers have appreciated the level of clarity and also my assistance/inputs in solving quite a few of the technical problems for them/along with them.

While it is possible that I could have improved my skillsets even without answering questions here, **I must thank Stack Overflow** for providing me with a platform through which I could improve both my technical and non-technical skills.

Answer (score 9):

When I started programming, I came here. Every time I needed help, I came here. Endless hours and nights of google searches and SO questions.

At some point I decided to give back.

[image]

I'm definitely far from a great user of StackOverflow, but a couple weeks ago, I got this email:

> Hey, man, I would like to thank you for suggesting I learn OpenGL on stackoverflow for my modding question. Not only did I learn how to use LWJGL, I got into game developement and am working on a collab soon with a developer called Coffee Stain. Just wanted to thank you again!

I had two comments on the post in question. Two sassy shitty "you didn't even try and I dislike you" comments.

> How much LWJGL/OpenGL do you know? Probably not enough...
>
> It's going to be pretty hard...

Somehow those two irate comments evolved into that huge result for some random guy out there, which is pretty awesome. Crazy internet butterly effect.

Answer (score 8):

Oh, boy. Where to start?

I discovered Stack Overflow when I was just getting started with programming. I was in high school, very interested in computers, but I didn't know any programming. One day, out of the blue, I asked myself: "I have this Android phone with cool apps on it. Could I make some on my own? Is that possible?".
I googled around and sure enough, it was.

The first few links led me to Stack Overflow. I made myself an account, and asked my first question. Everything was very new to me, and I didn't understand how this site worked at first.

I have to smirk when looking at the first question: *[Start Activity with Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627098/start-activity-with-button-android)*.

I was a total beginner back then. I was very confused. But very motivated to learn. And Stack Overflow guided me through this entire process and I found a very supportive community on chat.stackoverflow.com. I'm not sure if I would kept pursuing this path if it wasn't for Stack Overflow.

I'm not in high school anymore. I've graduated this summer. And will be starting university soon: Computer science of course.

I've gone from being totally new to programming to landing an amazing internship as an Android developer at a very big company, which has turned to a part time position since, for as long as I'm in university.

It of course took a tremendous amount of personal dedication, but I feel like Stack Overflow is partly to thank for that.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Overflow has helped me from where I started in school to where I'm at now as a software consultant. I can't imagine how many hours I would have otherwise spent searching for resolutions to any number of problems I've encountered. Instead there has been so many times where I've come over to Stack Overflow and found an answer in minutes. But finding an answer isn't all that great if you don't *learn* from it, and with Stack Overflow so many people give not just the answer, but they include a great explanation as to why that is the correct answer or why the issue came up to begin with.

I remember yesterday I was working on an issue with a "help" modal not displaying the "**X**" to close out the modal in the top right corner. I had been searching my code for what I considered to be quite a while... a simple google search lead me to Stack Overflow where I quickly found out it was an issue with [jQuery-UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) and [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29) conflicting with one another. I could have spent days trying to figure this out and how to fix it, but Stack Overflow lead me to the answer in just minutes. I was able to also learn *why* it was conflicting and how to try and prevent such an issue in the future.

I know that I'm not alone when I say that Stack Overflow saves so much frustration and time. It's a great resource for any developer hoping to expand on their knowledge, learn something new, get a problem resolved, or learn the basic processes of software development for beginners. I started developing as a young kid long before there was Stack Overflow, and Internet forums were really my only resource - and at that time even those were scarce. Fast forward today so much of that hopping around from one forum to another is gone because of Stack Overflow. It's my one-stop shop, and I really can't stress enough how vital that is to new and old developers as a way of sharing information with the rest of the world rather than looking through forum after forum and *hoping* to find something worth while that is still relevant.

With all that being said... Thank you **SO** much!!

Comment: Was "Thank you SO much" an intentional pun? If it was, that was great.

Answer (score 7):

## A Big, International Community

[SO has lots and lots of users around the world.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65260/275537) No wonder it get's the 1<sup>st</sup> spot for all programming questions on Google. Every new coder searches Google when they run into a problem. Google has been redirecting me here ever since I started coding. Also, there is the merit of having no international restrictions because everything is in English. SO became the No. 1 site for asking questions and sharing my knowledge with the world.

Also, meta and chat further broke down this boundary. With no reputations at stake, I could freely discuss and chat with other users, and eventually, I got to know a lot of people.

## SO is a Markup Language in Itself

SO uses the famous Markdown language for posting questions, answers, and comments. Markdown is widely used in a variety of places, such as Git, Jekyll, Ghost, etc. **SO was the first place that I learned how to use this markup language.** It was quite inevitable as I had to ask questions, and I had to use this language in order to do so. Markdown is an easy language, but it may not be easy if you're in the wrong context, such as writing for the first time without a WYSIWYG editor. SO gave me a head start in this.

Thank you, and as always,

## SOReadytohelp

Answer (score 7):

I was walking on an unrelated path (classical ballet dancer) and had an accident which disabled all my opportunities to continue professionally. At the same time I always had the top scores for maths and natural sciences. Reading my mom’s BASIC and [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL) notes, I was also into programming, but well, I was still a teenage kiddo.

Later on, I won a scholarship to study software engineering at a local university. We had a 1 Mbit/s Internet connection, but we were 40 students. We started with learning [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29), and I completed the book that we supposed to finish in half a year, in a month. We were supposed to learn [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) by the end of the year, but everything was proceeding so slow for me and I started studying myself. The same year I had to leave the school and all I could do was studying autodidactically, so I kind of walked on my own way to learn and do things...

When you are walking on your own, you make a lot of mistakes. You will fear making mistakes that you won't be able to solve, thinking no one is there to guide you. You think that you'll never reach to the point you aim to. Overcoming feelings like that is never easy. Since I've found Stack Overflow, I realized that the education or information I needed was actually out there.

Since then I went to other two universities (and left again, this time because of really bad education and I was working so much). By the time I left the third school I was already working as a full stack developer, making web applications to companies and individuals from eight different countries. Now I have my own company!

I've been learning from Stack Overflow for about three years and the second year I got an account. Since then I'm here to learn more or solve more or help someone *if* I can, almost everyday. I even taught what I learned from here to other people out there. There are many ways Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange communities) helped me for all these. **How?**

---

- Community wikis and answers like below which gives a good load of high-caliber information:

*[The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)*

*[Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)*

*[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)*

*[MVC for advanced PHP developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356420/mvc-for-advanced-php-developers/16356866#16356866)*

---

Most importantly,

- Having a really good and strict way of (in)directly making me learn how to properly ask questions, and how to maintain my code to share with others for different purposes,
- How to find the real issue for a problem that I'm having (thanks to the community) and how to maintain this mindset to solve future problems,
- Always being surrounded by people who are trying to solve problems or **helping others to solve their problems**, thus giving courage that you can do the same as well (sometimes we really need this),
- Having the chance to see how **professionals** do their work/solve their issues and learn about optimum/general standards of *doing things*.

---

There is no way to count how many problems one solves, and how many hours one saves while browsing on this vast network of information. Once again, thanks a lot to everyone who was/is a part of this.

**SOReadytohelp**

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how different my story will be from others but it is ***my*** story and I appreciate us having the opportunity to all have *our own* experiences and to share them with each other and possibly others.

When I first got my current job as an Android programmer (and many days I'm other things, as well), I hadn't done any Android. I was asked after my first interview to do a few small, simple apps to show that I *could* do it.

I started working on an existing app that, while a nice idea, it was terribly written. Unfortunately, I didn't realize at first just how terribly it was written. I picked up some bad habits by following what was already done. Then I started lurking around on SO when I had issues. I quickly(?) started to learn how things *should* be done in Android.

I started out by answering "simpler" questions. It didn't take long before I started looking at more difficult issues people were having and I thought, "What better way to learn than to try and figure this out". I learned a lot from researching questions people had. Questions that I had no idea what the answer was but, from looking at the documentation and at other posts on the interwebz, I learned a great deal and was occasionally able to give the answer or to add a more detailed answer than what was already given.

Needless to say, I have learned a lot from SO which has helped me in my current job (and hopefully to soon help me in a future job). From learning debugging tricks and understanding documentation better to learning how to create better code (not just usable code). But from being a more active participant on meta and in chat, I have also gained skills not directly related to programming. I have gotten better at being more decisive, direct, objective, and tolerant. I have also met quite a few nice folks in chat to learn about different customs in different areas of the world and some who I can chat with about things not related to development such as having personal/life conversations with.

In short, it's amazing how I came here to be a better developer (which has happened) but I have also made some valuable contacts and maybe even friends around the world.

Oh ya, and...

**[ROOM 15 ROCKS!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android)**

Answer (score 6):

*TL;DR: As a college student who's a self-taught coder, Stack Overflow helps me gain experience interacting with other software developers.*

---

Stack Overflow has mainly helped me in two different ways. The obvious one is that I frequently find solutions to challenges I encounter here, so I'm going to focus on the second way it's helped me.

I'm a mostly self-taught developer. I've never really worked on a team of developers, so I haven't had much experience working out coding challenges with other team members. Stack Overflow has given me a chance to analyze problems others are having and then explain a solution in a way they'll understand. I feel it's been instrumental in helping me learn how to interact with other programmers. It gives me the opportunity to get feedback on how helpful my explanations are and the chance to improve them.

Now that I'm in college, I think it's given me an edge when I need to communicate with classmates. One of my classes even has a group discussion board, so it's almost like our own mini Stack Overflow. This summer, I got to help kids learn how to program during a tech camp at my college, and my Stack Overflow experience helping beginning programmers made me comfortable helping the kids, who were also mostly beginners.

There are so many other things I could mention about how it's helped me develop my skills, from deciphering hard-to-understand English to how to form a good question. Thanks to everyone at Stack Overflow who's given me the chance to develop my skills while helping other people.

Answer (score 6):

My first experiences with Stack Overflow were as a student. Luckily, it seems that my questions were common schoolbook questions that had well-established answers. Reading Stack Overflow answers was often a lot easier than the corresponding Java documentation. It was super nice having someone take the time to better explain the underlying concepts that are often lacking in documentation.

Fast forward a few years, and I started working with technologies that weren't part of my "standard computer science curriculum," specifically [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS). All of the sudden, my questions were a lot more specific and harder to find answers for. I now finally appreciated the effort that people put into answering these really random questions.

Finally, I decided to create an account to upvote some really helpful answers. But I couldn't do that until I had 15 reputation points. OK, so I tried my hand at answering questions. At this point, I realized how little I actually knew about the vast world of programming. I mean, I could solve some of the schoolbook problems that I faced in the past, but it took a few heavily downvoted (and subsequently deleted) answers of mine to fully appreciate what I didn't know. Thanks to some comments, I learned my answers were fine for some situations, but they were terrible coding practices.  Sometimes my solutions would not scale, and other times they were horribly inefficient. And the helpful comments and the downvotes really helped me better understand the concepts I overlooked.

It was a real eye-opening experience, and I finally became a [consciously incompetent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_competence) programmer. And with a bit more practice at work and answering questions, I hope to move onto conscious competence soon.

---

TL;DR

Stack Overflow is not only a great resource that answers my questions. The community in general also helped point out my programming shortcomings so that I might improve them. I'm grateful for all the helpful comments, answers, and even some of the downvotes.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR: Stack Overflow has given me an outlet to do my best to help others which inevitably returns benefit to me ten fold.

---

The best example of this is a couple years ago when Swift was first announced by Apple. I decided that day, that I wanted to be one of the first people to become proficient in the language, but where should I begin?

The announcement came with a book written by Apple to help us understand the language, but this was incredibly dense and hard to follow, especially as the language evolved through the betas. Also, I am the type that learns best by doing, and without Swift being ready to use for a real product, that learning path was hard to follow. Well at least it would have been without the existence of Stack Overflow.

I of course spent time making little utilities and fooling around in Swift playgrounds, but the most efficient and valuable way I found to learn Swift was to scour Stack Overflow for unanswered questions about Swift and to do my best to answer them. I was pleasantly surprised that I was not the only one who was diving into Swift and even though Apple provides their own developer forums, many people had taken to asking questions on Stack Overflow.

By finding unanswered questions and trying to answer them, I was able to learn by doing and benefit from the experience of many other developers. We tend to learn best by running into problems and solving them. If we don't ever run into problems, we are almost certain to stagnate in our skills. By pushing myself to solve other peoples' problems using Stack Overflow, I exponentially increased the problems I solved thereby exponentially increasing the rate at which I learned the intricacies of Swift.

As I did this, I found myself ranked near the top of the answer's list for the Swift tag which not only brought me great joy and satisfaction, but also lead to me being approached to write a [book about learning Swift](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1784392502). This book has brought me a lot of admiration from friends, colleges, and family. I have Stack Overflow to thank for that; not only for providing me a platform to teach myself the skills necessary to write the book, but also for providing me the exposure to be noticed by a publisher.

Answer (score 6):

I am not a professional programmer (just someone who writes a lot of [code for research](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17781/why-do-many-talented-scientists-write-horrible-software)).  But Stack Overflow has helped me immeasurably as an educator.

Take last semester. A week before classes started, I was given a graduate-level course in embedded systems to teach (it was kind of an emergency situation, where the department had to scramble to find coverage at the last minute). This subject is so far outside my comfort zone, it's in a different time zone. Not only have I not *taught* it before, I've never *taken* even an undergrad course in embedded systems or a related area.

I can pick up the material myself, but you need a lot more than that to be an effective educator: you need to also understand what concepts are most difficult to beginners, what stubborn misconceptions you will have to uproot, and what the really bright students will grapple with. And you need multiple ways to explain key concepts, to reach different learners, and some idea of which explanations are most effective. I can't get those things from a textbook or from traditional online resources.

**This is where Stack Overflow came to my rescue in a HUGE way.**

My first step after writing my syllabus was to go to Stack Overflow and look up all of the tags related to topics featured heavily on it: [embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded), [bit-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation), [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management), [arm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arm), [deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deadlock), and [rtos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtos), for example.  Then I read Q&A for about three days. These questions and answers featured heavily in my classroom. Some examples:

- I took classic questions like [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) and [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work) and used them as lecture notes when explaining those concepts.
- I actually gave out [How do you set, clear and toggle a single bit in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c) as a handout and encouraged students to bring it with them to the open-book exam.
- Then there were the stunningly complete answers to really vague questions, which gave me insight into what students would not know how to even ask properly, and how to answer them: [What is Bootloader and startup code in the embedded systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696258/what-is-bootloader-and-startup-code-in-the-embedded-systems), for example.
- I learned what lessons I might need to undo from previous classes my students might have taken in the area (See [Is it faster to count down than it is to count up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823043/is-it-faster-to-count-down-than-it-is-to-count-up)).

etc.

If you have to teach a university-level course in a technical area without having any experience teaching that subject before, Stack Overflow is an amazing resource. It helped me understand *how people learn* the subject, which is *so* valuable to me as an educator.

Answer (score 6):

StackOverflow got me my first job.

I always wanted to work in aerospace. I picked all my subjects at school and college to aim for that career, and embarked on a degree in aerospace engineering. Halfway through that degree, I'd discovered that it wasn't at all like I thought, I wasn't enjoying it, and I was only barely scraping a pass. Along the way, I'd discovered that my aptitude with computers went deeper than I thought and I'd picked up some basic programming skills, so I switched to a computer systems degree at a different university. I discovered StackOverflow in my first year on that course, and it helped me find answers to all sorts of questions that the course led me to ask - not just coursework, but also in my extracurricular pursuits, which involved games programming and robotics.

Remembering my disappointment when I discovered what aerospace was really like, I took a year in industry to make sure that software development was really for me. The professional environment proved to be a serious challenge, forcing me to really up my game and learn a lot of new skills - and once again, StackOverflow was invaluable in helping me find answers to all these new questions. As my skills progressed, my interactions with StackOverflow evolved from mostly asking questions to mostly providing answers, as I became comfortable with the commonly-used areas of the technologies I was working with. I assumed that my questions would start to go unanswered as I dug deeper into the more advanced topics, but I was pleasantly surprised to find just how knowledgeable SO's community are, and how willing even the most experienced developers are to spend their time answering questions asked by relative novices. I gained over a thousand rep in six months, and started gaining access to moderation tools. I started reviewing questions in my spare time, wanting to give a little back to the community that had helped me.

I continued to use StackOverflow as both asker and answerer throughout my final year of university. My dissertation provided me with some challenging questions (forcing me to work out how to properly cite a StackOverflow answer in an academic paper), and answering other people's questions helped to consolidate my knowledge, helping me to produce better code for my coursework. I scored first-class honours in my software design and development module.

Towards the end of my time at university, I started to think about employment. I signed up to all the usual places, but something in StackOverflow's sidebar caught my eye: a careers site just for programmers called careers.stackoverflow.com. I signed up, filled in some details, linked a few of my favourite question, and went back to proofreading my dissertation.

I was contacted by a company based in the city a few weeks later; they'd picked me out based on the technologies I'd said I liked. They said that my StackOverflow answers showed that I knew the tech, and the content of some of my more interesting questions showed that I was doing cool stuff with it. I went for interview, and was offered the job later that same day - a full month before I sat finals. Thanks to StackOverflow, I entirely skipped the period of worry between graduating and finding employment - instead, employment found me!

So there it is: StackOverflow helped me change careers, complete a degree, and get my first job.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe my story is not so elaborate as those in the first page, but I think this is the most precious moment, and I really thank Stack Overflow for made me success in it.

I almost forgot when was my first time using Stack Overflow. It was started from a search result which took me here. Then, after saw this place as a place where I can get more information, then I registered my account and asked my first question: *[Combination LED in MCS-51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756657/combination-led-in-mcs-51)* (to this day, this is like the most dormant question I ever had).

Then, I started to be (not so) active at Stack Overflow. Improving my tags, randomly asking questions here and there, etc. One day, I stumbled into this at the right (bounty) time: *[How to save the state(all open windows and tabs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26925855/how-to-save-the-stateall-open-windows-and-tabs)* and got the points.

For some people, this may be like a simple question that you can answer and then move on. But for me, this is like my first big step into programming. This very question caused a [butterfly effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_effect) right at my life, encouraging me to do more in programming (at first, it was basic database fundamentals, and then it went into Windows application development)

When I was signing for Microsoft Student Partners at my country, I also did many search at Stack Overflow. One question that I asked was: *[2 XAML reference to single C# class (Universal App 8.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405265/2-xaml-reference-to-single-c-sharp-class-universal-app-8-1)* and it helped me well during the commitment review where I needed to develop a Universal Windows 8.1 app.

Currently, I am working part-time at my university lab. Making modules for students who do courses. One time, we once stumble upon some various questions about HTML5. During the meeting, I did a simple lookout at Stack Overflow, and found the exact answers. Thanks to Stack Overflow, we've cut the meeting hour almost half a hour and figured the best answer to be put at modules.

Until now, thanks to Stack Overflow, I am still studying more about programming, especially the new [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) Windows 1.

Thank you Stack Overflow, and always keeps growing, for the sake of every programmers out there.

Answer (score 6):

I started trying to program when I was about 11. I relied mainly on asking teachers and my parents about various programming concepts. The first real script I wrote was an application that allowed users to get their iOS UDID from MobileSafari (http://udid.falkirks.com). I hit a bunch of roadblocks with the text encoding and by searching Google I stumbled on StackOverflow, this magical website where everyone had already answered every question I had had about programming. With the help of StackOverflow, I was able to complete my first project, which gave me a big confidence boost.

Fast forward to last year, I was taking Computer Science AP a year ahead of most students. I had skipped Computer Programming Advanced which covered most of the topics included in Computer Science AP, so I was out of place. StackOverflow helped me patch whatever titbits of knowledge I was missing and I ended up getting a 5 on the exam. I left that class with a bunch of random knowledge about the inner workings and inconsistencies of the Java compiler, which I hope I never have to use again.

I am now 16 and entering my final year of high school. Over time, I have acquired a methodology where I don't want to use something or apply an algorithm, unless I understand everything about it. All the drawbacks, edge-cases and intricacies. StackOverflow has helped me learn things about languages and products that I use, that I would have never found out by myself.

Also, whenever I have a problem with git. I just Google "How to do this with git?" and the first result is consistently StackOverflow. Click it and I get a quality solution to my problem which would otherwise have had me pulling my hair out for hours (and probably end with `git push -f origin master`).

All in all, StackOverflow helped me gain confidence in programming, succeed in the AP exam and is here for me whenever I have problems. I wish I could give back, but I still think I have so much to learn before I can match the answer quality of existing contributors.

Answer (score 6):

Being an autodidact developer who often "learns by doing" Stack Overflow quickly became my prime resource for general (beginner) programming questions and any kind of problems I encounter during everyday programming tasks. 
Answers to questions which might be found in some lengthy tutorials or forum threads are available here at a glance, often with even more information than the answer to the actual question alone, e.g., explanations, reasoning, background information, performance considerations (when asking about algorithms), or simply useful (further) advice.
Altogether, Stack Overflow helped me increase my performance by providing very good, to-the-point answers which can be found easily and often provide even more than just the solution to my programming problems.

Additionally, Stack Overflow helped me learn and gain knowledge I doubt I'd find that easy somewhere else.
Especially, the [highest voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) and corresponding answers are excellent. 
Two examples are the well-known answer about [branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/2367849) by [Mysticial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) and [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s ultra-fast answer about a [time zone change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/2367849) to [Freewind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342235/freewind)'s question about an unexpected result of the [difference between two timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/2367849).

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow has helped me in several ways. Being a self-taught developer, sometimes reading the documentation makes no sense to me, not having learned the technical jargon. However, when researching a problem, putting it into layman's terms, Stack Overflow answers and related questions usually pop up in a Google search, because they are not technical documentation, but real people talking about real problems.

Another way Stack Overflow has helped has been in several job interviews. I had several interviews when searching for a new job, and in nearly every interview, the question would come up "How do you solve technical problems you don't already know how to solve?" My answer for that was usually "Search on Stack Overflow." The response was always at least a smile and note taking, but one interviewer actually said "Yes!", and fist pumped the air. Yeah, that was a good interview.

Lastly, though not exactly related to Stack Overflow's 10-million question milestone, careers.stackoverflow.com has also helped in my job search. While I didn't get my current job through that site, it did provide a nice cross section of the skills that employers are looking for currently. This led me to put in time to expand my skill set, and, inevitably, led me back to Stack Overflow with questions.

In general, the support from the Stack Overflow community, the open willingness of everyone to help, and being able to give back to other struggling beginners has given me a sense of accomplishment and faith in the developer culture.

Thank you Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 5):

**Before joining Stack Overflow:**

I have some skill-set in HTML, CSS & JavaScript. Obviously, I used to fiddle with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and adopt the trial-and-error methods. Although it leads to many solutions, I never really understood how it worked. I was struggling to answer most of the questions my peers would ask, even if something basic.

**After joining Stack Overflow:**

After seeing so many quality answers that would go deep into how web browsers work, it certainly gives much confidence in answering questions. Even references to official w3.org articles has improved the browsing experience for finding apt solutions recommended by the official organization.

It has also improved my question asking ability. I think the improvement can be seen from [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013032/prevent-user-to-find-password-through-firebug-chrome-dev-tools) to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224802/extend-the-final-state-of-the-first-animation-for-translated-element). The First question was asked without much effort, while the second seems detailed. The timeline between the two is around three months, the time period I learned many things here.

In addition to that, it has been a very humbling experience here since many of the high profile users collaborate to solve a problem. The exciting notifications of `+10` and `+15` and satisfying comments from the question posters when they find your answer useful just makes my day everyday!

Thank you very much **Stack Overflow**, I do think it should be one of the better learning resources, hiring methods of the future contrary to the college education and hiring based on grades.

Answer (score 5):

**Helped you succeed in school**

I am almost done with my IT/CS study now. When I first started out I didn't know the first thing about programming.
Every assignment we got, I turned to google for tips & guidance on how to do X and Y and how to handle certain
programming problems. Nearly every search I made had SO as top hit. As my study progressed I spent more time on SO
because every assignment got harder and I had to look up new stuff (we are taught the basics in class, but mostly
you have to figure things out yourself). I learned how SO works with the voting and everything and felt the need
to create an account to rewards all the users that I had learned from, so I did. As I learned more over the years,
I became able to answer some questions myself left and right. I more or less became 'addicted' to spending time on SO.
I have spent **a lot** of time reading interesting questions and answers, and to this day I still learn new stuff on
a daily basis.

During my time on SO I read and learned about pros and cons of X and Y, tips & tricks in programming, corner cases where stuff that
should work, doesn't. And much more.
I have asked fellow classmates but not one of them has or uses his account on SO or spends time on it besides looking for
information they need for assignments. Because I do, I have always felt that I have a great advantage over them, having learned
a great deal more than would be necessary to successfully study here. It has occurred more than once that we had some decisions
to make in a group project where someone would suggest we do it a certain way and I could say *"nope that's not a good idea,
 because"* and then I would explain them something I learned on SO and they'd be like *"oh I never knew that, good to know!".*

**Changed your career**

Because I was ahead of the rest of the class, about a year ago I was invited to join our school's excellence program.
Through that I met and connected with new people. One of them helped me get where I am today, doing a graduate internship
at Philips Innovation. It's possible that I will remain to work here after my intership is done and for many years after that.
I feel I would not have been given that chance if I had never been active on SO, so thank you for that!

Also, I would like to quote Dave Zych here, because I read his piece and this part applies to me 100% as well.

> I was able to show my potential employers my SO profile and show them real, concrete examples of what I know. Along with that, it displays thousands of interactions with other programmers, my ability to explain things, and examples of writing and usage of the English language. My SO profile has been such an incredibly useful tool for things like this because there is so much information a potential employer can see outside of the 1 hour, high pressure interview.

Next to that, I have a profile on SO careers and have already been contacted multiple times for (parttime) job offers, even though it clearly states I'm
not a professional programmer but still a student. That doesn't happen to students that only learn what they're required to learn and go no further.

Through SO, I became interested in technologies other than those we were taught in school and spent free time exploring them and learning about them. These are bonus skills I have which, today, make me someone who knows a bit about everything. This can (or not) give me an advantage when looking for a job in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow gave me confidence. I know when I'm facing problems of my own, and the difference when facing problems of all programmers working on the same platform as me. A big distinction. I didn't have to doubt my coding abilities when issues seemingly turned up out of nowhere.

Now it's my full time job, and I've made a career out of it. Most of what I know is self-taught so knowing I could push forward without worrying that I was going into a field blind and making the wrong choice.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow changed my life in different ways, so I need to divide the history in parts.

When I finished my degree in computer science, I was good enough (not the best) in math and in computer science theory, but I was never a good programmer and this wasn't the only problem because all the good content that could make me a good programmer was in English. English is not my mother language (maybe this text shows this clearly) and I had a kind of fear in learning English just to improve my programming skills, so I didn't do it, even knowing that English is the "official" language for IT world.

When I started to work as a developer, I needed to google for some things (after all, I was a bad programmer) and then I started to find all the answers that I needed on Stack Overflow. I didn't do my registration at first, but I started to read a lot of information in English and the registration was natural, when I realized that my questions could be answered and that I could answer some questions...it was perfect, but I still had trouble with English. However, I was excited to answer something and ask new ones, so I forgot my problems with the language and did it.

Nowadays, I do not have the best English skills, but I improved it a lot, so:

***First change of life made by the Stack Overflow:*** Improve my English skills, what gave me new job opportunities and also helped me to finally get the original materials in English to learn new things.

Using Stack Overflow daily, I discovered the awesome Stack Exchange Network and after that I was in love with the possibilities to share my knowledge about many things and at the same time learn more and more. The spirit of this community throughout the network that has been created around Stack Overflow is amazing. That changed my way of learning and also changed my vision about sharing things.

***Second change of life made by the Stack Overflow:*** I learned with the community to share my knowledge in different ways and today seek to do this in different ways, either by asking / answering questions or helping open source projects.

While improving my skills as a programmer I feel that this is not the work of my life. I see that my real vocation is to share my knowledge with others, and then I decided to be a professor. I’m doing my master's degree right now and I’ll start a PhD course in the first semester of 2016. Remember I improved my English because of Stack Overflow? So, I want to do all my PhD in English.

***Third change of life made by the Stack Overflow:***

I changed the course of my professional life and now I want to be a professor just to take more and more opportunities to share my knowledge and my participation (passive and active) in Stack Overflow certainly contributed to the decision.

Beside all these stuff, participating in Stack Overflow is really cool. 8-)

Answer (score 5):

Wow - where do I start...

**Consuming**

I - probably like most of the other users coming to this community often - started out as a pure consumer of answers. If you have a problem - Stack Overflow is most of the time the way to go - if you can articulate your question properly. I've touched a number of areas in software development throughout my carrier - be it SQL, [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29), [iBATIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_iBATIS), [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework), JavaScript, [AngularJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) and more recently also Android app development. I find it happens very rarely that I cannot find a similar question or the exact question that I have already here. Most of the time there is either a spot on 100% answer or a couple of close answers that give me fresh ideas on how to approach my problem.

**Contributing**

Then I became a contributor myself - this was a rather recent event - and I find the award system highly motivating. Even more motivating is providing someone with an answer that helps that person progress or even solves the problem completely. I'm now hunting badges and trying to get to my next milestone in terms of reputation - and I made it a habit of spending 20-30 minutes every morning going through new questions in my preferred areas and trying to help where I can. It says a lot about the quality of the contributors that it is not always easy to find an unanswered question to which I can provide some help. Most of the time new questions are answered properly within minutes - a really impressive community of very smart and getting smarter people.

Answer (score 5):

It helped change my mom's perspective towards programming and nerdy-stuff in general.

When I started out doing some side-projects, I'd get too involved in it and would sideline my academics, but still managed to balance them both, well, nearly enough.

That was when I discovered Stack Overflow. The incentive of reputations was the first reason I actively contributed here. To be honest, I played it as a game, but a game which made me more productive and knowledgeable in my field of *learning*.

My mom was apprehensive of "dabbing at the keyboard which made no sense"(to her, obviously).

The more I stayed here, the more mature I became. I began treating this as a knowledge treasure that grows manifold every other day.

## So how did Stack Overflow help me?

My friends in India, have no idea of what I do and they kinda hate computer-related stuff. But then, I started getting *noticed*. I began to receive emails (yay!).

When my mom viewed many job offers that I got, she was impressed and I'd spend millions to see that look in her face, a delighted one.

For, I was ~15 and *had* to or *forced to* not accept it, as I was still a school-goer.

### The moment my mom and I'll cherish:

The Stack Overflow employees gave me lots of things:

A t-shirt, a pen-drive, a pen, some stickers (unfortunately all of them had Stack Exchange branding, instead of Stack Overflow, but let's not bring it in here)

### Why?

I had made a website kinda an awful clone of facebook and had sent a mail to Stack Exchange to review it and if it was of some use.

They graciously replied back giving me lots of constructive feedback. They had gone through the process of signing up in my awfully long sign up form.

But to make sure that I was encouraged, they redirected me to Google Forms(Docs?) wherein I filled in my address to have the above stated things shipped to my place.

When a FedEx parcel came, addressed to **ME**, it was a special feeling. I had never seen FedEx parcel before and there I was standing there with awe.

From that day onward, my Mom and Friends realized that I wasn't hammering away some stuff on my keyboard, but was doing *something* productive.

And for that, THANK YOU, STACK OVERFLOW <3 :D

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow actually helps me on a daily basis.

Between working with languages I'm unfamiliar with, lurking on
[Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25347/survival-game-create-your-wolf?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top) (I love attempting to understand the logic of all the different solutions), and learning enough each day to improve my usefulness at my current job, I can safely say that Stack Overflow is extremely useful and important in my life.

Every day there is something new for me to search for. Even though I don't ask questions on this site, I often find my answers with a quick search, and off I go to learn.

In fact, I've been looking into class reflection lately, because I saw a reference to it in one of the answers to the above question.

To me, Stack Overflow is more than just a website with information on it. It's both educational and entertaining, and I wouldn't even have my job today without it. I've learned so much about SQL, Java, C#, and more just reading other people's Q&A's. Without that, I'd still be baking donuts at [Safeway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safeway_Inc.).

As I've said in [another post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey/304263#304263), Stack Overflow is more educational than college courses for teaching programming: I've learned more here in *two weeks* than I have throughout my entire *two years* in regular courses.

Answer (score 5):

**The questions I couldn't answer taught me more than my B.Sc. in Computer Science**

I encountered StackOverflow many times from Google searches before I even thought about joining. In that regard it had already helped me numerous times. When I finally decided to join, it was to ask a question. I didn't think my question would be answered for a while, so I logged back and came back the next day to find that it had been answered only five minutes after I posted it. I was a little disappointed that no one had upvoted my question and I hadn't gained any rep. I thought that it'd be fun to try to get some rep I was halfway through a 4 year degree in Computer Science and had been programming in PHP and Javascript since middle school, so I thought I might have enough knowledge to answer some questions. Little did I know how much I would learn from answering...

My first answer on StackOverflow earned me a comment that said "Thanks alot Paul", but no rep. It wasn't until my sixth answer that I got a checkmark and a decent amount of rep (I got 8 upvotes on that answer the day I wrote it). The answer was very simple and I thought it was odd that I gained more rep for it than for some other answers. As you can probably tell, when I first joined I was very focused on earning rep and unlocking privileges, helping others was a secondary goal, and learning from others wasn't in the picture. That all changed the first time I answered a question completely wrong.

It was my first heavily ***downvoted*** answer that made me realize how valuable StackOverflow would be. I have since deleted the answer, since it was incorrect and there were better answers already posted, so I'm not sure when it happened (about 4 years ago). I know that it was a Javascript question and I know that my answer was wrong. The fact that I can't remember the specifics, is a testament to just how much I have learned from StackOverflow over the years. From that moment on the way I used StackOverflow changed. Before then I was focused on earning rep, so I would only answer questions that I thought I knew the best answer to and I would ignore questions that I didn't know the answer to. After that moment I started searching for questions that I didn't know the answer to (but were still relevant to languages I used); they became the most interesting questions to me. Every question I opened I would either answer, or favourite and then come back to when someone else had answered. For some of the most interesting questions I would stay on the tab and refresh, just thinking about the question, and what I thought a solution might look like, while waiting to see what other people would post.

After the way I used StackOverflow changed, I started learning way more than I thought I had left to learn, about the languages I use daily. There have been hundreds of times where I've found an interesting question and learnt something new. Over the years the cumulative knowledge I've gained from all those experiences combined with my own experiences while coding, has made me an expert web developer. When asked how I learnt PHP and Javascript I usually say that I am entirely self-taught (I didn't use these at all during my degree), but in reality it is the StackOverflow community that has taught me most of what I know.

A few other ways it has helped me:

- My current employer found me through StackOverflow Careers
- Hundreds of Google searches have led me to an answer on StackOverflow
- I asked a few more questions in my first couple years of StackOverflow and usually received great answers. It's been a couple years since I've asked a question on StackOverflow and I'm not sure why that is; but it could be because StackOverflow also taught me how to ask a good question and in the process of doing that I usually find the answer I'm looking for before I ask the question.
- StackOverflow helped me reinforce my own knowledge, for example I knew the answer to this question, because I was reading Knuth's books at the time it was asked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22328216/772035

Comment: Very good answer.

Comment: How did you feel about being called an "alot"?

Answer (score 5):

I consider myself very lucky to have had Stack Overflow with me every step of the way during my programming life so far.

My story starts back in school several years ago. I was learning my first language, Java, but my teacher was unable to answer many of the nagging questions I had, especially those concerned with how things work behind the scenes. All books in the library were hopelessly out of date, so naturally I turned to the internet. **Stack Overflow quickly became known as a reliable source information and knowledge.**

I use Stack Overflow in several ways:

- *Direct answers for when I have a specific problem.*
  With 192 answers and one question, I'm very cautious about asking questions. If I can't find an existing answer to my problem, it probably means I'm asking the wrong question. Ironically, a lack of questions can sometimes be helpful in itself.
- *General immersion on a topic.*
  I've found that ordering questions by votes and looking through the discussion gives me a good introduction to a topic. One example of this is [Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) - coming from [SVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), I remember rebasing sounding like witchcraft (and to a much lesser extent, it still is).
- *Learning techniques and patterns that aren't necessarily available anywhere else.* 
  Stack Overflow gives me exposure to the code and thought process of senior developers, which I would not otherwise have had. Different answers also give several angles from which to attack a problem, which is often useful outside the boundaries of the original question.

I've since started a computer science degree at university, and have a promising internship within the technology industry that I hope to turn into a full time job. While it would be foolish to say my career path is attributed to Stack Overflow, I'd definitely say this site had a part to play. **It is highly likely that answering questions has helped me in technical interviews.** Without Stack Overflow, I think I would've quickly become frustrated by my lack of progress. Nowadays, **if I can't find something akin to what I'm trying to do on Stack Overflow, I reconsider the way I'm going about the problem**.

Answer (score 5):

I first started off as a programmer back in 2008. I was at university, doing a master's degree in chemistry, but I'd always liked the idea of building things for myself. I started helping out with an online radio station to build a website for them, and today it's expanded into its own community with thousands of active users. But that was in my free time.

So I dropped out of university and started working as a developer.

I found online communities to help me learn. GitHub and Stack Overflow were probably the absolute driving forces behind my career; GitHub taught me *how to contribute*, but Stack Overflow taught me *how to do things right*. It's helped me in countless situations (including getting jobs!), and has always been in my list of open tabs when programming, whether working a 9 to 5 job, or doing freelance work.

It's through doing freelance programming that I saw a proposal for [a new Stack Exchange site about freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/tour), and during its private beta, I signed up. I offered to help moderate the site, and now I'm volunteering for the same company that helped build my career up to what it is today.

I owe where I am to Stack Exchange, and I'm delighted to give back.

Answer (score 5):

Originally, I was only vaguely aware of Stack Exchange, as I'm not a developer, and my coding was limited to security analysis of code.

Then 1734 days ago (approximately) I was pointed at [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) by a friend and colleague (another [Rory](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/37/r%D0%BEry-mccune)) and I found it an amazing place to ask and answer questions, and I rapidly became a pro-tem moderator there. Over the years I have taken up [mod](https://music.stackexchange.com/)-[ship](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) on [quite](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) a [few](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) [Stack Exchange](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) [sites](https://video.stackexchange.com/), so a lot of my activity has been around helping others, mediating, cleaning up and generally being nice, and on many sites I supply reasonably well received answers, which ties in with my paternal and mentoring urges, but...

**How did Stack Overflow help me?**

I had an engagement integrating a security code review process into an established code review process that was being upgraded, using [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) and [ClearCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_ClearCase), and over the course of two days what was quite impenetrable and frustrating to me (having only limited experience with these previously) became clear through Von's answer to my [one and only Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5552339/529337).

I'm still not a coder, and Stack Overflow is not one of my top day-to-day Stack Exchange sites, but that convinced me that Stack Overflow had real value even to me, a non-coder, so I used the site much more, finding answers that helped me complete a much broader range of activities than I had expected to on that engagement and ever since.

Answer (score 5):

I think many users share story similar to mine, a lot of it has to do with SO being so widespread and people always happy to help. To say something about myself, I've always been interested in PCs and programming and decided to pursue that career further in an electro-engineering university. Unfortunately for me, even though the main course was IT, because the university was electro-engineering, focused learning of actual programming was somehow on a backburner. Of course - not to badmouth here, the teachers were professionals. The university itself has good status, I think as a person very interested in IT I was hoping for something else/more.

So, that's how I got my Java background. I certainly didn't feel like Java expert at the time and my knowledge was mostly theoretical. Feeling not very confident about myself, I've decided to venture into Android development. It always seemed very interesting to me, Google tries to make good tools to support developers (I have got to say, Android Studio is pretty great) and it's Java-based. I did what I assume many people do when they start out with new language / framework. I read books, listened and did online courses and wrote simple apps based on them.

A lot of code was provided, and none of it went too deep - the purpose was to give something quickly rather than something deep. I realized after a while, that's simply not enough. I took advice I'd recommend to everyone by now (although probably not many starting programmers are reading stuff on Meta Stack Overflow) - the advice being "just start". Find something you want to do, figure out how do you want it to look like, what the app should do, and go do it.

The start wasn't easy, that's for sure. Luckily, my Java background was enough to figure out how to do what I want - and for anything specific I quickly found my home on Stack Overflow. I didn't even have to ask most questions, and that's the amazing part.

For almost any issue I had or dreamed about to put into my app there was somehow already an answer / code snippet / guidance how to do what I want. That's including obscure settings like *Pick color theme*, *Night mode* or *creating material themed settings menu*. I really have to say a big thanks to people always happy to help even absolute new people like I was, with code examples and sharing their knowledge. And even though I didn't have to ask, Stack Overflow played huge part to get me what I needed - during that time I got my "100 consecutive days" badge easily.

Today my app is in the store (not posting links to not look like a cheap advertiser) and users are very positive about it which is what matters to me. I got my satisfaction in a way that, yes, I can actually code functional big project and I'm currently looking for a job in a field.

Hopefully, I'll get to edit this bit soon about my findings :) But again, massive thanks belong to the whole community which helped me in a great way. I have a lot to learn to reach some of almost legendary names posting here, but I still visit Stack Overflow daily to help with what I know and give people same help that I got. I'm glad we are all making this site better.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't that much of a Stack Overflow story (sorry!), but it's a story of six years on Stack Exchange, and it’s probably something worth sharing. It could be, but I'm not quite a coder. I figured I'd share anyway, since it could have been. It’s a story of how I hit pretty close to rock bottom and got back up. I'm sure there's some Stack Overflow folks with similar stories.

I do use Stack Overflow *passively*, to look up stuff like Git commands and stuff, but it’s in no way my main site. I have no special, heartwarming stories to tell there. It’s a useful resource, and I'm glad that it’s here. This though, is a story of Super User (SU) mainly. There aren't any [Ewoks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewok) (though, I've had a terrier much of this time) involved.

I've been on Stack Exchange for six years. Six years ago, I'd dropped out of university twice, had utterly no faith in my own skills, and basically spent all my time living the basement dweller dream of sorts. I also had *terrible* [agoraphobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoraphobia), was depressed and was stuck in my apartment most of the time. My parents didn't quite get what was wrong with me, and some of my extended family thought I was just plain loony. I was a mess. There's a whole load of stigma about mental illness, even the mostly harmless sort to others around here. Sometimes I think I managed because of my dog (the lovely rascal that he is).

Often we joke on the Internet, [no one knows you're a dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet%2C_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog). No one knows you're a mess either. Things focus on how you come across, your knowledge, and your answers, and that *worked for me*. Being able to share knowledge helped a certain part of me *thrive*.

I'm reading [Slashdot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot) and I see an open beta for this site about "computer questions". I'm curious, and bored and start hanging out. I figure I could ask a few questions... and I end up answering questions (and not quite noticing the steady increase in my reputation). One day I get an email saying I'm in the first two pages... and SU will send me a T-shirt (Today, I have swag from SU, [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and so on... it’s still *the* special SU T shirt). I realise I actually *know* a little. Then [I hit 10K, then 20K. I'm over 70K now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174863/whats-the-feeling-of-having-more-than-10k-points-of-rep/174873#174873). I went back to school knowing I could kick ass (with a few small bumps to show along the way when school kicked back). I graduated last year, and I have a job. I'm also a moderator on SU.

*I have skills*, and more importantly I have *faith* in those skills. I've turned the tacit skills of my oddly misspent youth into things that people actually can read about and benefit. I've gotten better at finding problems, and describing them (even if it’s a work in progress). I've learnt a lot from people around me, and there's a sense of community on my home site which is awesome. Life's *normal* again.

It’s not *the* thing that pulled me out of the hole I was in, but it sure helped a lot. So... it’s not a Stack Overflow story, but I figured I'd share it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a self-taught programmer, and I've gotten a degree, but in something entirely nonprogramming-related (animation). I had learned enough when I was younger to know how to string code together, and the concepts that make a program. But I was always pretty uncertain. I would just throw in code that I thought should work, and then slowly work through why it wasn't working and what was causing problems.

I eventually stumbled onto Stack Overflow when solving problems, I made an account and asked some questions. It was great to have my brain mangled around an incomprehensible problem that someone could answer and untangle for me so I'd both fix it now and understand what was actually happening.

I started browsing a little too, wanting to become more a part of this site. I primarily use Python, and started to find out about some of the finer points of what it does just from reading other interesting sounding questions. Some of the tools and quirks are incredibly helpful, but I never would've found them otherwise. I even started answering questions and got to untangle other people's mangled brains to show them their problems, the gratitude and relief that help brings is one of my favourite feelings on here.

This all happened in less than a year. At the start I didn't think I could answer questions at all or really be of help, but now I'm a proud contributor.

Answer (score 5):

## TL;DR - Stack Overflow. Allowing me to live the dream!

As far back as I can remember I've always loved anything geeky. Computers. Technology. The Internet. How things work. From that first moment that every adult in the world ever wants to know *"what do you want to be when you grow up?"*, I knew the field in which I wanted to work. It's has got to be IT! Maybe I can build my own programs and websites? The beef with big dreams like this is that as I found out, it isn't easy.

I took everything IT-related at school. I went onto take a degree in computer science at university and the moment that I graduated I felt invincible. I've followed my passion and got my degree. This is it! I'm unstoppable, baby! It's going to be easy to walk into that dream job now, right?? *Right??* **Nope.**

I went to several interviews around that time. Flunked all of them. I had the drive, but none of the real-world experience. Stuck in that ol' Catch-22 of needing the job to get the experience, but not being able to get the job because of not having any experience. Wow. I was absolutely **crushed**. I don't think I've ever felt as low as I did right then at that moment. I lost a lot of faith in the dream at that time.

I eventually picked myself back up and decided that the only way to get to where I wanted to be was to take a low-level job and claw my way to the top of the shop. So, after some time wallowing around in self-pity, I found an internship job working as an analyst for a small company that in all honesty was slightly too far for me to drive, but I wanted so badly to move towards my goal so I took it anyway. The position was due to last four weeks. Can I prove that I've got some skill in that time? *Challenge accepted.*

From that moment forth, Stack Overflow played an invaluable role in my career. I had work to be done in areas that I'd never looked at before. The company initially wanted [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) and [Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access) skills, macros, [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications), SQL... to be honest it was intimidating. I had a technical background, a passion and some good ideas, but I just didn't have the knowledge to deliver. So I found myself trawling Google for information. *Hmmm... this Stack Overflow site is popping up a lot. I have got to bookmark that bad boy!* Literally any time I got stuck from that point onwards, I could count on Stack Overflow and its users to give me that nudge. That perfect example and explanation to back it up. This site is like the holy grail of development resources, man!!! I've stumbled onto a gold mine here.

I got offered a full time position after that internship. Things were looking up! The faith in the dream was reinvigorated and I once again I felt like I was on the right path! I continued to use the (now legendary) Stack Overflow and my own drive to produce the results that started to get me noticed. Suddenly I found myself in a world in which an IT developer position had become available within the business. I had an "in" and an impressive backlog of functioning solutions for the business. The only issue is that the IT team work with Windows technologies. [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC), [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), C#, [VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), [Web Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/what-is-web-forms), [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), etc. I don't have any experience in any of that stuff! **BUT WAIT!** Stack Overflow to the rescue once again!

The company agreed to give me a trial as an IT developer and in that time I had to evolve rapidly to learn so many things that were completely new to me. Stack Overflow's community changed everything for me. Made it all only a click away. This collaboration of knowledge pushed me to succeed. Needless to say, I got offered the IT developer job - and I'm still here today. I can't thank this site enough for everything it has done for me. I'm now part of the community I love so much. If I can give back even a fraction of what I got from it, that'll make me very happy indeed.

Thank you Stack Overflow **:-)**

Answer (score 5):

> I would define SO as a place where one will get **"Solution for any and every problem you can face while coding".**

Some people might not notice, but it had changed the way question and answer websites work. The time it takes for a good solution and the accuracy of the answers are truly astonishing. Whenever I search for any problems, I always look for an Stack Overflow link. May be it's the trust, that I would get a reliable, clear and complete solution. The answers are complete, even if some point is missing in some answer, others will extend their hand and fill in the gaps. It's sometimes enlightening to go through answers, and I end up smiling most of the times. :)

*Coming to the main topic, how did Stack Overflow help me?*

**Well, it helped me in everything.**

### Projects

> I have done a number of projects in my academic career, and I am still working on one. The amount of help I have taken from Stack Overflow is massive. Almost every project I had faced some issue, either with some programming construct, or the way the application was suppose to work. The surprising thing was, I never had to ask questions. I always got answered questions, to go through and help myself pick what I needed. I remember one project where I was struggling with the use of `ptrace()` and after a lot of searching I got the solution finally on Stack Overflow.

### How to answer

> When I started my master's degree, I got this zeal and passion to help people and answer their questions. May be because I started using SO a lot. Anyway, I started of by answering a few questions about C (because that was all I knew properly at that time), but somehow my answers faced some critics. In the beginning I didn't understand why it use to happen, but then I widened my gaze and tried to look properly. I understood where I was wrong, and to make people understand, you need a clear understanding of the language yourself. It encouraged me to take a step forward and understand things in a good way. It made me a better programmer, and definitely a good teacher. Now, I teach my classmates also sometimes if they face trouble.

### Collaborate and Help

> It happened in some questions only, but it was a different experience. Sometimes, when it so happened that questions were a little confusing, and there was a little confusion with the answers as well. That time it was a great experience to comment and communicate with users who have answered, and try to understand or improve the answer. It encourages new users (which I was a year back), and gives a comfortable atmosphere for contribution. I learned it on my journey and now I strive to do the same for other new users.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow did not change my programming career. It saved it!

I was starting my first job ever (still as student. I was there to learn, but...) and I was assigned to just read PHP documentation and learn it because they had no work to give me (I never used PHP before). Three days after, they told me that I was hired if I could solve an Android bug that they had been struggling with for a couple of weeks.

It was an Out Of Memory Exception. They were trying to take a picture, encoding it in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and send it through a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service. After a morning investigating it, I found this Stack Overflow question: *[Strange OutOfMemory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)* and that was just exactly what we needed, because uploading a 10 MB picture encoded in Base64 was just... horrible (Those were just profile pictures of a social network that would never be shown more than like 300x300 so having a 2800x2800 picture was pretty useless.)

I reduced the sample of the picture, so it would take just a little less than 1 MB and presented the solution to my boss. He was kind of impressed and hired me. It would not be the first time that Stack Overflow gives me the answer of whatever I ask for, but that one was life saving!

My salary was awful, but I got enough experience to go to my current place where I am so happy working as a programmer!

Answer (score 5):

Like many others, I think I was a non-contributing user of Stack Overflow. I didn't even have an account, and the site just always gave the answers I needed, not like many other sites who buried me under a lot of ads without actual any helpful information.

Almost two years ago, our company became more involved with Stack Exchange when we decided to profile ourselves better as 'subject experts' using our contributions to Stack Overflow.

Since then it went fast. First I had some trouble adjusting to the way Stack Overflow works, but when I got used to it, I really got addicted.

I have learned a lot from contributing and reading contributions of others. It really made me a better programmer. It learned me new techniques and technologies.

Now, we even use Stack Overflow as an input source for our job interviews. One of the first things we ask during the technical assessment is whether they contribute to Stack Overflow. It really gives a lot of insight. If new employees don't contribute yet, we encourage them to do so.

Answer (score 5):

At the end of 2010 I said goodbye to my monthly pay-check and instead became self-employed. In the years before that step I was full-time engaged in managing large projects that didn't leave any room to keep-up with what I love doing most: writing software.

In preparation of earning my own money I had to get up to speed with the new and latest technologies. During that self-learning process I stumbled across Stack Overflow. Having used several other sites before, the difference was striking. Not only did I find what I was looking for, I was also able to help others, sometimes by digging into my knowledge of *older* technologies.

The SO virus really grabbed me when I got access to the review queues. You know when you got into something if you feel bad for not using all the review task/votes allotted on a daily basis. I even got the hang of Meta and I contribute there as well.

If you told me 6 to 8 years ago that I would be active on a site that offers Imaginary Internet Points, Stinking Badges, Unicoins, Unicorns and Hats I probably would have laughed at you and make you feel ridiculous. I'm sorry for that, predicting the future is hard. I don't regret being part of this imaginary world, thank you for letting me in. Now let's close those 10,000,000 questions....

Answer (score 5):

Well long story short, I probably wouldn't still be a developer if I hadn't found Stack Overflow.

I don't have much of a formal education when it comes to development. A diploma course at a trade school that just taught the basics of development, but barely scratching the surface of anything significant, I remember graduating thinking that my success in school would have somewhat prepared me for the real world.

I was very, very wrong. I got lucky and landed a good job just out of school with a really small development team. It wasn't until I started working with experienced developers that I realized just how much I had overestimated my own skills. Every day was constantly a struggle to try and accomplish whatever task was assigned to me, limited to relying on Stack Overflow's evil counterpart and the ridiculously poor ASP.NET forums until finally sheepishly asking my co-workers for assistance for the 100th time that week. There was a point where I had seriously considered just quitting and finding another career path. I was clearly not ready to be doing this for a living.

That was until I found Stack Overflow. It had already been around for a few months and had an active community. A place where I didn't need to ask most of my beginner level questions because it already had answers to most of them. It also helped with my confidence, knowing that I wasn't the only one who had at some point ran into a certain issue. It quickly became my number one resource for my own personal development. Asking questions helped me out of several jams, but it was actually answering questions that really forced me to take a closer look into what I was doing.

6 years later and I'm still with the same company in a much more advanced role. I really have no idea where I would have ended up if not for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

School is hard. Especially when all your classes are 10 weeks and you have to sprint to get all your work done. I started computer science in college in 2010, and ever since then Stack Overflow has been there to help me understand all the new languages and concepts that I was introduced to.

When I first transferred schools, one of the first classes I had was called Advanced Programming Techniques. That's where we first learned how to use Linux (officially). I also learned some of the different programming languages that exist in the programming world. I went over languages like Python, Bash, Awk, C, C++, Java and a few others. The biggest problem was that I had to pick up a new language every week, and at first they all seemed to be very different and confusing. This is where Stack Overflow came in. I struggled so much rushing through all these languages and switching back and forth that they started to run together. Stack Overflow was able to help me wrap my brain around any new language that I had to learn. I was able to get answers to simple questions that other had asked before about quick syntax problems. Every time there was a new language I had to learn, I had a little bit of a head start because I could see some of the little nuances between then before we started in class.

A few years later I had a class specifically in programming languages. This is where I learned things like scheme, lisp, ML, haskell and even basic logic programming. Again I found myself in the same spot; trying to learn completely new syntax, rules and style. Like before Stack Overflow was there to help me understand.

During my years in school I have had to interview with a few companies for internships. A usual part of those interviews was a question: "What language do you use most often?" My answer to this question is usually along the lines of, "I can work with most of the popular languages out there and I can pick up any language your company works with." One of the places I interviewed with had asked me a follow-up question that I wasn't really ready for. He asked "What languages have you worked with in the past?" I had to think for a minute. the list was not a short one. I started listing all the ones that I had used in school and that Stack Overflow had helped with. About midway though the list the interviewer stopped me. "Have you really used all of these?" He sounded surprised. I told him that I had to learn them all for school and that I had used Stack Overflow to help understand some of them a bit more thoroughly. He offered me the internship a few days later.

Stack Overflow got me through these tough classes and even helped me understand the differences and similarities between all the languages. Now that I am about to graduate, I thank Stack Overflow for being able to help me understand what my professors were talking about, and for helping me start getting out into the real world. I feel that I have a deeper understanding of all the tools I have at my disposal.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow has helped me become a much better **mentor**. Since I started answering questions, I have become much better at:

1. Debugging other people's code
2. Explaining myself much more clearly
3. Having patience

Over the years, I have worked with quite a few junior developers and interns. Early on, I often found myself having to explain things more than once and in multiple ways. I often wondered to myself why I wasn't getting my point across. It wasn't until I joined Stack Overflow and started answering questions that I realized what the problem was. It was me! I wasn't good and describing the problem and solution effectively.

I attribute this to the fact that on Stack Overflow I had to type out my thoughts rather than express them through spoken word. And not only that, but I had to do so without writing an entire book! It taught me to be **concise**, which at the same time also taught me to truly understand the problem!

Many people have heard or seen this quote:

> If you can't understand something simply, you don't understand it well enough.

[Who said it](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8742/28758) may be up for discussion, but regardless, it was true for me. Stack Overflow helped me realize that in order to be a better mentor, I had a lot to work on. To this day, I still find myself not being the best mentor, but I'm definitely better than before!

Answer (score 4):

I can't begin to enumerate the ways SO has helped me as a programmer and a professional; it taught me that I don't know everything (which is a tough lesson to learn, especially when you're 18 and top of your class in CS), it taught me that I shouldn't be upset about not knowing everything because nobody else does either, it taught me to ask myself hard questions about the code I was writing, it taught me that being a jerk to people smarter than me was no way to go about getting smarter myself, and it continues to teach me new things every single day.

Probably the most important way SO has helped me *generally* is that it taught me how to **research**; I don't want to spend time writing up a question just to have it flagged as a dupe because I didn't do enough research.  This has been hugely helpful both in my personal programming endeavors and my professional career (I mean, the word **research** is right there in my job title).

I guess if I had to pick a specific instance, it would be [a question I found yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) about how to write a proper benchmark in Java.  See, I have been having issues with a [particular problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527639/performance-of-visitor-pattern-vs-reflective-invocation) for a while now, and I thought I had come up with a very effective solution without compromising performance, but the best I could come up with was "this should perform better than what I had before".  The benchmarking question really helped me to figure out whether and why I was seeing performance bottlenecks, and sure enough: my independent research into the problem had lead me to an effective solution that perfectly fits my needs.

Answer (score 4):

Its been 2 years now, since I've started frequenting SO on a daily basis. As a programmer, the access to knowledge base I had earlier was limited. Learning not so hard things can sometimes make you feel that you know a lot of things. Thanks to SO, I was able to burst that bubble I used to live in.

I now know my limits a lot better, that I can go a lot farther, that I can learn more in an year or in a month than what I thought I could, and that becoming a better me is a constant process.

There have been many users, who've inspired me to become better at what I do - be it [@Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) answering on Python, [@daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) answering on Django, [@Jörg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%C3%B6rg-w-mittag) answering on Rails, [@mysticial](http://Mysticial) answering algorithms, [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) answering on version control, or [@Ingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat) answering on vim. So many experts, all in one place, the whole environment has allowed me to learn on multiple fronts at very fast speed. There are many many many more experts who contribute in various capacities here, a lot of whose answers and conversations have helped me increase my knowledge base over the past 2 years

Through the exposure at Stack Overflow, I also started visiting other SE sites - Programmers, Server Fault, workplace, and many others, and the amount of quality content, advice and solutions I've found have only helped me broaden my perspective and grow even further as a person. The SO meta (which I've started visiting only a lot more recently) has made me appreciate how helpful the SO community.

Stack has taught me the meaning of humility, the importance of communication, what learning actually means and a lot many other good lessons that I hope I can remember for life.

I've a fair amount of rep now, and I get constant recognition from friends, peers, potential employers and recruiters all the time, but that is only a trivial bonus compared to how SO has helped me in other ways.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: Stackoverflow showed me that I am not as stupid as I thought at the beginning of my career.

During university I had many doubts about my abilities as a software developer. I had a hard time understanding algorithms. I was not very good at math. And I had to look up the simplest things constantly. I really felt like this was way to hard. But the code I wrote usually worked, so it couldn't be that bad.
But the impression of not being fit for the job just got worse when I started to work on a side job, with a tiny embedded software company that was overwhelmed with projects and only employed two top-notch developers. Since I was playing in my free-time with similar things, they asked me if I want to work for them.
Which I did. But soon I realized that I'm not fit for that job. Their code worked on first try (it seemed). I was still fixing bugs a week after the deadline. I never consciously realized that they had at least a decade more experience than myself. I thought that everyone expects me to do the same work in the same time, with the same results.

I missed deadlines left and right, my code contained dozen of bugs. In hindsight I probably did reasonable well. It was just completely stupid to give me the sole responsibility for a project. And I was stupid to not admit that I need help. I was always (and probably still am) too proud to admit that I am overwhelmed with doing something alone.
I never consciously realized that I just had a few months "experience", and they were doing these things for years. So after a couple months I quit that job. And I quit university as well. Or lets say I switched from computer science to electrical engineering (which I later quit ;).
Programming was still something I was very interested in, so I continued to play around in my freetime. And I made a few small custom projects for small businesses, as a self-employed developer. No boss, no coworkers, just me, the code and some embedded hardware thing. But I never felt that the work I did was very useful. The feeling of doing mediocre work was always there.

And then someone showed me an iPhone, must have been around 2009/2010, until then I was never interested in that Apple crap, Linux all the way. But I fell in love with it, and I wanted to make an app for that thing. As smooth as the apps I saw. Until then I was working primarily with embedded software. Where the user interface are a bunch of buttons and a 7 segment display. So iPhone was something new, exciting and very different.
Anyway, I started to learn iPhone programming. And then I learned some more and then I bought another book and learned some more. Soon I was very good at following tutorials for beginners. After months of wasting time with learning stuff I already knew, I actually started my first real project. During that time I discovered stackoverflow, not sure why I never stumbled upon it earlier. Once I found it, it basically had answers to almost all questions I had. Sometimes I found a question that didn't have an answer. In that case I was a little bit disappointed and I continued to search for a solution. That's what I did for a couple months.

One day I thought I should answer a question myself. So I did. And then I answered another one. And another one. According to my profile I answered 7 questions the first day. 3 on my second. 13 on my third, and 14 on my fourth day at stackoverflow. And holy ship. My advice was actually useful for people. They thanked me for helping them. And they upvoted my answers. Sometimes I actually guessed the solution to incomplete questions.

That's when I realized that I actually know what I'm doing, that I'm good at diagnosing problems and finding solutions.

Helping people on stackoverflow really boosted my confidence about my developer skills. And seeing that people who are professional developers have questions as well, really helped to get rid of the feeling that I'm a lesser developer. I sometimes found (already answered) questions of people well known in the community, and I thought that I could answer this.

Now, 1256 answers later, all doubts about my skills are gone. Turns out I am actually a very good software developer.

Answer (score 4):

I am a self-taught programmer and, like many self-taught programmers, I lacked understanding of even the importance of things like architecture, patterns and good practice, let alone the details.

This issue was compounded by the fact that I started my career in a backwater company with two other self-taught developers, neither of whom was any more knowledgeable than I was.

I stayed there for six years. Why wouldn't I? The work was easy, and we all had a great time congratulating one another on how awesome we were because none of us knew any better.

So on paper, I looked like a hell of a lot better developer than I actually was.

When I did eventually leave, I went to another small company with two other developers. They were both very good, and had built a system I could barely understand. Then they both announced their intention to leave. Then my wife had a baby two months early.

When I got back to my job, I found myself the sole developer on a system beyond my comprehension with no documentation and no handover whatsoever, working under a tyrannical boss who wanted results yesterday.

What could I do? Ask stack overflow. My opening shot is still one my best-rated questions on the site: [Getting up to speed on modern architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644290/getting-up-to-speed-on-modern-architecture)

I did what people said. I read the books. Scoured the forums. Asked more questions. Got answers.

I got fired from that job, and rightly so because I wasn't competent enough to deal with the day to day demands of the role, especially as what was ostensibly a development lead.

But I'd learned a lot. From you. All of you. Enough to prepare me for a middleweight job in a proper software house.

Now, five years and two more jobs on, I'm acting as the Technical Architect for a company of eighty people. I've been been happier or more productive. Cowboy Coder to Architect in five years feels like one hell of a sprint: and it's all thanks to Stack Overflow.

Thank you.

Comment: Inspiring!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

## Learning and Recruiting - two aspects where Stack Overflow has helped me

I think it's futile trying to list all of the ways that Stack Overflow has helped me in my professional career - it is without doubt the most important website for finding information on programming topics. It's usually the first site in any of my programming-related Google searches (it's strange that I still search through Google, even though I know that I'll find an answer here). I'll try to describe the importance from two different angles (in addition to the general helpfulness for finding answers).

### Learning a new technology

When learning a new technology or tool, I find that following a tag on Stack Overflow is a great way of getting hands-on information. I've used this several times (e.g. with [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) or with [AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)), where every morning I for several weeks, I spent a couple of minutes on browsing through the latest questions and answers for that tag. Even if I couldn't answer any of them initially, it gave me a good impression on what functionality is out there, what some of the common problems are, and how other people (hopefully with more experience than I) solve them.

Doing this for a couple of days or weeks slowly builds up familiarity with the topic, and often leads to new ways of doing things. On a regular basis, I found new patterns, scripts or clever ways of solving problems, and I was able to apply them to my daily work. In addition to that, it raised awareness on how to ask questions. What is the required information, how to present examples, how not to ask a question - these are all things I learned through browsing of the most recent questions and answers.

### Recruiting

Since I do a lot of job interviews for open positions in my team, I try to find out how people go about solving problems - since that is one of the most important skills in software development. In addition to asking questions about how they solved specific problems in their current or previous job, I've added two very simple questions to my standard set:

- Do you know the website GitHub.com and can you explain what it does?
- Do you know the website StackOverflow.com and can you explain what it does?

If people are aware of these sites, I follow up with questions on how they use these sites, i.e. whether they have an account, whether they participate actively, whether they upvote/ask/answer.

Believe it or not, but there are still developers out there who are not familiar with StackOverflow. This does not disqualify someone from getting an offer, but familiarity with the site and how it works is a plus in my book.

Answer (score 4):

For a long time I used Stack Overflow just to look up answers - I didn't even have an account, because I never found that I needed to ask something new. While I learnt plenty of things along the way, I've gotten a lot more out of the site since I signed up and started writing answers of my own.

I often used to feel that one of my weak points professionally was that I struggled to communicate my work to others. I had always been stronger at written communication than spoken. I was an application developer for years, but I was essentially self-taught; most things that I knew I had picked up on the job as I needed them. I didn't always know the right terminology, sometimes I only knew concepts from the perspective of one language (usually [vb6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6), unfortunately), and the problem was self-perpetuating because as a result of it I tended to lack the confidence to speak up. I worried that people would constantly underestimate me because I couldn't get across what I knew or confidently explain how I planned to tackle a piece of work. I would have valuable ideas which I couldn't explain to people, causing them to be overlooked.

While there have been other experiences that helped me along - general work experience, a change of role into business intelligence & data warehousing, carrying out coursework for my masters degree, etc. - I have found that answering questions on SO has been hugely beneficial when it comes to both improving my technical and conceptual communication skills, as well as improving my confidence about my knowledge and my ability to communicate it.

I'm starting a new job very soon; I found interviewing a surprisingly easy process to say I used to struggle to put a lot of my technical and conceptual knowledge into words. At interviews, I found myself speaking about concepts and patterns that I have written about here, and which I probably would have never before explained to another person if it weren't for SO. Having practiced putting these ideas into words in my preferred format and at my own pace, I was far more prepared for a verbal discussion about them - both in terms of having the words ready, and in terms of my confidence about what I had to say.

I am also learning - bit by bit - how to teach people. I now look forward to having a role where I can coach others, and I'm considering starting up a blog to document and share useful and interesting things I come across in my field, and ideas I have that other people might find helpful. Who

For me, SO has been - and I'm sure will continue to be - an invaluable learning tool.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Through Stack Overflow, I realized the difference between *writing code* and *programming*. I came to know about the existence of *actual* [`C` standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)), the definition and the differences among the [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), [unspecified behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior) and [implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) and how to write code that make good use of the defined standard of the `C` language. Also, I came to know how following a good coding standard turns an ordinary piece of code to a *production level* one. Overall, I am a better programmer now, thanks to the knowledge shared by and gathered from Stack Overflow.

In a nutshell, I came to know the difference between

```
int main()
```

and

```
int main(void)
```

and most importantly, *why* the difference is there and the applicability of either of them. (*Pardon me if the above example is too `C`-ish*)

To tell the long story, I stated my career as a system software engineer and I was not very comfortable with `C`. Like most of the fellow newbies, my knowledge was limited to certain books which was *recommended* in my academics. After stepping into the professional world, I felt, the knowledge gathered from the book is not *enough* to excel in this field. I needed to do something more.

There came the cavalry, Stack Overflow. I became a regular (the initiation story [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303169/2173917)) on Stack Overflow, and it helped me learn not only the ***how to*** of coding, but also the ***why to*** part.

I learnt and realized, *almost* nothing is taken for granted. There **is** a reason behind each and every syntax and semantics. I stopped learning `C` by trial-and-error, and rather I started careful study of the language and today, I have learnt <del>a lot</del> at least the basics of `C`.

Just to reflect the outcome, currently, in my organization, I'm a part of the team for algorithm design/optimization and code review for the production release, alongside with my assigned activities. Also, I do mentor a batch of freshmen. Really, a great transformation for me in a short period and cordially, this would not have been possible without the knowledge I gathered from the quality Q&As present on Stack Overflow.

If I may, thanks to one and all, who helped me grow, personally and professionally. All of us together, let's make us better.

---

P.S - If I don't mention how Stack Overflow helped me to accept constructive criticism, this post would be incomplete. I developed a positive mentality of *digging into* a seemingly complete solution (answer) and find out the (possible) finer side of it. Always there is a chance for improvement, (let me) go for it.

Answer (score 3):

I was a self-taught programmer in several different languages, which can make it hard when you go to do a project, and you realize you don't know how to use certain commonly-known functions or methods because you never learned them.

I didn't know about basic things like Dictionaries (or HashMaps in some languages), Lists, or foreach statements for the first few years I did programming. Eventually I knew there had to be a better way to handle stuff like

- Handling key-value pairs, then keeping two arrays, one holding the keys, and the other holding values at the same index.
- Constantly creating new arrays to handle lists of data that would re-size,
- Struggling along with trying to solve and not understanding basic errors (at the time I didn't use Google), like NullPointerExceptions, or ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

I knew there were better ways, but I just didn't know what they were, or what to look for.

I realized there had to be an easier way to find answers for this stuff, otherwise other programmers would probably be driven insane by the issues.

That's when I realized I could probably look up my errors with Google. I started looking them up, and then my projects started progressing a whole lot faster!

Then I found a site called "Stack Overflow" (you should really check it out if you haven't), and it was like a dream come true! A place where I could ask questions about any programming language and get a really fast response. A place where I wouldn't be judged for bad past questions or forum posts (I had that happen in a couple of communities for specific programming languages). It really helped me to excel in what I know and love :)

Now I'm working as a professional programmer and consultant on a large-scale project, and I probably wouldn't be where I was today if it wasn't for the friendly Stack Overflow community.

Thanks everyone who's helping make Stack Overflow such a great and inspirational place!

Answer (score 3):

I made my first steps on the world of programming in 2011, when I joined a web design and programming 2-year degree, and I was completely lost.
I mean, I wasn't bad at all, but some PHP concepts entered backwards in my brain, and that's when, recommended by our teacher, I started lurking on Stack Overflow.

The amount of info and help I found here was enough to create an amazing final project, DevRep (never released, a software repository for independent developers), and you (the community) also helped me a lot to understand the grasps of ASP.NET, which I was required to use in the project, but where our .NET teacher wasn't really good, he didn't even understand his own questions!

I got a fancy 8.5/10 on my final project and decided to keep in the programming world, signed in for another 2-year degree (that time in multi-platform systems), registered on Stack Overflow (lost my account, was made with the old school email), and there the community helped me understand the concept of object-oriented languages, inheritance, and why Android Studio dislikes us all.

I have to say that I'm what I am thanks to both my teachers and this amazing community, and both have taught me to always keep trying, to make myself able to find my own answers thanks to a quick search rather than always asking first, and that's what got me the cool job I have as an Android and iOS developer!

Thank you all for you time, and I hope we all get cool T-shirts.

Answer (score 3):

***Help*** is a very kind word but truly StackOverflow drastically changed me.

Joining the StackOverflow was just a coincidence. I never knew that the site which has one up arrow and one down arrow in every question and answer can change me. In my 3nd year of graduation while I was just using internet as a young guy *(NOTE: I'm still young :D )* or more clearly as a newbie I was looking for the use of `continue;` in Java, just because teacher had given us few problems to solve with Java programming language. My curiosity made me to click on the upvote button and I signed up on this site till then I had never heard about this site (I'm serious.).So, this is how I linked up in this site but still my mind was completely unaware about the community *who* is running this site from last few years and will do the same for many more years.

Several months I had used this account just to read the required answers of the problems given by our Java teacher. Look how foolish I was I never asked any question on StackOverflow in those months if I did I could have changed my self earlier. Never mind the day had come when I noticed on Ask Question button (see how blind I was), I asked my first question and get a very quick answer, quick, *really* quick at least for me and apart from that few *green* reputation and moreover some suggestions. The few minutes after asking this question were like some hidden *heroes* are rescuing me from dark tunnel where I would have lost my self. *I had never experienced this before.* Yes believe it or not it was exactly the same that time. I didn't care about the reputation and generally new users don't care about it. I even didn't know what reputation was and silently without uttering a word I got my answer. That was fantastic at least for me.

> StackOverflow **help**ed me to **help** others and **help**ed me to get **help** from others. See, how **help**ful it is.

I kept finding answers of my questions and I got very good grades in Java Programming thanks to StackOverflow I still remember I read about few points which includes difference between stop and run in thread, convert integer to String in Java, dynamic dispatch in Java and so on. In mean time I did never answer any question because I thought I can not. One day when I open StackOverflow I found one question where a newbie like me was asking about LinkList or something I still remember that (see how StackOverflow increases your memory) it was my first answer not quite an answer but an attempt that increased my confidence up to some level that yes I can answer at least try to share something what I know with others who don't know about it. I started answering on stack overflow.

My first interview. Nervous as usual.

> - **First question  :** What is immutability in Java ? I stunned.. I said I
>     have no clue regarding this.
> - **Second question :** What is OOP ?  I tried
>     to answer.
>     ... and some more difficult questions

I didn't clear my first interview because I was not able to provide such level of expertise they wanted. After graduation I was jobless for few months approximately 8 months during these months I was totally depressed. I had tried in many small big companies but didn't clear the Java technical round. I was looking for a Job. These months I was not there on StackOverflow. One day somehow I reached again on this site don't know what happened I started preparing for interview in between I started answering questions which are based on some other answers of StackOverflow (Usually this is what new user do). When I started answering I tried my level best. I didn't know this answers were actually helping me to improve my self. I made lot of mistakes on Stackoverflow but still it's with me to help me on every point.

> Stackoverflow has become Google for programmers.

I got a call for an interview of Java fresher.

> - **First Question  :** What is an Object in OOP ?
> - ***My Answer***     : Object is a heart of Object Oriented programming where everything is an Object. OOP is totally based on an Object it starts with an Object and ends with Object. There are lot of languages are there which are based on OOP including Java........
> - **Second Question :** Can we create constant in Java ?
>     How ?
> - ***My Answer***     : Absolutely, we can create a constant in Java and
>     for that we have to declare it `static` and `final`.
>     
>   **...**

I cleared it although didn't nail it but I proved my self at least. So, ultimately SO helped me to become a programmer who is now working in a company from the guy who was not able to code and who was not getting any job. I can't say I have learned a lot then I would be lying I have learned few thing from the lot of things which are there on StackOverflow. Thanks to StackOverflow I am able to interact with the people like me. Now please read the first statement of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

So this post is not really about jobs and careers, but I hope you catch the humanity behind. I'm 24 and have been away from programming for the first 23 years of my life.

One year ago I was in the process of graduating with a degree in Environmental Engineering. During the whole course (5 years here) I had very little contacts with programming that didn't trigger anything in me.

My first android phone gently did, as digging in the store was just revealing more and more disfunctional, bad-looking applications. I hesitantly said "let's try myself". First days were hard and, totally stuck, I was not even walking up that learning curve.

**StackOverflow** eventually did trigger my passion and made me think "I can do it". I don't know how many of you can relate to this feeling - growing up (old) away from anything programming-related and then getting in or, better, realizing to be in. One often thinks, from outside, that programming is a sort of exclusive field you don't enter as you wish. Intuition, versatility, enthusiasm do not look to be enough, from outside at least. I now know that *help* can be the missing piece.

Today I'm half the worst programmer here, but I'm learning, and, beyond having graduated, I'm in the process of publishing an ambitious application. **StackOverflow** didn't help me as a programmer, as the question states
 - it *made me* (feel like?) a programmer, and I'm really grateful for that.

However that's not the most important thing for me. **StackOverflow**:

- made more confident about my capabilities, by helping me along the way;
- made me improve and constantly train my English skills;
- made me feel a very little, but not useless, part of a community;
- gave me a place where I feel understood. I grew up shy and hesitant and, when talking, often feel the fear of
  being misunderstood, misjudged, misinterpreted. I don't have that feeling here (thanks also to the topics I guess),
  and this makes it a really pleasant, though virtual, place to stay.
- made me discover wonderful sibling SE sites, in which I don't actively partecipate but which I longly read and enjoy;
- gave me hope for a second job, in case my E.E. degree won't bring me anywhere, thus helping with my career.

Answer (score 3):

**Mostly self-taught developer picking up a new language and framework every couple of months -- what does that lead to? Needing help along the way!**

I took a few computer science courses in college and one of them required learning three.js, a WebGL Javascript library, to render 3D visualization of anatomical structures. I had [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995050/how-can-i-import-my-object-with-its-inherent-textures-from-blender-to-threejs). This was my first time getting my hands "dirty" with my own coding project. I had so, so many questions about how to use an open source library and how best to take advantage of the sample problems. When I played around with the library, I had a few questions and three.js back then was relatively new! There were few sample projects but nothing of the scope of it today.

From that moment, I realized how powerful StackOverflow is and how thankful I am for the community here.

I was able to get a job starting out a tester but worked my way up to a software developer quickly since manual testing was absolutely tedious (and I was writing unit tests for fun). I was excited to become a developer but also absolutely mortified to be writing production level code! *My Project Manager told me that he knew I learned C++ in college and that C# would be the same thing*! Little did I know that was hardly true, so I had to learn C# on top of ASP.NET MVC! I ran through online tutorials which helped, sure, but I started to get my real questions when I was assigned the tasks. Some scenarios were complicated for a newbie and I needed guidance or info but I was too daunted to inform my coworkers or PM that I had questions! I thought I had to know everything about software development...to be a software developer.

So, I turned to the anonymous online community where questions are encouraged! I've had sooo much help. I've asked sooo many questions, I've answered my own questions, I've learned from other people's answers, and I go on chatrooms for quick concept questions to be sure I'm in the right direction. Or just to hang out with the awesome community members. I love to hear other people's stories and I'm so thankful for all the contributers!

Often I tell myself I would be homeless if it wasn't for SO! THANK YOU!

SO has taught me:

- C#
- ASP.NET MVC
- WPF
- Android
- Kendo UI
- JavaScript (and it's really, really weird constructs)

Who knows what is next in store?

Answer (score 3):

> I have started working in Android since 2010. At that time there were less sources on
>   internet but I learnt many things from StackOverFlow. I have always
>   got solution instantly from StackOverFlow comparing to another blog or
>   site. ChatRoom of StackOverFlow is really great tool for chat with
>   other technical person and help to each-other , I 
>   participate in ChatRoom as well. Always I try to help others. I have never
>   seen any blog or forum like StackOverFlow.

**Story :**

> We always work on clients based projects. If something is not
>   feasible then we must have to give proof. Once, there was one functionality
>   which was not feasible in my android project. I did a lot of search on google and I
>   didn't find any solution so I told to my project manager and he
>   agreed with me but client didn't. So I posted my query on
>   StackOverFlow and sent link to the client. Then only the client agreed with us.
>   In short client always believe on StackOverflow answer.

[Here is that question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244472/how-to-add-an-image-in-email-body)

Thanks to StackOverFlow Team.

Answer (score 3):

### How StackOverflow changed my career

I work in a software house that use a proprietary language, and I work with it for 6 years. I build desktop apps and the only web experience that I have was with a classic ASP chat at the high school (oh dear...how time is passed!).

One day my boss tell me that he want to start a new web project and want to include me, I said that I'm a bit inexperienced, and the answer was "Study and check on internet".

I checked on Google some general questions and I landed here...wow what amount of knowledge and wisdom.

So I have started to follow some tutotials about ASP.NET and javascript/jQuery and in the meanwhile answering questions about this tags here, and the questions are accepted and upvoted (hurray, I'm understanding what I'm studying).

After a few years, my boss see that I'm really involved on web technologies and active on StackOverflow, and ask me to become the technical lead of web projects. Great, I'll keep studying and answering here on StackOverflow, I learn a lot and I'm becoming better on English language (I'm Italian).

Two years ago an MVP mail me to ask if he can use one of my answers (on SO) on a book that is writing, I accept and he told me if I want to collabarote and the book, yes, great!

The more time I pass here the more thing I learn, thanks StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow has been my absolute go-to for years as I learned how to program. I could always come here and find the answer to all my newbie questions, already asked and answered.  It wasn't until I got more experienced and started coming across more complex problems that I actually joined.

I've always been terrible at asking for help. I like to figure things out on my own, but sometimes I get stuck. If I've been spinning my wheels for a few days, trying everything google turns up with no luck, I come here. I never cease to be amazed at how quickly someone helps me. I'm usually given pointers or an answer within an hour or two. People will work with me to narrow down my problem and find the flaw in my approach. They come up with elegant solutions that I never even remotely thought of.

I've started trying to answer questions. I like the puzzle and hope I can be helpful. Although I will admit I usually get schooled by another user who comes up with a much better solution. That being said, it's a great way to learn and I'd like to think it's making me a better programmer.

Answer (score 3):

Let me start with a tweet I posted some weeks ago:
"#SOreadytohelp Because there's always at least 1 person in the world that has the solution to your crazy idea! "

Stack Overflow can be divided in two large areas in my opinion: either you have a problem that others have had in the past as well, and you can just read about how they found their solution **or** you have a problem that is so bizarre and unique, that nobody posted about it before and... Someone will actually have the solution for your insane problem.

I'm a programmer, but a part of my time at work is dedicated to improving my coding skills, and Stack Overflow is an amazing place to improve yourself: I check the new questions of my favourite tags and see if I can answer them. If I can't answer them, but the questions are interesting, I follow them up, so I learn new methods and concepts. I'm at that point that I got a special bookmark-folder filled with interesting concepts and ideas for potential upcoming projects.

*But exactly how did Stack Overflow help me, you ask?* The community explains things. It doesn't give you a black box solution and move along. No, it explains why your solution doesn't work, and how you can adapt your solution to make it work. When stuck on a problem, you just know that, after checking Stack Overflow, you'll have the solution for your problem, but also that you will **know** why your problem was a problem in the first place. Which, in turn, will help you next time to avoid that situation.

Answer (score 3):

When I took over my current position, it was not a smooth transition.  I had been at the bottom rung, a true junior level developer.  Then all at once the landscape changed.  Two senior developers left the company for other jobs and one, who had been sick, passed away.

And...this all happened as we were in the latter stages of a complete rewrite of the software from C++/Win32 into a pure C# .NET platform.  Huge learning curves for everyone.  Suddenly, the vast majority of that newly acquired knowledge was gone.

To say that Stack Overflow has helped me a great deal would still be to pitifully understate the matter.  Users of this site are simply incredible.  The amount of knowledge I see in the list on any given day is staggering.  In my mind, I picture the Ghostbusters containment unit when I think about the server that has to hold all those questions and answers.

[image]

From C++, to C#, to SQL, to HTML and CSS...I have always been able to find, or ask for, an answer on Stack Overflow.  It is, by far, my most trusted and reliable resource for the information I need to do my job effectively.

Comment: So is that what you put on your [xkcd survey](http://xkcd.com/1572/)?

Answer (score 3):

## Stack Overflow Saved my Study Abroad Year

I had just finished my first year of studing Computing at university. At this point I didn't even know what SO was. For my second year of study, I decided to study abroad in America (I'm from England). I was super excited and did not know what to expect. When I had to enroll in classes, I faced some difficulty. I was not used to this process becuase in England, our classes are assigned to us and we don't get much of a say in the matter. Having to make this decision *prior* to leaving the country was difficult as I had nobody to talk to really for any guidance regarding which classes are suitable for me. I tried to make a decision based on the classes I had just taken and my teachers here also made some recommendations based on the class names.

Unfortunately the class choices were all wrong as I ended up joining classes meant for students with **far** more programming experience than I had (some of my classes were meant for Juniors and Seniors). The reason I could get into these classes is because all of the prerequisites for study abroad students are waived as they don't know what I've done back in England so they assume I'm choosing suitable classes. I had a really hard time keeping up. Almost everything they were saying was going over my head. I was so upset as I was absolutely clueless in everyone of my classes and what made it worse is that I knew that that year was supposed to be the best year of my life!

I was doing **a lot** of extra studying to catch up and most of this studying ended up coming from SO. Without this website I am *certain* that I would have failed my classes that year. When I had questions outside of class, this website always provided the answer. Due to SO I was able to get through homework assignments, lab tasks, exams and ultimately my study abroad year! Things got easier as the year went on and I've been using this site ever since! I went from being an absolutely clueless novice programmer, to finishing top of my class the next year back in England (due to all the extra studying I was doing). I then graduated with a First class degree (4.0 GPA) and immediately got a job as a software engineer where I am working now!

*Thanks a lot Stack Overflow!*

Answer (score 3):

## **Stack Overflow has helped fuel and turn my dream of becoming a programmer into a reality.**

I first discovered Stack Overflow shortly after I decided to develop my first iPhone application, [uFeel](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/ufeel-mood-finger-scanner/id432169227?mt=8&at=1l3vm3h), in early 2011. Equipped with only an informal introduction to the subject, courtesy of [thenewboston](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL53038489615793F7), and no previous programming experience, besides some minor CSS I had written for message board users on IGN, I tackled the daunting task of developing my first real program. It didn’t take long until my console was overrun by countless errors, and what do we do when we encounter an error/problem we can’t solve? Google it of course. Numerous times Stack Overflow was the place I found the answer to my problems. Stack Overflow didn’t just answer the problems though, the answers, more times than not, also explained why these problems were occurring and helped me learn how to handle and avoid them, expanding my knowledge immensely. Two head scratching and Stack Overflow searching months later, I had finished my first application and published it on the App Store. Ever since that day I have been hooked not only on programming, but also on Stack Overflow.

Since then I have released an additional 23, [rather silly](http://zeroviews.net/), applications to the App Store and finally feel like I have a solid grasp on what I’m actually doing when I sit down with an idea I plan on developing. I often tell people I’m a self taught programmer when they ask me how I learned to program, but I owe this confidence and ability to Stack Overflow and its many helpful, knowledgeable, and inspiring users.

Answer (score 3):

My first full-time programming job was as an intern writing VB code. I had almost never seen/used any VB code up until that point. The first couple of days I had no internet access (*government jobs, sheesh*), but somewhere around the start of my internship I signed up for Stack Overflow. That was 5 years ago. During my internship I asked and answered a *lot* of questions - especially in the Python tag.

Practically speaking, I was able to get answers to my questions about VB, and Python, and eventually other languages and topics throughout my college and professional career, but what StackOverflow really did to help me was that it provided a space where I could practice my writing skills and answer questions. As everyone here knows, teaching other people is one of the best ways to learn, and with every question that I've answered, I learn a little bit more and a little bit more. Many times when people asked a question I *had no clue what the answer was when I read it.* The very process of researching the answer for another person and crafting a reply that was designed for the Maximum Internet Points™ helped me develop my skills and understanding more than asking my own questions has.

I strongly suspect that I would not have grown as much/as quick as a developer without StackOverflow.

(also it introduced me to Markdown, which is flippin' awesome, so there's that)

Answer (score 3):

I have been using Stack Overflow in one form or another for three or four years. The specific story I'm thinking of happened roughly a year and a half ago.

I was tasked with rewriting the login system and security for my company's website. Being relatively new to the web developer field, and being the only web developer in my company's employ, I needed to learn how to properly do it, as well as how to actually implement it. That's where Stack Overflow came in.

I knew obvious things, such as storing passwords in plain text is bad (that was why our security needed rewriting in the first place) as well as password storage should not be reversible. However, if left to my own knowledge, I would have been just using an `md5` hash and left it at that. Fortunately, thanks to Stack Overflow, I quickly learned that `md5` is broken, and that the best kind of hashing algorithms implement slowness as well as complexity. After extensive reading of question and answers, I settled on using Bcrypt for the hashing of passwords.

Also, through Stack Overflow, and Security SE, I learned various practices to prevent other threats, such as never emailing a user their password, throttling login times based on the number of times a user has tried to log in, allowing a way for a user to remove a lock on their account, either by calling, or changing their password. I was able to learn about password strength requirements and issues with such requirements. I also learned to implement a temporary, one time use link in order to reset passwords, in order to help protect against traffic sniffing and the like, as well as forcing connections to https. I started the project being 'newb' at website security, and ended it feeling like I have come leaps and bounds in my knowledge on the topic.

Along the way, I learned many, many, many, MANY times over that using the `mysql_*` functions in PHP is a bad practice, due to those functions being deprecated, and moved away from using those as well.

All in all, Stack Overflow has improved my skills as a developer, and although I don't have much rep, I try to give back where I can, even if it's something small, like an edit, or a flag as needed.

Thank you Stack Overflow, and here's to ten million more questions.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Stack Overflow for about 3 years, I don't really know. I found about it because every single time I searched a Java question the first result Google gave me was Stack Overflow. After some time I decided to make an account to be able to comment, upvote and lots more. Then it started.

I found out how amazing Stack Overflow is that I decided to contribute to it too. I thought that there are so many new questions that there must be something I can answer. Then I saw the option to see the latest questions tagged "android" or "java" (what I know the best).

I didn't even realize how I got 80 rep in less than a couple of days. Next day I logged in: +30 rep. How did I get that? Oh look, my old question has so many views and an upvote! Look at that answer! It got accepted and 3 votes! And like that I saw how useful my answers but even questions were, as people didn't have to ask and wait for an answer.

Now this was the past. Right now I have 541 rep and find this out. Not only for the competition, but after I wrote the first few words, I felt like I have to write this. Also when I visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) page I realised how much Stack Overflow helps people!

I thank you for making this amazing site and helping me out every time I had a problem. Ok, let's forget my fail questions where I posted the project zip instead of code and no logs, or when my question had -10 downvotes and I had to delete it :)

```
═✿✿✿═════✿✿═══✿✿═════✿✿✿═
════════════ (\../) ═════════════
════════════ ( ◕.◕) ═════════════
════════════ (,)(,) ═════════════
▀█▀.█▄█.█▀█.█▄.█.█▄▀.-█▄█.█▀█.█─█
.█.─█▀█.█▀█.█.▀█.█▀▄-.-█.─█▄█.█▄█
```

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow has helped me in many different ways. It has helped me to figure out solutions to obscure exceptions; it has helped me to find a community of people with similar experiences; and it has helped me to find a place to share some of my experience with other people who are trying to get things done.

Before I was a user of Stack Overflow, I was a user of Stack Overflow. I just didn't know it. When I first graduated and took a position developing I was implementing an asp.net mvc 3 solution. At the time it was pretty cutting edge, and there was only 1 book out on the topic. Every time I came across a hurdle, I would search on google to try to find information. Most times I found that information at Stack Overflow which back then to me just seemed like another forum (I know, its not, but in 2010 that was my first impression). Eventually I came to have a lot of respect for the Question and Answer design Stack Overflow used. This respect came from a proven history of containing the information that on a daily basis was helping me move past places when I got stuck. Prior to this, I would always have to email someone, buy a book, or just grind it out so it really saved me a lot of time - and it still does.

However, just having a place to search for the answer to all my problems wasn't the end of what Stack Overflow did for me. It also gave me a place to interact with millions of other developers. I have been to some large conferences over the years, but none of them compare to the level of interaction available at Stack Overflow. One of the few places I discovered here to interact was in chat. Having the "rooms" separated by programming language allowed me at first to go to specific places when I was having a related issue, but the C# room in particular stood out to me because it also covered asp.net in general. None of the people I know in my own private life are developers who also use the asp.net mvc framework. In the C# chat room I found a place that I could converse about that type of technology on a daily basis and it has been not only informative but very fun. It was something that I didn't know I would have liked to take part in, but definitely enjoy. So far I have posted about 50,000 messages to that room and am one of the "owners". Feel free to stop by! :)

Over the years I have become very acquainted with various nuances of developing software, specifically in the full stack asp.net mvc environment (c#, MSSQL, razor, JavaScript, css, html) and that can be seen in my activity. I have a gold tag badge in JavaScript and have posted over 1500 answers altogether. My whole life I have enjoyed helping other people with finding solutions to problems. In general, I like solving problems so if helping someone else also means I get to solve something then count me in. Stack Overflow merely amplified this ability by allowing me to help someone 24/7/365. Literally, I could go help someone right now and for every minute of the rest of the day. Which is awesome, and also requires a little bit of restraint because we all need some of those minutes to ourselves.

All in all, I love this place. I feel like it was built for me, because I am Stack Overflow; and so are you. We all form a vast community here built on a foundation of helping others and also of solving problems both our own and for other people. I just want to see this place succeed because I feel like it also allows us as a community to succeed.

Thank you Stack Overflow, and thank you to the community of other users who are Stack Overflow. Without you, we wouldn't have any of this.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1623007/joe), you probably would think I wouldn't say Stack Overflow helped me very much.  After all, I have four questions and 1500+ answers as of writing this.

However, asking questions isn't the only way to benefit from Stack Overflow, and I would certainly say that I've benefited from Stack Overflow as much or more than it's benefited from my contributions!

- **Organization and Markdown**

  I've always been a contributor to various online forums in my particular language; what Stack Overflow has done for me the most in that regard, has been to teach me to better organize my answers.  I'm fairly verbose, and in particular in my other most common forum - a mailing list, SAS-L - I started out fairly poor at organizing things.

  Along came Stack Overflow a few years ago, and it wasn't terribly long before I picked up on Markdown, and the significant benefits that arise from organizing your thoughts more effectively.  Things that aren't very easy to do in email - or at least, don't come naturally - do here; I find myself thinking in a much more organization-focused way now.  More enters.  Lists.  Indenting.  Just thinking about my answer more as I write it - and that's carried over, to some extent, to the other places that I post.

  I also learned Markdown, of course, which was a big help when I started learning [R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) - whose most common printed output format uses Markdown.  I found myself learning much more quickly than my (online) classmates, because of this.

  Finally, Stack Overflow is one of the best ways for me to find answers I have written, myself, to remember how I did something in the past.  Some of these are self-answered questions (all four of my questions are, in fact, these); some are just answers I remember posting to an interesting question someone posed a while back that happens to help me.
- **Community and Stack Exchange**

  Stack Overflow brought me to Stack Exchange as a whole, via the Hot Questions feed, and that's turned into a great resource for me.  As a new parent about the same time I joined Stack Overflow, it led me to *[Parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com)*, which has a great community of users and has helped me become a better parent - you'll find a lot more questions there than here! - as well as connected me to other parents who I can share stories with and laugh at theirs.

  Other sites have helped me learn about [travelling internationally](http://travel.stackexchange.com), read some interesting anecdotes about the [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com), and solve some interesting [programming puzzles](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).
- **Learning other languages**
  When I started learning R, Stack Overflow was a great resource to answer the questions I had.  I never had to ask a question, in fact - every time I needed to know something, it was already answered. The only time I wasn't sure, the R chat room folks guided me to the right place right away.

  I've also used Stack Overflow to improve my SQL; seeing some of the solutions [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) posts when [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_(software)) and SQL overlap have helped me tremendously just in seeing different ways things could be accomplished.  I use [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) just frequently enough that Stack Overflow is a great tool for remembering how to do things.

All in all, Stack Overflow has been tremendously helpful in expanding my mind - from learning other languages, to learning about parenting, travel, finance, and more; to learning how to be a better helper.  All that, and the ability to answer occasionally intriguing questions - including [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903856/sas-macro-ampersand/22915555#22915555) that led to [a paper](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings15/3285-2015.pdf)!

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow in just the short time I have been a member has become my primary resource for programming troubleshooting information. I'm by no means a programmer; there is no such beast in my country.

I first found it through Google Search trying to solve some minor issues with a little educational game I was making for my kids. And since then I have made many little free programs that are in use in 11 govt departments here as well as a lot of the schools. All of which seem amazing to us here, because there's never been any sort of software in our language.

But now my basic knowledge of SQL, HTML, JavaScript, and CSS has probably in a few short months at least tripled and is growing every day. And the ideas I can see a way to accomplish are beyond anything I'd have thought of before.

I've gone from dead simple little programs to graphic rich, slick looking applications with bells and whistles. Which has opened up a lot of eyes and a lot of interest in programming from my engineering students. Because I make stuff in my language or bilingual they benefit everyone here since broken English is the norm which makes it difficult for people to learn when everything at advanced levels is just in English.

(My background is network engineering and linguistics.)

Without such a resource and the assistance I get with my probably naive questions (although I do try and solve everything myself before posting them), I would never have even attempted a lot of what I have done. After joining Stack Overflow and receiving so much assistance and learning so many things, my confidence has really taken off. So in summary, kudos to all members who are sharing their expertise and helping others.

PS: I don't want a prize. I already got one finding you guys.

Comment: Re *"broken English is the norm"*: Why is that? Lack of skills (the education system is to be blamed)? Due to an [inferiority complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferiority_complex) (not lack of skills) - e.g., caused by [colonialism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/colonialism#Noun)? Too large a distance between the native language and English? Standard straightforward English seen as too formal? Something else? (Not rhetorical questions - I am really interested in the answer.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen our education system is beyond crap. Since Independence most govt departments turned into family businesses, education in particular is a bad joke

Answer (score 3):

When I first found stackoverflow I was not confident enough to apply for a developer position. There was definitely something that struck me upon becoming a part of a community consisting of thousands and thousands of developers willing to help one another. It was mind blowing to say the least, I truly felt right at home and instantly wanted to be part of it all.

This is where it all truly clicked for me. For some reason, stackoverflow boosted my confidence and moved me towards my first position as a Python Developer while still a College Student. I relied heavily on the community in my first few weeks at work and it was well worth it. I was finally part of a development team and it was thanks to the stackoverflow community and their willingness to help one another.

Not too long afterwards I began answering questions on topics I was most familiar with, slowly gaining reputation and learning more about the subject; Explaining something really makes you understanding much better. I spent a good amount of time on my answers doing additional research and ensuring that all parts were covered in oder for the OP to fully understand the details.

It's fair to say that stackoverflow and the careers page have changed my life for the better. I use it as bragging rights in interviews and it WORKS. Interviewers love to browse my profile and ask about my accepted answers. Its been a life changing experience and I will be putting much more of my time in the upcoming years.

Looking forward to many years with stackoverflow, one day even join the team ;)

Love you guys, Love the community, lets keep it going!!!

Answer (score 3):

StackOverflow helped me **a lot**. Let me elaborate on this: currently, according to my upvotes, it helped me exactly **3,630** times *a lot*. Imagine that, learning 2.5 new useful things on average each day for four years now. And all that for free. Pro bono. Only upvote and (optionally) a kind word required. **Priceless!**

Also, more specifically, it helped me **133** times when I asked my own question (surprisingly, only [4 of them remained unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/534755/nikola?tab=questions&sort=newest) so far).

My experience with StackOverflow was very positive from the start (something I'll elaborate a bit more below) - it was my first few weeks on a "test period" for a new job and I couldn't solve one thing. They said it would be tricky and I sort of hoped that if I get it done quickly I'll get some recognition. I did my fair share of googling and looking around the site (I knew about SO at that time already, but just haven't asked any questions yet) and since I didn't find any related question I finally decided to post. Not surprisingly, I got the answer in a matter of minutes. Sure enough, I did get permanently employed after that (and few other small tasks that I had to do on top of that).

See, I would like to emphasize on a way that I asked my first question, by repeating that I've googled quite a lot and searched through existing SO questions. Now, we who are around here a bit longer know what started to happen. New users started to come and, well, the quality of questions was not on a given level. And, that's why it hurts me to see quite a lot of people shitting on StackOverflow (yeah, we know who they are - simple google search will turn out quite a few posts), but if we would just be honest and acknowledge the fact that it somehow seems that these days everyone wants something "out of the box - give me the codez plz", without ever doing the research them self. What's the learning value in that, I honestly don't know.

Anyways, fast forward 4 years, I'm still loving it. Somewhere along the lines of using StackOverflow daily, I've grown as a developer and turned from the one who asks questions to someone who tends to contribute back to this wonderful community by giving answers. And, just yesterday I've "set the record straight" and leveled the number of my questions with the number of my answers. In the future I hope to help even more.

As for other opportunities StackOverflow provided me, I can only say countless. I don't have a huge rep, but nevertheless I've gotten into an invite only programming site thanks to my SO profile. Also, I've gotten few requests to write a book, be a technical reviewer, and I get a lot of clicks from SO to [my blog](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog). It seems a bit cocky to say, but people do tend to look at you differently when you say you have a somewhat fairly large amount of rep on SO. For me, it's some kind of a badge of honor, to be honest :)

All in all - **thank you StackOverflow**.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR: Stack Overflow taught me to enjoy reading others' code.

---

### I hated reading code:

For a long time, I really hated reading code.

Other people use different logic in their program. They use different naming conventions. They use weird functions, crappy file names, etc.

I was literally getting angry to the person who has written that ugly piece of code just because they don't use the same function names as me. So, I was basically either:

1. **Trash all the code** and start rewriting it from scratch.
2. (Or hopefully) **Start refactoring** everything from the beginning and use my own naming conventions, file names, my own program logic, etc.

This was mainly because I have never attended an "open source" project with other professionals. My only "*collaboration*" at that time was the "*group projects*" that we were having in the classes. And sadly enough, I was able to do the coding by myself in these group projects. So, I was basically able to survive without reading others' code at that time.

### I needed to ask questions about my code:

I was not reading other's code, but I was having issues with my own code. **So, started asking questions on Stack Overflow** from time to time. And guess what? The answers were using different naming conventions and different functions, etc. However, they were also giving proper answers to my questions. So they were good and bad at the same time. I guess Stack Overflow posts/answers was my first *real*  experience in which I give some effort to understand some other person's code.

The more I read answers, the more I liked others' code. Because they were teaching me other ways of solving problems, other ways of thinking, interesting ways of solving small issues, indexing, etc.

### Now, I read others' code every day, and enjoy it:

Well, not reading everybody's code is enjoying, but I guess you got the point.

I feel more comfortable when explaining a programming issue to a colleague, or a student since I know different other ways of doing the same thing and their consequences, etc.

And, more importantly, I feel it becomes easier to answer their questions since your sympathy abilities increase when you read more of other peoples' code.

**Being able to read other people's code is very important**. And Stack Overflow actually helped me to realize this fact.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen thank you for the grammar fix. Well appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 3):

When I began to get into programming, I found that learning the ropes was really hard... especially when you can't find the ropes, or when you do, they're falling apart.

Between the mess of [W3Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools), [Yahoo Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers), and barely understandable obsolete blog posts, it was really hard.

However, as my Google-fu improved, the more Stack Overflow began popping up in my search results, and I began noticing a pattern:

- The solutions worked.
- The questions were understandable (*mostly, but hey, what're ya gonna do?*)
- I could find solutions to just about anything on there, and if I couldn't, there was always that big 'Ask Button' in the corner.

Sure, Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange are a little daunting at first, but once you learn the ropes, you start growing and learning crazy fast.

After a little while on Stack Overflow, I began to *really* understand what I was writing, and how not to abuse functions and features, but how to actually use the functions and how to write code that wasn't mistaken for Italian pasta.

Stack Overflow helped me grow as a programmer. Beyond that, it offered me the chance to do that for others, to help them grow as programmers. While understandably hard as a beginner programmer, I will be better equipped as time progresses.

Answer (score 3):

All my programming life up until the last few months, I've been developing almost exclusively for desktop environments, mostly in C# or VB.NET. This summer, I decided I should learn web development and get into the whole JavaScript/HTML5 thing so as to not become a fossil. I knew there were boatloads of tutorials on the Internet for web development, but I also knew many of those teach questionable practices or are simply wrong.

So I turned to (*drum roll*) Stack Overflow. On SO, I found the answer - several answers, in fact - to every JavaScript and CSS question I had. Being new to web programming but not to programming in general, I appreciated the task-orientedness of the Q&A format; all I had to do to take each next step was search SO for a few keywords. Seeing votes on posts and the reputation/background of answerers helped me identify the best answers. I now have my feet on the ground in web programming, and I'm (fairly certain I'm) doing it right.

Stack Overflow has also helped me get better at communicating. I know some people can't deal with SO's quality standards, but I love how only good questions and answers stick around. MCVEs are so extremely useful in asking programming questions, and in my experience, they can also be used in general problem solving and even education. *MCVE is like a way of life for me now.* MCVE really drove home the point that one must **try** rather than expecting somebody else to do everything. It's amazing what can be accomplished when a task is broken down and defined well.

Thank you, Stack Overflow, for your high standards. MCVE forever!

Answer (score 3):

## Finally a real programmer

At first, I was posting answers to help the community and give something back to it because it's helped me a lot. Then, **I realized answering questions wasn't just good for others**, but it also helped me to become a better programmer.

I knew that every time I answered a question I had to make it as complete as possible by including every small detail in order to make sure other programmers fully understood what I had written. Before submitting my answer, I went through the documentation and the other reference websites because sometimes a programming concept wasn't clear in my mind. By answering dozens of questions, **I also realized that I did know very little about what I thought to know**.

Browsing through other questions tagged with programming languages that at first I wasn't interested or I had no knowledge about made me explore lots of new things. To name a few: Java, SQL, and even electronics with Arduino. **Hours of joy learning new things!**

I am immensely grateful that Stack Overflow exists because it helped me becoming a real programmer and exploring new technologies I wasn't aware of. I started from scratch and slowly built my knowledge. Bit by bit.

Answer (score 3):

## It gave me something to talk about during my interview.

About a year and a half ago I was job hunting and got two interviews. During the first interview I was given a test in which I knew all but one question. I was told my answer was wrong and was told the correct answer but was not given an explanation. I asked the question [Why does the following code print out 10 instead of null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432710/why-does-the-following-code-print-out-10-instead-of-null) here and was swiftly given 3 correct answers.

Two days later, I had an interview at another company. During this interview, I was asked to rate myself in PHP out of 10. I answered that I was a 7 and the interviewer asked me why. I told him there was a lot I did not know and used the question above as an example. I got the job :)

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I'm still a college student who just starts to code for around three years. For sure, my story won't be as great or awesome as other experienced programmers. However, Stack Overflow has been a great resource for me to understand how things work and how to get better understandings of my code.

First of all, I had around one year background during high school for learning basic programming in [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29). It was wonderful and I loved the course a lot. However, things changed and I decided to apply as a [biochemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biochemistry) major for college. Biochemistry  was great until I realized that I still liked programming in general. Hence, I decided to take some intermediate to advanced programming classes during my freshmen year. And yes, programming is wonderful even though college classes are much harder than my casual high school course (especially with the [quarter system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_quarter_(year_division))).

My first time using Stack Overflow was during the time I had struggles with OOP in Python. I was unclear on how to make a class and how to use the class effectively for my class project. After looking at some answers on Stack Overflow, I had a deeper understanding of why people invented OOP and why it is good to use it instead of making functions all over the place. It was a great experience with the Stack Overflow communities! I literally had the "ahhh" moment when I figured out my troubles through questions/answers on Stack Overflow.

After a while using Stack Overflow to look other people's questions and answers, I finally reached to a point that I could give out answers to some questions myself on Stack Overflow. It was a really cool moment when helping someone else. The more I use Stack Overflow, the more knowledge I gain. I helped me a lot in school and outside of school (personal projects). I asked some questions on Stack Overflow and the community was pretty active in which I could get a good answer in 4-5 hours. I wish the website can maintain its strong community and resources that can expand later in the future. Anyway, thanks Stack Overflow a lot!!

P.S.: Also, I changed my major to computer science immediately after the first year in college.

Answer (score 3):

**The Question:** [How to connect to EC2 instance within an iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082921/how-to-connect-to-ec2-instance-within-an-ios-app)

**The Story:**

Stack Overflow has helped me countless times, both by asking questions and by finding other questions. A very memorable experience I had was when I was trying to add a survey functionality to one of my iPhone applications. I had recently learned about [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) and was wondering if that was the way I should do it - by copying my private key into my application.

Obviously that was a terrible idea. And luckily, [user Undo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664/undo) was there to help me out.

Putting it like this:

> You don't want to let people SSH into your server, especially by
> embedding your private key into an app binary. It's crazy easy for
> someone to get it, then wreak havoc upon your server.

I learned all about [HTTP POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) - both the server side using Python, and the front end with [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C). I also learned about some SSH security. Undo's answer helped me implement my survey feature into my app and it worked really well - until I decided to short cut all my hard work with a [Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_(platform)) database...

Answer (score 3):

Fresh out of college - I was assigned a very simple project. The task was to write a Windows service (with file-watcher) to convert some [EDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange) files to various formats (including [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), and [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel)) and finally email the converted file(s). The team consisted of four developers - two of them freshers, a database administrator, and a lead (who was, naturally, on leave when the problem started).

We completed everything perfectly, went ahead and deployed. Everything was fine except the email formatting.

**The problem:**

The email formatting --- on some lines either there would be two line break or none at all. Client was using [Outlook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Outlook) while we had [Lotus Notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HCL_Domino). The issue was only occurring in Outlook. We spend a complete week trying to fix the problem (adding environment.newline, \n, br with HTML formatting - nothing worked) before finally posting [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183786/newline-not-working-in-email-net-windows-service) on Stack Overflow.

Two minutes - that's all it took before someone posted the solution.

It's since that day that I'm fan of Stack Overflow and have spent several hours learning new concepts and ideas.

Thank you to Stack Overflow and all those who are part of it!

Answer (score 3):

Like so many others, the answers on here have solved many of my issues. At first, I was a lurker (or as the staff says, a normal visitor). No account, no voting, no editing, nothing. One day I found a question and none of the answers fixed the issue I was encountering. I eventually figured out a solution to my problem. I debated internally about posting my solution on the question as an answer. I was anxious that I would be judged and the community would react negatively. The feature that got me to post was the ability to edit my answer. If the post had a typo the community and I would be able to fix it without much shaming. I also wanted to start to pay the knowledge forward. Without additional people adding additional knowledge, Stack Overflow wouldn’t be valuable 10 years from now to a developer in my position.

That one answer still gets sporadic upvotes to this day. That one post improved my confidence with posting online and I continued to find questions that I could answer. While doing that I noticed that I wasn’t a very effective communicator. I would need to pour significant effort into research, typing a couple of drafts to an answer, post an answer, then reread it, edit it a couple of times. But like anything in this world, best way to improve on something is practice.

Real life has limited the time I have had to post on Stack Overflow in the last year or so but I still value the ability to improve my communication skills and confidence. I would like to think that has improved my personal and professional relationships.

Answer (score 3):

Before Stack Overflow, in 2007, looking for answers was really painful, there was [some concurrence](http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/),  blogs, and forums. No real solution for asking advice on a specific topic.
Helping others was also complicated:

- writing a blog post? Who would read it if you're not known blogger?
- Contributing to forums? Better find the right one...

So, starting in 2008, Stack Overflow made me grow when I was trying to provide answers. Solving another person issue can be tricky, because of missing context, conveying consequences of your solution to the asker. I learnt a lot while proposing the best fit answers I could think of.

Some answers were just the result of simple googling, copy-paste and cite sources: those ones improved my Google-fu, which is really helpful when you have to prototype whatever new fancy framework ([Angularjs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) 1.0...). Others answers required more analysis on the issue's cause, and stress tested my understanding of the framework/library/language. Those answers really improved my knowledge of various fields, and improved my technical writing skills as well.

And of course, Stack Overflow helps me for all the obscure questions I asked while trying to make some code "just better" in [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209732/how-to-put-same-item-in-multiple-groups-inside-listbox) or [NHibernate.Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548946/nhibernate-search-index-different-properties-in-one-field) :)

Answer (score 3):

As a web application developer, I use Stack Overflow *literally* all the time.

Some background: I'm a college computer science student, graduating this coming December. Before I got my current position, I worked as a server at a local Italian restaurant. The money was nice for a part-time position, but I realized if I didn't get out of that business quickly, I might never leave. The late nights were making it nearly impossible to study or do any homework, and the long hours were beginning to take a toll on my body.

One fateful day in my CSC232 class, the professor passed around a sheet of paper with information on an internship for a local, reputable company. The description was extremely vague, so I had no idea what to expect - but I knew I **had** to have it.

I spruced up my resume and contacted the hiring manager about the position, and got an interview. After that interview (and one or two others), they gave me a "test" of sorts: to create a simple web application to allow management of a database of "parts."

I had never used any of these tools before, so I was slightly overwhelmed. After many hours of searching and tweaking my code, I was stuck on the concept of a connection string. I asked a (bad) question about it, and Stack Overflow helped me find the solution. In fact, it still helps me find solutions to most daily issues I run into.

I got that internship because of this website, and in December, when I graduate, I'm going to accept the full-time position.

Thank you, Stack Overflow, and all of your wonderful users striving to make this place as great a community as possible.

Answer (score 3):

It was nearly 15 years ago that I had met Java in university. I had a Java book like a brick on the wall. I read the book, wrote the code because questions were simple. I graduated from university and In my first job experience I encountered many questions at Java projects. I tried to solve them but they costed me a lot of sleepless nights to find solutions. One day my boss saw me and asked a question "How do you solve a problem you encountered?". I said that i read related documents, books, API etc. and i find the solution. He said "No, answer is wrong. If you encounter a problem, you will find the true person who encountered that problem before. If you find him you will find the answer. Don't explore America again and again.". It was the turning point.

I met with Stack Overflow in 2008 and understood that it was the meeting point people explored America before me. I found here solutions to my questions about Java, Spring, Gradle etc. Many times i found answers in minutes. So now i don't explore America again and again, i solve the problem and go on my way. I'm not googling, i'm just stackoverflowing. Stack Overflow is the place where people help each other to save time, save money, save sleep. Now i try to help people by becoming a member. I believe that if someone has a question, he/she will find the person who asked it before at Stack Overflow. Congratulations to everybody for making the 10 million mark.

Answer (score 3):

## Stack Overflow helped me bootstrap my career.

I should explain a bit - I reached this site when I was a first semester senior in college, and I hadn't received any opportunities for internships.  I felt confident with what I knew, being a CompSci tutor and all, but I was staring down the barrel of being flung into the work force without any real-world experience to speak of.

I was worried that they wouldn't give me the time of day.

That's around the time I reached Stack Overflow.  I had decided to take it upon myself to prove that I know and understood certain concepts, and the best way for me to do that and for it to be publicly visible was to participate here.

From there, the site has helped in an immense way to both allow me to share what knowledge I have of Core Java, Ruby and Python, as well as gain knowledge about Spring, Rails, and Flask.  It continues to help me to this day, both as I look for answers to questions that I may have, as well as help others with problems that they're having.

Answer (score 3):

Most stories about how SO helped one become a better programmer are usually about solving this problem or that problem, or some answer that somebody gave, or an answer that I found...

While all that is immensely true for me, what I found to be the most help is the answers that **I** wrote. And the questions, too.

I learned how to be a better writer. While most of my best writing (IMO) is on Security.SE, I got a lot of practice writing answers here, and that has definitely helped me produce better communication - writing, documentation, collaboration, anything really.

It helped me learn how to ask a proper question, when I inevitably need help: how to focus on the important part of the problem, how to communicate the issues, how to share the problem-solving process I've already gone through.

And moreover - SO has helped me learn the value of community, how to participate, how to give back. I used to be about me and my team, now I am contributing to many communities, volunteering my time in many different ways, and this is, in a large part, thanks to SO.

Answer (score 3):

**Stack Overflow has helped me learn to answer my own questions.**

There is tremendous value in creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Usually the process of whittling code down to a minimal example helps clarify the problem, allowing me to rephrase my question and find an existing answer, reveals design flaws, or silly programming errors on my part.

Compared to my past self (just randomly changing values and control-flow or throwing `print` statements everywhere), I've become much better a systematically narrowing down what's going wrong. I find the same skills apply to other areas in life.

More in general, Stack Overflow has been an invaluable resource for just *getting the job done*. Every time I have questions on other topics and end up at sites like Yahoo! Answers, I cringe at the lack of quality, the subjective answers without any supporting evidence, and the general chaos of it. Trying to imagine what the programming world would be like if we didn't have Stack Overflow is kind of nightmarish. Being an [ISFJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Briggs_Type_Indicator), helping people is very rewarding to me, so it's great being able to be a part of Stack Overflow and working to make the world a little bit better, one post at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow has become an essential part of my life as a programmer.

My favourite part of Stack Overflow is looking through other people's questions and answers. Figuring out why they encountered the problem in the first way and how I would have done it. Then looking through the answers to see how other experienced programmers solved the issue. It is very inspiring and instructive to compare their solutions to my own. Forcing me to reconsider my own solution.

Trying to solve other people's questions teaches more than any tutorial could. Just like reading answers from the masters, answering questions myself makes me see things in a different light.

I have taken a lot from the community but I'm proud to have contributed a little to it also. Every person helped counts as extra experience to me.

In the end, it makes me a better programmer. Thanks Stack Overflow!

Comment: I wrote this a bit weirdly and incoherent... Oh well, I hope it is inspiring to someone. Time to go home today, I spent too long on SO already.

Answer (score 3):

Like most programmers, I discovered Stack Overflow through Google searches for problems that I had.  The Q/A style with voting allowed the best answers to float to the top, which always gives me the answer that I was looking for.  Naturally, this helped me with debugging school projects, as well as understanding CS concepts.  I'm always amazed at the breadth and quality of the Q/A's on Stack Overflow, compared to other programming sites.  Stack Overflow pretty much became my go-to place for answers.

A few years later, several of my friends posted how much Stack Overflow rep they accumulated, which inspired me to try answering questions.  It felt good contributing back to Stack Overflow, and I definitely learned new things from reading good questions and figuring out the answers.  If I didn't know the answer, I would wait for others to answer so that I too could learn.

Overall, Stack Overflow has saved me countless hours of struggling with bugs and being confused, as well as solidifying my understanding of CS concepts and programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

> **TL;DR:** I joined this site to learn by asking questions, but ended up learning more from answering them.

*Here is my story:*

As a developer who has learned most things through self-teaching, Stack Overflow has been a great resource for looking up error messages, bugs, and other issues. Prior to Stack Overflow, back when I was just starting out, it was pretty rough. Google search results would return a wide variety of results, with an even wider range of quality, mostly bad. But in more recent years, Stack Overflow has been my go-to source for a variety of issues, and is almost always one of the top results when I search.

Then one day, I had a problem I couldn't find anything about, an apparent CSS rendering and/or layout bug present in only [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)/[Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)) browsers. Unable to find anything on this issue after some time trying to craft a search query to find anything on the issue, I decided to turn to the website that had given me so many great CSS hacks and workarounds. I registered for an account, created an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), posted my question and waited. My question got one solitary upvote, but not much else.

Thankfully my story does not end there. I read about this thing called a bounty, but my 6 rep points simply wouldn't cover such an expense. What should I do? How hard can it be to answer some questions and gain some reputation points?

Well, it wasn't quite as easy as I expected, but it was also much more rewarding than I expected. I found myself learning a lot from attempting to solve other people's problems. Be it from prompting me to learn a new feature, researching a thorough explanation for exactly why the CSS box model behaves the way it does, or even someone offering a better solution then I could come up with, there is almost-always something new to be learned, no matter how well you thought you understood it. Perhaps this is why I have ended up with such a high answer-to-question ratio, currently at *1:53.5*.

Stack Overflow has been a great learning resource to me, even in ways I never expected. I know I wouldn't be where I am today if not for Stack Overflow.

Here's to another 10 million questions!

Answer (score 3):

TL:DR I started programming in middle school, am now in high school, and am very thankful for the Stack Overflow community.

I started learning Java in 6th grade. After a couple of months, I ventured out into the world of programming on my own with no help. This tactic crashed and burned quickly and I put my problem into Google. This website called Stack Overflow appeared and it seemed like a good site. I clicked on the link and was transported into an amazing community of programmers. In this new world, I found a lot of really nice users who were willing to help out and not hate.

It is kind of mind-boggling that it's been four years since I found Stack Overflow. I have since become interested in a lot more computer-related things. Android programming, Java programming, C#, computer hardware, etc. I have a ton of problems and the Stack Exchange community has helped tremendously! My first computer that I built wouldn't have Windows on it if it weren't for the Stack Overflow community. My first Android app would have a lot more bugs if it wasn't for the Stack Overflow community. My first Windows program wouldn't even run if it wasn't for the Stack Overflow community.

I have been enjoying Stack Overflow for the past few years and it is something I am never going to forget. I started out with beginner Java issues. Soon I became comfortable answering questions with much more complex problems. After getting into Android programming, the same thing happened. I started out by answering the simple questions before getting into complicated and/or obscure questions. I am still a small user though, only affecting around 1,000 people. But helping out these 1,000+ people is why I exist on this site.

I highly recommend any new users to get involved because that is when the site will reward you. Getting involved and being curious is what makes this site so special. I wouldn't have the computer knowledge I have without the Stack Overflow community. I have found people on this site that I now hang out with in real life. So join the millions of people on this site and make a difference!

Answer (score 2):

> How did Stack Overflow help me?

There are many many ways in which Stack Overflow has helped me. Apart from technical help which I did receive even before I joined Stack Overflow this community made me understand what *communication* is. Before entering Stack Overflow I was a very poor in communication skills and was very shy to speak (even on-line). Once I joined Stack Overflow, it taught me how to be nice and speak out to the point. It helped me improve my knowledge of English. Before joining Stack Overflow I did not know that there should be [no space before punctuation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6?m=21001974#21001974). This greatly helped me in my GRE and TOEFL preparation (In TOEFL they ask you to speak, Stack Overflow gave me the confidence to speak).

There were many incidents where I used to act rude to the users (because I did not know how to speak), but each and every time I used to be corrected (mostly from the [Python](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) chat room). Slowly and slowly, I began to pick up how to speak. Yesterday i.e. 31st Aug, 2015 I successfully managed to defend my point in a debate (my first ever). Thanks to Stack Overflow and its users my vocabulary has greatly improved (now I am hopeful of getting good marks in my next comp exam slated for 29th November 2015).

Thus Stack Overflow designed to help people *technically* helped me in a completely different area. I have just two words for Stack Overflow and its users:

***Thank you***

---

<sub>A short note on how ***Meta Stack Overflow*** helped me.
It taught me to be jovial in life. I was really surprised when even top rep users poked [fun](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303804/google-is-mixing-github-and-stack-overflow#comment239887_303804). This attitude of Meta users helped me change my attitude from being a very serious person to a more fun-loving person.</sub>

<sub>Another short note. I was asked in my interview if I did hold a Stack Overflow account. On replying in the positive he surfed through my list of answers (in his phone) and exclaimed, *"Look I have up-voted your answer"*. This was the moment when I did shout out in my mind ***Thank you Stack Overflow*** and it came from my heart.</sub>

Comment: There is no space before question marks and exclamation marks in English, but, there is a space between "Stack" and "Overflow" in the name "Stack Overflow"; this may help you if you ever decide you'd like to work for Stack Overflow. :-P See http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance for more details. :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Thanks a lot! I would certainly love to work here :D.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the help Stack Overflow gives me wouldn't really make a good story here, but it wouldn't feel right to not at least mention it. For the past ~3 years, this has been the first site I'll check for any problem I have when programming, and almost without fail I've found the answer I'm looking for. It's reached a point where I'm disappointed if I have to go to another site to find an answer, because as often as not, the "answer" is just a link to another resource which is no longer there. That basically never happens here, and it makes solving a tough problem much less painful.

There have been a few times that stood out as particularly helpful though. My [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180484/effeciently-transfer-large-amount-of-byte-data-from-c-to-java) in particular was what convinced me that Stack Overflow was a place that was worth taking special notice of. I encountered the problem at the first internship I had which involved a lot of independent programming and, honestly, I was a bit over my head most of the time. It was the first time I'd had to do anything with JNI, and it was all new to me.

I ended up having to ask a question about transferring large amounts of data between C++ and Java. I'd had a working solution, but it was terribly inefficient, and searching online would only ever turn up descriptions of what I was already doing. So I gave in and, reluctantly, posted my first question. And, within a few hours, I had an answer. There was no wasted time, no having to dig through a pile of back and forth conversation. Just a simple "you should use this. Here's why."

That answer helped me to finish the project I was working on, and helped make it be one of the pieces of code I'm most proud of. It wasn't a large answer, and it didn't earn the answerer very much reputation, but I appreciated it.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow has assisted me in three semi-related and considerably far-reaching ways. Currently, I am in an academic and employment limbo, so I am are working to get an 'edge' on my chances of a new career.

First and foremost, I have been helped with my programming skills - my particular area of research requires that melding of some unusual and often disparate algorithms, but I have found examples here of how it could be done. This leads to my second point: I am not one for wanting the answers, the bits and pieces I find here provide me with the basis to figure out how to assemble the code.

Finally, writing skills, though mine are not the best, I am learned by observations (and from the many blogs, etc.) how to document my questions and how to document the code itself for communicating with another party.

I have not achieved my goal yet, but are well on the way, with Stack Overflow's help, I should get there in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

## How has Stack Overflow helped me

Over the years, Apple has developed and added many new features to iOS.  Since I don't develop apps for a living, it takes time to learn about a framework or feature and start to use it in an app.

My general approach to learning about something new has been to watch the WWDC videos, then check out Apple's sample code.  But without a team of developers I can casually turn to during the day, I've been dependent on Stack Overflow for help when I have questions.

The answers I've found here on Stack Overflow have helped me improve the apps I've been making, and feel more confident about the features I'm adopting.

I rely on Stack Overflow so much, I always have at least one browser tab open to the site.  Stack Overflow has clearly been my single consistent resource for help, and has helped me to become more confident as I learn and adapt to new and changing features.

I think the most significant way that Stack Overflow has helped me is that the more I learn, the more answers I have been able to provide in turn to others.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of SO since I was in college, And it really helped to finish my course.. And now I'm currently working as a back-end developer, so therefore I'm not that exposed to front-end development, though I also code in front-end but not that much. As a way of giving thanks to SO for helping me, I signed up and started answering questions on SO, but most of my answers are more on the back-end.

As I really want to learn front-end developing, aside from watching tutorials, I started answering front-end developing problems on SO. There was a time that I [answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31980374/4273446) on SO and I was very happy because I discovered a new syntax on CSS(using `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` ), and I couldn't discover that if I didn't try to solve that question.(*but I only posted it as a comment because it was already marked as duplicate before I found the solution*).

There were times also that I encountered a problem on SQL, and I'm running out of time, so I badly need it to be resolved, I already tried to search it but couldn't find the solution. So I asked it on SO and luckily, after 10 mins someone [answered my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28362823/4273446) and it worked perfectly.

I could still remember the feeling the first time I got my [first accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27073120/4273446). I feel so honored that time that I helped. It feels so great every time they say that the answer you provided works perfectly..

I'm so grateful that I participate on this site 'coz It really improves my programming skills and career.

Answer (score 2):

Much like [rc1 answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303993/4957418), Stack Overflow is virtually always my choice when I google a programming question I have. It is just so much superior to wading through documentation that is sometimes obscure or obsolete.

I had the opportunity to learn a bit of programming in university, but it honestly didn't help me much when I eventually got a job programming as a fresh graduate. I still had to learn how to do everything, and I quickly understood that formulating my question in the google search-bar and selecting the top Stack Overflow links was the fastest and most useful way to get my answers.

Stack Overflow helped me create production code of languages I hadn't previously heard about, to be used in actual commercial projects. The code was, of course, reviewed, for quality assurance, but basically it gave me the confidence that I can program virtually anything with a bit of research. It gave me the confidence to say that I am a programmer.

Answer (score 2):

I started off in college, that's where my love for programming started, it was just some basic `c++`. All of my questions to why different things happened, my tutor could not answer... So that is when I found SO. I was just a lurker and looking for answers for quite some time.

I finally signed up when I left college and got myself a job as a QA person, but in my spare time I was doing a lot of different programming projects and I had so many questions (Alot of them was bad ones to start) so that is when I made the account and started asking questions.

StackOverflow helped me with my career and also my personal hobby (programming), I used to think that X was the best way to do something, but now I see some answers some people post and I still have a lot to learn, but just reading answers and attempting to answer questions had improved my skill a lot, I am actually thinking about why am I doing it this way? Is there a better way to approach this? Let's check StackOverflow to see how they have done it!

I am thankful for this community.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow has been my way of 'sharpening my teeth' - I'm using it almost like homework. It gives me a steady stream of case studies and real world problem examples to try and solve. And ideally whilst simultaneously implementing (or at least advising) on 'best practice'.

There's that old adage - 10,000 hours to become a master. Well - Stack Overflow hours count too. Probably count double, because "debugging is twice as hard as writing code".

And so I've chewed through an awful lot of examples of programming tasks - from simple to complex - and had an opportunity to move beyond 'solving the problem at hand' to actually contemplate best practice and *elegant* solutions to a particular problem.

This is also rewarded with Stack Overflow. You'll get upvotes for something hacky that works. You'll generally get more for an elegant solution that's well explained and offers the pros and cons of a particular approach (Or even why you *shouldn't* do something, provided you offer a constructive alternative).

So yes, Stack Overflow has helped me professionally in moving up the 'stages of a programmer' by getting some more practice in.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm sure many people here know, starting your first internship can be terrifying. From day one, I was dropped into a personal project, with the management too busy with hitting deadlines to realistically be able to help much. At university I primarily used my friends as a resource if I got stuck, and tried to do the same if I could.

A friend of mine recommended Stack Overflow... and it became my lifeline for the rest of summer. I have spent hours pouring over explanations to questions, and have felt I've improved as a programmer both in terms of practice - the amount of comments I fill my code with hopefully testify that.

Although I only have a few questions to my account, I've tried to follow all the rules and make them brief and helpful, whilst containing information that is hopefully of use to others in the future.

In realistic terms, without SO as a resource I'm sure my project would have teetered over the edge into nothingness several times, but as it was I was able to discern how to optimise my program without a security risk, and manage to hack my way through the opaque nature of the windows documentation to interface with a WinRT OS.

In terms of my future, SO is the reason that I have built the confidence to do well in this internship, and hopefully the rest of my career. Hopefully in years to come I can help others as I have been helped.

Ta very much everyone!

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow has helped me clear up almost any slight confusion when it comes to programming. Have a question? Just Google it and most likely a SO question with a good answer will appear in the top 5 search results, I really like the stabilisation of this, one big knowledgebase everyone can use. Premium support without the premium price.

The most helpful StackOverflow has been for me is when I was working on a project for college, I had to work with Bluetooth programming which was totally new for me. SO cleared up a lot of confusion on how to start by getting great answers on my question.

Answer (score 2):

**Short version:** Stack Overflow allowed me to find answers I couldn't easily get elsewhere. Then I started being active myself because I liked how the site was organized and that I could help others while improving my own skills as well.

---

When I first got into programming in High School, around 2005, there was little well organized content online. We had computer science olympiads with difficult algorithmic problems that I enjoyed solving, but my teachers didn't care about such contests much, nor were they prepared to adequately prepare students for them, so I had little support from my teachers in terms of training.

We had a local online judge, like SPOJ, with a forum, and I was also active on an IRC channel where I could get help from some friends. I would also post questions on a C++ forum (you'd have to solve the contest problems in C, C++ or Pascal). However, on the online judge forum, people wouldn't always reply if you were stuck, at least not with enough helpful details. On the C++ forum, the answerers were mostly good programmers, but with little experience regarding competition problems. Same with my IRC friends.

I discovered Stack Overflow around 2010, when I was a CS college student. I was still active on some online judges since I liked solving such problems, and I wanted to go into research after graduating. I was googling for some algorithms, and I saw a link to SO. I found what I was looking for, and I liked the reputation system because it rewarded not only quality work but also quantity and long-term participation. I felt like I could trust high-rep users because they have proven themselves over time, and I wanted to be one.

I decided to make an account. [My first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237021/how-can-i-compute-the-number-of-characters-required-to-turn-a-string-into-a-pali) was quite well received, and I got an answer very quickly, although I didn't really expect to draw the attention of people familiar with such problems so easily. I was very happy, so I added some tags and started following them. Soon, I found questions that I could answer, so I did. I liked helping people, and seeing my reputation grow made me feel like I was appreciated and accepted by the community. It was a very good feeling.

I was very active throughout college, earning most of my current reputation around that period. It also helped me learn a lot more than my college classes would provide. I'd see questions I didn't know the answer to immediately, research or think about them for a while, then post an answer. I wouldn't have done that without SO.

I'd also see questions asking about more details regarding some subject I was told about in a class. Again, I wouldn't immediately know the answer, but after some digging around and pondering, I'd figure it out, post it, and it would usually be at least upvoted. Stack Overflow gave me a lot of material to self-study.

Not only that, but many times someone else would post a great answer, which I enjoyed reading and learning from. So it wasn't only self-study, it also felt like going to class and learning something very cool when opening an interesting question and seeing a great, detailed answer.

I also learned to take criticism better and admit when I'm wrong. Also not to post something until I am at least relatively sure of its correctness; kind of like *think before you open your mouth* (I have a few self-deleted answers, I feel like I still need to work on that a little).

In the previous 2-3 years, I've been less active, but I still posted some questions and answers. I rarely went more than a few days without accessing the site I believe, even if I only checked out a few questions. The site can very well be used to find out what's new about certain technologies from hands-on perspectives once you have a little experience with the site and those technologies.

This year, I've decided to be more active again. I'm learning a lot from the entire network, I am more active on the moderation side and I am also active and learning in tags related to my PhD. I've been a member for a little over 5 years, and barring some major changes, I don't plan to leave.

Answer (score 2):

**Stack Overflow provided an avenue for me to help to others**

I have been aware of the site for many years, and likely used responses found here through Google for many technical questions. In many ways my professional peer group provides only a limited avenue for me to discuss technical questions, and so the Internet has been a primary source of help. As an accountant my professional role has never been 'programmer', but I have always tried to leverage my past knowledge to perform better. In that, Stack Overflow has been very helpful.

However, the real benefit which Stack Overflow had for me came when I was learning a technique that I had not seen before. After going through many similar questions asked on the site, I gained a more nuanced understanding of how the technique worked, and most importantly *when* it worked. I saw a few questions during my search that had yet to be answered to the same degree, and signed up to respond.

I have never before had an opportunity to provide so much technical feedback at my leisure. Most of the questions I've answered have involved concepts that I was not previously 100% confident in; researching my own answers has improved my own technical abilities tremendously.

I find the layout of the site to be very conducive to this 'Socratic' type of learning - even if most of the time the SO 'Socrates' could have just Googled his/her exact question title to find an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had just accepted a new position at my job to be an applications engineer for the IT group, which was kind of a dream position for me. The problem was that the languages and tools they used I was either very rusty with (at best) or completely unfamiliar with. Management knew this and said they were willing to give me three months to see if I could get up to speed or otherwise be moved back to my previous position. And so began my quest to secure my new job.

The first obstacle was Python. I had never used the language before but found myself getting up to speed fairly quickly based on some past scripting experiences. However, Python is not a shell script and I needed to dive deeper than the docs and some quick tutorials. Passing a function, list comprehensions, yield statements and *args and **kwargs are all things I picked up through examples found on Stack Overflow and used in production projects.

The next hurdle was AngularJs. I was familiar with the basic web standards of HTML, CSS and Javascript but using AngularJs along with various other related libraries was a bit daunting. Plunging into the existing code and eventually Stack Overflow I learned some best practices on defining modules, what the differences are the in various services and how to find which scope you happen to be in. I was also encouraged to utilize a task runner which streamlined my development and production deployment process tremendously. Feeling rather confident in my new found abilities, I built out unit test cases for as many parts of my application as I could, in no small part to examples I discovered here.

While almost none of my code at the end of my three months was production ready, my company saw how quickly I got up to speed and what kind of positive change I was bringing to the position and they knew it wouldn't be long before they would see returns on these results. And I knew I had made a turning point myself when I no longer scoured Stack Overflow for answers but for questions that I could provide answers to.

Answer (score 2):

Before I created my account on Stack Overflow, the answers on this site helped me learn a lot about programming. A few years ago, I needed to verify the accuracy of my pi calculation for one of my projects, and [this answer by the world record holder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14283481/2982225) gave me so much to think about that I started visiting the site more frequently in order to read the interesting answers written here. I used to sort questions by votes and read them in leisure. I learnt a lot about coding from these posts, and I knew SO had made me a better programmer. However, it was after I created my account here, that SO had a larger impact on me.

It has almost been two years since I signed up, and SO has helped me in so many ways since then. I always found the answers for my coding problems here, so I never had to ask a question. But writing answers has been a great learning experience for me. I have become better with words. I learnt how to communicate more effectively with fewer words, interacted with folks from across the globe, and now I document my projects better. It is immensely useful while working with teams. SO has helped me not just with the vast amount of amazing information it contains, it has provided me an excellent platform to develop my writing skills.

Answer (score 2):

*Please be humble about my English skills, as it isn't my native language.*

I'm young, right now nearly 20. How does my age connects to [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), you ask?

> Well, I was always fascinated by technic, computers and robots. Even as a small kid I wanted access to computer. And because my father is IT specialist, I had been watching, what he was doing. Of course, I was fascinated by computer games. I got my first computer at the age of 10. I had been thinking, i could do some programming, but instead, I spent my time playing games...
>
> The first breakpoint was, when I went for one year to Germany. I visited Grammar school and I had a lot of time on weekends, because i lived in a small village. I thought, it would be awesome to make application for my Android phone, so I started programming.
>
> And that time, I discovered Stackoverflow. It helped me a lot, because as complete beginner, I had no ideas, how to do really simple stuff. Of cource, I followed different tutorials and my books, but that wasn't enough.
>
> **What makes Stackoverflow really special, and I love it :), is that people help you with your particular problems.**  Sometimes it gives you kick in the right direction, sometimes you get complete solution. I discovered Java, SQlite, Android SDK, Git, HTML5, CSS.

I'm currently developing Android application for biggest recipe portal in Czech Republic. It also helped me to gain stint in german company. I will also study university in Germany.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Stack Overflow fueled the fire to a love of programming that I now have. Stack Overflow is what made me understand programming. And, amazingly, Stack Overflow drastically improved my language skills.

I first learned programming from a summer class for middle school students, where I learned the programming language known as Java. Well, more like I learned basic syntax; we didn't even get to functions or objects. However, I started getting excited about programming. For the next two years, I came up with random project ideas and followed tutorials to figure out how to do them, and I solved Project Euler problems. My code was all extremely ugly. Eventually I found a tutorial on Swing (Java's built-in GUI library) and tried to make something from it. The code exploded in terms of messiness. But then I found Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow was able to answer some of my questions on general GUI problems (via its archive of Q/As).

Due to the fact that I was tutoring some kids, I wanted to make a game to help with memorizing basic addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. Through about a week of hacking things together, I came up with something. I believe there were two files total: one with a main function, and one holding everything else. Naturally, it was a mess. But I didn't realize this. What I did realize, however, was that I wasn't generating problems with even frequency. I didn't know how to search this, so I didn't find anything I could use, so I asked a question on it. I'm hesitant to link that question, since I clearly show little understanding of the problem and of what Stack Overflow is really for. What I was able to show, however, was that I had worked on the problem.

Over the years, I asked more questions and answered some. But I mostly read current Q/As already on the site. I learned about something called "coding style." Also "conventions" and "good practice." I hadn't heard of them before. Gradually, the code I wrote began to become readable. Magic numbers started disappearing. Programs started becoming more than 2 files. Functions started getting better names. I started using the Event Dispatch Thread. I finally understood the value of having readable code. Strangely, this also leaked into my English language skills. I spent more time crafting sentences, attempting to make them understandable. I put in the effort to make my questions clean.

Eventually, I encountered something known as "Big Oh" notation. I was fascinated by it at first. I didn't understand what O(n) could even mean. Or O(n<sup>2</sup>), O(1), etc. Through Stack Overflow, I learned exactly what it means.

I ended up learning that there was more than just Java. There was this programming language known as Python. I went to learn Python. I later learned C++, recognizing that many people use it and that it wasn't an out-of-style language. I kept learning new programming languages and libraries.

When I started college, I learned that, due to my programming on my own (and mostly because of the knowledge gained from Stack Overflow), I had knowledge in Computer Science up to about the Junior level. This was as a Freshman. As I took required programming courses, I cringed at the required bad practices such as `using namespace std;` (which were put into header files we were required to use without editing). I realized that none of my current joys of programming could be possible without Stack Overflow.

Due to Stack Overflow, my entire view of programming changed. Programming was no longer simply a tool to accomplish things. Programming became the accomplishment. I learned to love the journey even more than the destination.

Answer (score 2):

Back in late 2011, fresh out off unemployment, I met this dude from a local Java group about this Android stuff. That it's going to get big, and we should start investing time on it. So, I decided it's time to dig on this mobile stuff. Bought my first phone, installed Eclipse IDE and studied for a month and a half with the help of StackOverflow. The Android book I studied was of [Wei Meng Lee](http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118017110.html). It was the best complete tutorial book at that time. But a book could not cover the whole thing. So, to get more details I would use StackOverflow as a reference, or if I want to get to know more about a certain Android API.

But Android references/tutorials back in 2011 were so scarce, including here on StackOverflow. Sometimes I couldn't get the answer I needed. But that didn't deter me on pursuing Android development. As I kept on playing with Android development, I was totally enjoying it and having fun. I came from a web development company as a PHP programmer, and in this little city here in Southeast Asia, no one was doing mobile development. So for me it was the most risky thing an unemployed person like me could be doing. No job, and no mobile development job posting. I'm starting to ponder and re-evaluate my current situation. Should I go back learning web development or continue with Android. I end up choosing the latter. Luckily after a month, the only Android job posting came up and I am the only applicant. So there my career on Android started.

Without StackOverflow as a reference to the Android book, I'm pretty sure it would deter me, made me feel hopeless and waste some precious time on the months learning Android. As I would probably go deep into forums or some old college .edu whitepaper sites. Android fragmentation on those years were so severe and the platform wasn't mature enough. The projects we're doing at that time was so demanding that we needed to go deep on the Android APIs, builds would break or R.java disappearing suddenly. Yeah, StackOverflow has been with me since the very start of my career.

So to give back on the StackOverflow community, I would help out on my free time during those days and help out fellow Android developers on their challenges.

One of the awesome things is the chat, I get to interact with other developers from other parts of the world. So thanks again to this site. Keep up the good job.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow helps me every time I encounter any programming-related problem I can't solve by myself (and another SE sites when it's not programming-related).

I've started visiting SO as I've started studying Computer Science at university. I had to write several programs and as every beginner, I encountered *a lot* of problems. Googling for manuals and documentation was almost mandatory, but what to do, when there is a full page of errors that shouldn't be there?

Most of the times (if not always), I ended up looking for solutions here, and SO helped me not only solve my errors, but also understand what I did wrong. I am still studying, and still running into some problems I can't solve. And SO is always here to help me.

I am not only a student, but also an intern in a software company. When I was applying for the job, I was searching for random interesting Q&A here, from which I might learn something interesting that might help me. It did. And yes, I still run into errors or issues I can't solve by myself, and I can still rely on SO to find a solution I need, with some explanation why it happened.

Stack Overflow helps me in school, work, and also with my hobby projects. It doesn't matter on what I am working currently, there is almost a 100% chance that if I get into a problem, SO helps me solving it. One more time, thank you everyone! I learn something new every time I visit this site!

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to pinpoint when I started using StackOverflow, but there was a moment when I suddenly realised that all of my technical answers were coming from the same website. After a while I even realised that I could actually contribute myself and help others - after all, isn't it fair to give back for all of this stuff I get for free almost every day?

I pondered for some time how to help and then one day I was fighting with [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) and found someone else who had the same problem that I had recently come across. So I went ahead and submitted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12371007/1663001). Then something awesome happened... I received some upvotes and even an accept! That little green tick meant I'd helped someone and that felt amazing.

So fast forward a few years and I now find myself regularly looking for questions I can answer, but why do I still do it? Is it so I get to see the little *+10* in the nav bar? No, I realised that my contributions were making **me** a significantly better developer. I was even picking up things that I'd probably never have looked at otherwise. Even the areas where I felt I was very good at have improved dramatically.

It's not just the technical aspect too. I think I'm now an even better technical communicator. Interacting with other users on this site (both good and bad ones) has allowed me to improve those skills immeasurably.

It's definitely worth mentioning that I've been in software development for many years (including back in the day when we didn't have SO and had to rely on other [not-so-good](http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/) resources!) This is a corollary to my theory that you can never stop learning in this space, but also that you should embrace that new knowledge and not be afraid that you are falling behind.

So aside from the 1300 or so upvotes I've given to various users, here's a big thanks to everyone who has ever posted content here. Without you all, we'd be much worse off!

Answer (score 2):

Stack Overflow has been, and continues to be, a great source of knowledge for problems I never thought would have simple answers.

For example, I've struggled with a nagging problem for a while, involving a family of websites I've been maintaining. Deployment is done via manually copying files to the site via FTP, but some of the pages are generated via an in-house CMS, and some are built by an admin tool and used as shared components of other pages.

When making changes that span all pages, I thought there was no way to search through all the CMS-generated and component files to find any missing lines or missed updates. In addition, I was struggling with figuring out if any deployed files were missed during our painstaking manual FTP deployment procedure.

That is, until I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16957078/410342), and realized I could just grep it. Derp.

That's going in my favorites, my bookmarks, and my on-screen sticky notes for sure. Finally, the one piece of deployment verification I've been desperately missing is there.

Thanks, Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

There are three points in which Stackoverflow influenced me a lot.

1. programming skills
2. english skills
3. a passion for science

In 2013 i started my apprenticeship as a programmer. Until this day i did never hear of stackoverflow and had 
barley no programming and english language experiences. Surley it does not take much time(maybee two weeks) 
since i discovered that most the time i searched an answer for my question, i came out on Stackoverflow. At the
beginning i tried to search for answers in german communities, because of my bad english skills. Soon i 
recognized that a programmer can not go without Stackoverflow and that its by far the best resource on the 
internet. So i also started to improve my englisch skills to use SO as much as i can.

Today i use Stackoverflow for almost two years. I stopped googeling my questions and started to type them directly
into the SO search. The website is always opened on my secound screen. As a result of using SO i improved my programming 
and my english knowledge. This helped me a lot to pass my apprenticeship.

Also the variety of StackExchange communities inspires me. Due to the hot network questions i discovered the 
other communities. One click on an interesting question on Physics Stack Exchange was enough to catch my interest
for science. Since then i read many physics questions & books in my spare time.

So you can see that Stackoverflow not only influced my working life, rather my whole life, in a positiv way.

And thats why i would say thank you to all people of the community.

THANKY YOU <3

Answer (score 2):

I started learning the R language as an undergraduate student. Most of my programming experience up to that point had been in Java and C, so a lot of my R code ended up looking something like this:

```
# Find the difference between each pair of elements in vector "x"
diffs <- c()  # Empty result vector
for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)) {
  diffs <- c(diffs, x[i+1] - x[i])  # Add i^th difference to result vector
}
```

While this code works, it's actually quite atrocious -- it reallocates the result vector at each iteration and is therefore terribly slow; even if I had pre-allocated the `diffs` vector it would still be quite slow compared to `diff(x)`, the built-in R function that computes pairwise differences. And so it is learning R -- you slowly learn tricks to avoid monstrously inefficient code and start using `for` less and less frequently, but often the best way to do something is to know about some built-in function that already does it for you (much more quickly than you could do it, because typically base R functions are implemented in C).

Since learning R involves learning about the vast array of built-in functionality that yields efficient code (both in length and running time), I found myself constantly searching the Internet for the best way to do common tasks. Unsurprisingly, Stack Overflow has often been the knowledge repository that helped me out. Need to split a vector into a list based on some grouping information? The Google query "[r] split vector into list" has top result [Split a vector into chunks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r), and the top answer suggests the `split` function. Need to find the pairwise maximum value between elements of two vectors of the same length? The Google query "[r] pairwise maximum" has top result [How can I take pairwise maximum between two vectors in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994543/how-can-i-take-pairwise-maximum-between-two-vectors-in-r), correctly suggesting the `pmax` function.

As an academic in the field of operations research, self-learning R has proven to be hugely beneficial to me -- I used the language in every single research project I did during my PhD at MIT, I co-developed [a MOOC](https://www.edx.org/course/analytics-edge-mitx-15-071x-0) that almost exclusively uses the R language, and the MBA course I teach as part of my lecturer position makes heavy use of the language. Now as an active contributor in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) on Stack Overflow, I still learn all the time from the wonderful community here. Many thanks to Stack Overflow for the key role it's played in me learning the R language!

Answer (score 2):

So I started programming back in 2011<sup>1</sup>. What originally got 
me interested was Minecraft modding. Now, I never really took any 
tutorials in Java; I just followed a tutorial on how to make a mod, so 
my coding sucked. It was absolutely *awful*. Fast forward a couple 
years, and it was still pretty bad. I'd still never taken any tutorials, 
and I could barely sort of make my own programs. So, I decided to take a 
mostly-online AP Computer Science course that used Java. Bad move. 
Between my previous knowledge, my inability to learn online, and (as I 
figured out later) the low quality of the course, I learned nothing 
within the first month except the existence of `double`s—and I also got 
terrible grades.

Then I discovered Stack Overflow.

I found that whenever I Googled a programming problem, I'd almost always 
end up at Stack Overflow. I started to browse the site, looking for 
interesting questions. Instead of reading my course's lessons, I would 
just read the top relevant questions here at SO. I got an account, and 
started answering questions. By the following month my code quality had increased drastically, I was top of the class with 100% on almost every assignment, and my AP Computer Science "teacher" said he often had to look up Java stuff because the way I solved the course's assignments was so much more advanced than what the course expected<sup>2</sup>.

Fast forward 'til now, and I occasionally help my dad with computer and coding things (by Googling his problem and looking through the SO links), I've become fluent in a couple programming languages (which I learned mostly at SO) and can code reasonably well in many more (SO as well), I have a small programming contract/job thingy (where I constantly use SO as a reference), and I'll likely be heading off to college next year to get a degree in software engineering (where I'm sure SO will be an invaluable resource).

I attribute most of my growth in programming to Stack Overflow; without this site, I doubt I would have decided to become a software engineer, and I would probably have gone into some field I disliked—because I now know I dislike pretty much everything except programming.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Actually I had done a little bit before that, but it 
was just extremely basic stuff in BASIC.</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>He wasn't very knowledgeable in Java, but still...</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Looking back at my old work, I realize that I *used* to be stupid.

Back in 2014, I set off to learn how to program. I started with the infamous language, Python, the language that my uncle uses and had recommended.

So, here I am, learning Python, and I become too lazy to touch the documentation. I had been told that Python is like writing English, and I think I took that a little bit too literally. My first project was going to be something that could "install" or really just move files from one place to another. Within the first two months, I was doing stupid things... like this:

```
def After_Install_Check(): 
    '''Function verify's the correct installation of the file'''
    File_Install(filepath, mode) 
    File_Access(filepath, mode) 
    if "File_Install" and "File_Access":
        return True,
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Yes, I know. ***I'm <s>not</s> incredibly ashamed of that.***

When I first came onto Stack Overflow, I was likely a pain. Here I come, all joyful, and I ask a question. I had asked my first question, which gave me a few up votes, and the answer was incredibly comprehensive. However, I had to be "smart", and start calling out how *it doesn't answer the question*, and, being an absolute royal pain. But I learned.

Since then, I've asked 27 more questions, learned another language (Java), and am starting to learn a third: Swift.

I've asked many questions, including: [Is storing Graphics objects a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370403/is-storing-graphics-objects-a-good-idea) and [Why does this Jython loop fail after a single run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239955/why-does-this-jython-loop-fail-after-a-single-run) They are all really helpful, and have let me build my skills, and more importantly, understand the languages that I know. I know them well enough that I would consider myself fairly competent in them.

**So what about today?**

Today, I'm able to do much more than I imagined when I first started learning. Without Stack Overflow, I would've likely continued on doing incredibly stupid things. Today, I'm developing my first application that I hope to deploy, a Graphics app that <s>hopes</s> is better than MS Paint. I've written high-level APIs to help simplify lower-level tasks that I've shared with my friends, and that have helped them learn as well.

Oh, and most importantly, Stack Overflow has also taught me to read the documentation. :D

Comment: If you're from Python , and you read this (and my horrible code), tell me before you come, so that I can run away :P

Answer (score 2):

> How Did Stack Overflow Help You?

TL;DR; It took me from an enthusiastic uneducated php learner to a working web programmer.

When I started learning about computers, somewhere about 16, mashing my first parts onto a asus motherboard and fooling around with FreeBSD, I had no freaking idea about anything relating to computers. It took me some years to start being interested, and then my father (himself a self-thought web web-programmer) hinted me to my first web-related job. Later on, he got me on a full-fledged web-application contract, which was (and is) how I actually make money to live.

**OOP**

Somewhere after I started this job, I started using SO. First by answering some questions, which I was (still am) pretty bad at. After some time, I got the chance to learn about things, being infused by questions and answers alike. The first big step was OOP. I can't remember the question or answer, but at some point, I realized that if I was to succeed in delivering the project to the clients (my father was not anymore on the project, I was and am alone on that one now) I had to leave behind procedural programming, which was everything I've ever been shown, and program faster and better. There OOP cam around, and saved my life. Suddenly, I moved from thousand-lines-long functions to smaller objects, easier to maintain and refactor.

**Namespaces**

The second part was namespaces. That was crazy. As much as OOP changed the way I could think about programming, namespaces revolutioned the way I thought about thinking about programming. Suddenly, code got organized in an organic way. Parts of the application began to make sens when grouped together.

**Source Control**

The third part was when I learned about source control, and how I could not really manage programming without it. I started using bitbucket, later on github, started to have code which I could actually deploy on different machines servers way easier. At the same time I started using local development environments, hinted by comments on how source control and local development was mandatory.

**php storm**

then, somewhen, someone commented on a question, just saying `php storm is so great`. never having heard about it, I googled on it, landed on their webpage and tried the ide which now allows me to code better, more solid, less error-prone code.

And even since it is only getting better. In the process, I learned about autoloading, since I started having so much files for classes, interfaces etc. I learned about best practices on file structures, conventions on naming. I started hanging out on php's chat, where I learned countless invaluable hints, got convinced to learn about nginx, understood that apache was in fact one amoungsdt *others*...

### Stack overflow allowed me to make people happy about the software I code for them while earning enough money to live a marvelous life

Honest. It may sound cheesy, but a large part of the fact that I earn money to pay my rent and drink beer with friends without being **stressed out** about it is because of the invaluable advice I got from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I have started programming in Php/Python and had many issues everyday while developing applications. When I  googled for the problem hoping to find a solution, there were many blogs/websites/forums which had various solutions for the problem. Stack Overflow was also there in those results, mostly in the  top.

I have started using Emacs/elisp and had many issues with emacs customisation. When I googled for the problem only Stack  Overflow showed up  most  of the times.

I feel that there are very few resources for elisp when compared to a language like php or Python. Without Stack Overflow, without those  geeks who  wrote those extremely  useful  answers, it might have  been  very difficult  to learn  and get  good at  elisp/emacs.

Answer (score 2):

I heavily <sub><sup>[ab]</sup></sub>used Stack Overflow for several years to find answers to a wide variety of questions I had about [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) development whilst at university, and it wasn't until near the end of my final year that I finally made an account. This was my chance to give something back to the community, or so I thought...

...I then landed my first job a couple of days after signing up - a web development job, at that, a hobbyist passion I'd had for many years - and completely forgot about Stack Overflow altogether.

[image: ...]

Spring and Summer swiftly went past, and it was well into Autumn before I rediscovered Stack Overflow. With tags like [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), this magical place appeared to have answers to the all the questions I had that other people had asked in the past.

Then one by one new questions were appearing - questions which *I* knew how to answer. Eventually after shying away for a while I answered one; then I answered another; then another... The internet points started rolling in, but this was more than just that, there was constructive criticism as well. My answers were working, but they weren't perfect, but the community guided me through how to improve. Questions I didn't even ask were being answered by the people who were taking time to read the answers I was posting, and quickly the quality of both my answers here and my own code outside of Stack Overflow was improving greatly.

How *does* Stack Overflow help me? It continues to make me a better programmer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't remember the last time I had any other site than Stack Overflow as the top three results when searching for programming related terms.

Stack Overflow has helped me a lot in understanding how many of the components in the .NET stack works, how to properly use them, and what to avoid. I've also learned a great deal about (anti)patterns, good (and bad) practices, and to just keep things as simple as possible.

Since I work with web applications on a regular basis Stack Overflow hasn't been a stranger to the different tags such as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)([jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery),[angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) with friends), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and so on. I would say that Stack Overflow was the primary resource for learning [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs). Not only the Q/A portion of the site, but also the friendly guys over at the C# chat.

Whilst I'm not in the business of asking question, I still use Stack Overflow as a reference when there's something I need to look up. Most of the times the offical documentation (if any) lacks proper (close to) real world examples and common usage. Whenever I have the ability and knowledge, I try to answer questions as good as possible.

I guess when I am going to ask my first question, it has to be a good one right?

Thanks Stack Overflow for being such an awesome community with all the great people that hold huge amounts of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** StackOverflow helped me to understand the MVC Pattern and the oo-programming in general.

It was at a sunny day in 2012 when I started learning Java. The very first steps were with Swing and some really simple *Click there and this label changes* exercises.

As I didn't even know about classes, patterns etc. I've written everything into one class and most of the code directly into the main method. Of course I was using methods. I was really proud of my two or three functions called `init()` or `method1()`.

After some errors, my code worked and I thought: easy, that's it. But then, my mentor said *Now we make this code MVC-Pattern compliant. Let's try it for yourself first.*

So I started browsing the web about MVC and found this answer:

[What goes into the "Controller" in "MVC"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015813/what-goes-into-the-controller-in-mvc)

At first the answer is really short and simple, but at that time, the *conversation form*, which was used in the answer really helped me to understand the really basics of it. On this base I started reading other articles about the pattern and I could refactor my code to fit the MVC-pattern.

During my research I saw other experienced developers coding-styles and I began to understand the object oriented programming for the first time.

So my first contact with StackOverflow was the day I started developing in Java. And it was also the first time StackOverflow helped me.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of years ago after remaining unemployed for over an year, I started teaching myself programming. I started learning [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) (as there were a few vacancies in some of the companies) after learning it about a month, not to mention all the help I got from ***Stack Overflow***, I landed a job but being a beginner I was given a couple of months to prove I could be valuable to the firm.

I soon realized how little I knew about the language and how vast and competitive this web development world is. I remember working day and night (which I still do :P) to improve my knowledge, coding structure to follow, so that I don't get fired when my code was reviewed. ***Stack Overflow community*** helped me a lot in this and somehow almost every time whenever I was stuck with a problem ***Stack Overflow*** was there to help me out.

Today, thanks to ***Stack Overflow***, I have a job, I am a valuable member in the company, I am working on a big project, learning about database administration, cloud computing, etc. I didn't stop learning; there is lot to learn. I recently started learning [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop), seeking help from ***Stack Overflow*** as always :)

***Thank you Stack Overflow and every user who spared some time, to help out people like me.***

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any particular moment when I thought Stack Overflow had changed my life. I have too many! I'm only going to comment on one topic that it has affected my daily life and still does.

I was never very good at reading tools' manuals. I first knew about Git from a friend like 5 years ago, when I was starting my studies as a Software Engineer. I only learnt the basics: commit, push, change branch... And I was happy. But as many of you will probably know, Git has so much power that can be unleashed. I'm also a curious person, so when I wanted to make something magic happen with the repository, I just typed what I wanted to do in the Google search box, clicked the first Stack Overflow link, and there it was. Some unselfish user had wrote the command or commands to make the magic happen, and a detailed and user-friendly explaination of what was going on. I have learnt so much about Git from that. It's my favourite daily tool, the first thing I install on a new PC.

Today, in every team I work on I'm the Git guru. I'm the one spreading the word about git's magic and answering teammates' questions just like Stack Overflow helped me resolve.

I can say that all this advanced knowledge of Git has changed my life. And Stack Overflow made it possible. So thank you very much, SO! And have another great 10 million questions!

Answer (score 2):

**No One to Ask In a Hardware Company**

I am a C# developer in a company selling semiconductor manufacturing machines. Simply speaking, it is a hardware company. My colleagues are experts of hardware, hydromechanics, spectrometer. They are great in their fields, but none of them know C#. I was assigned to a new project to create an user interface using C# [WPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation). I am the first one in the company to use C#, and I had no colleagues to ask about C#, so I learned C# solely from the Internet. When I encountered problems, I searched my problems using Google, and usually I found an answer on Stack Overflow.

With the help of Stack Overflow, the first version of the software was released. And I found that I could answer some questions on Stack Overflow, so I started answering questions.

**Readability Counts**

However, Stack Overflow helped me again when I answered questions, because my code in my answers were reviewed. This is especially important for me, because no one else in my hardware company could provide useful feedback on my code. When I posted bad code to answer a question, my answer was downvoted. If the code was useful, it was upvoted.

I could compare my code and other people's code. So I learned what is good code by reading the best answer. I was amazed by how clever the people coded their idea in their answers. **I learned that readability is very important in coding.** I used to think that shortest code is the best; the purpose of a routine is to minimise the number of lines of the program. But now I know letting other people to understand my code is much more important.

Thank you all of you of sharing knowledge and helping others freely!

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the numerous useful and interesting things I have learnt by reading answers written by people far smarter than myself, Stack Overflow has started to become a proxy for my (increasingly faulty) long term memory.

On at least two occasions (that I can remember, but don't trust that) I have googled for a solution to a problem I have encountered at work and have been shown Stack Overflow answers to a question that ***I myself*** asked some years ago, but had completely forgotten about. I get to be highly critical of my younger self's grammar and writing style *and* get the answer to my problems!

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow helped me in various situations to clarify tough questions coming up from my colleagues where I was unsure of giving an answer.

I'm rarely asking on the site, but I am merely trying to give answers.
There were some questions originated from colleagues coming up to me, and I've tried consolidating and asking here:

- [What is the actual purpose of std::type_info::name()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861760/what-is-the-actual-purpose-of-stdtype-infoname)
- [Eliminating instantiation of useless destructor calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909598/eliminating-instantiation-of-useless-destructor-calls) Even without any accepted answers the comments were helpful to clarify.

Another sample is where I was providing a canonical way to show how to refactor some interface inter-dependecies:

- [How can I remove/refactor a «friend» dependency declaration properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492132/how-can-i-remove-refactor-a-friend-dependency-declaration-properly).

I've been originally posting this on our company internal wiki, though it turned out to be non-proprietary knowledge and is useful to be made public. Stack Overflow turned out to be the right place to publish.

Last but not least, Stack Overflow was helpful for me solving very technically narrowed problems like I had with this question:

- [Expecting googlemock calls from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767131/expecting-googlemock-calls-from-another-thread)

Any of the above samples brought me or my companioning teammates further on challenging the real-world problems we've been seeing day by day.

We have improved our production code along the answers or commented suggestions, and our products are well achieved as high quality in the markets we're working on.

Most of my colleagues use Stack Overflow as a constant (re)source for high-quality answers for their day to day upcoming problems, not only mine of course, but some of them might got incented by me giving them answers or links directing here.

Answer (score 1):

I just got an A in my Computer Science GCSE, which I needed to get into my preferred 6th form centre. This will hopefully get me into a good university, and get started with computer science as my job.

One particular case stands out, I needed to count the number of lines in a file, and Stack Overflow gave me short one liner that was better than looping through the whole file. It was a simple thing, as a lot of the best questions are, but it had a well presented and clear answer.

This prompted me to sign up to Stack Overflow (almost 2 years ago) and upvote the question and answer, and even though I'm not active here, I just reached 10k on Ask Ubuntu, and I have 25k network wide.

I'm starting my AS level Computer Science at a leading 6th form college and I'm sure I will be using Stack Overflow, and the other coding sites in the network, even more than before.

I'm also hoping to pursue Computer Science as a career - from what I've gathered the answers already here (sometimes even more so than asking) can save a large amount of time.

Of course there are many, many other questions I've looked at - and I've even answered a few - but that one liner stands out to me. I have it saved in a file of useful code snippets, and I still use it in my programming.

Hopefully this site will be around through my life - and still here for future generations. For the time I've been coding, I've always had Stack Overflow to help me, and I don't want to try and code without it!

Answer (score 1):

## Stack Overflow helped me become a Web developer

During the summer, back in 2013, I've taken a basic summer class called *"Introduction to Client-Side Programming"*. Being around a year in to my university's computer science programming, I had enough experience to quite easily understand and get a good grade in the class.

Although I really fell in love with web development and JavaScript and wanted to learn more about it. So I offered to become the [TA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_assistant) of the class in the fall semester, and I really enjoyed helping other students *"get it"*. Then in the start of ~2014 I've found Stack Overflow, which really opened my eyes to not only how many people are interested in client-side programming, but how skilled people are at it. And I learned quickly not only how to do it better, but the proper way to do it.

Before Stack Overflow, web development was simply something I knew how to do. But today it's one of my best skills, so much so that all my jobs/internships I've been at where all web development. I feel that Stack Overflow helped me a lot from being a "*so-so*" web developer into a "*decent*" ("*good?*") web developer.

Of course I understand that I have much to learn. But through answering/asking questions on Stack Overflow helped me learn so much more than a basic class during the semester can teach you. I don't even know where I would be today if Stack Overflow wasn't around.

Answer (score -1):

Buried within the vast panoply of answers in SO are some real gems of arcane knowledge that cannot be obtained anywhere else.

I dip into this pool to deliver results that amaze and astound. People say "*Wow! How did you get that to work...?*". The secret is combining the knowledge contained within this vast corpus with one's own expertise.

For example, things that I have put to excellent use, are:

- [Making scripts that can execute on any system from a network mounted file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510688/single-script-to-run-in-both-windows-batch-and-linux-bash)
- [Using colours in batch file messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file)

When [sufficiently advanced technology can appear to be magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws), SO allows practitioners to sprinkle that bit of magic dust on a solution.

Answer (score -6):

SO provides me a lot of things. It provides me solutions to my problems. At the same time, it also provides such a great and helpful community.

Moreover, it taught me how to be self-dependent and not just ask for others' help without trying anything myself.

Answer (score -6):

When I was in my first job, I had the first issue in [Android 4.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Ice_Cream_Sandwich) (Ice Cream Sandwich) years ago and I didn't know how to resolve it, so looking for a solution in Google I met Stack Overflow and the answer of my problem.

From then on, I frequently used this page. I have opened many issues with many answers and also helped to resolve many problems. I'm better professional thanks to Stack Overflow and all the community. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -10):

Not a lot.

I started my computer science degree thinking this site could help me learn how to code and help me succeed in school. I tried to ask my question the smarter way I can and what did I receive? Nothing, except a...

We aren't here to teach. –  @SXXX

So what are here for, if it's not to ask questions about what we want to understand and get smart answers?

This site sadly seems to go be used by a few people who take the big-head...

Comment: That is not a great story to celebrate but I do hope you get some swag anyway...

Comment: ;) kind of! Trying to create a check list to ask the mve, expecting a blame, having a blame...

Comment: comment before downvoting

Comment: No, voting is anonymous and the tooltip on the voting button explain reasons for voting. Above that voting on meta is different.

Comment: I do not agree with you,  how can one improve his answer when all he know is that he is downvoted?What strange community is the stackoverflow one.

Comment: The down vote says *the answer is not useful* that is enough of a comment I would think. The question asks  *how did SO help you*, it didn't ask *how did or didn't SO help you and please share all your positive and negative experiences about that*. And the community is not strange as we have proven to be one of the most popular sites. That popularity is due the moderation this community employs. Enough users assume on a daily basis that anything goes on Stack Overflow. And to make commenting  mandatory is discussed over and over again and rejected as many times. Search on meta for a good read.

Comment: The (direct) teaching/learning part is a common expectation, and something Stack Overflow (the company) ought to expand into.

Comment: We _are_ here to help you and answers are supposed to "teach" you, not to _tutor_ you personally though. That user is wrong in a way and that comment makes me look like [this](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/b3/e5/b3/b3e5b3ee7fb113ec86bac9bd32dc3de4--photo-story-creature-feature.jpg)

Answer (score -17):

How has Stack Overflow been helpful to me? Don't you mean, **How has oxygen been helpful to me?** Or Stack Exchange? Having failed to search and find such a question on meta.stackexchange.com, I'd like to give an Stack Exchange answer.

At the risk of giving something that was unwelcome in another thread, let me give a few points of detail here. And more specifically after experiencing beginnings of **autoimmune symptoms that were shut down completely by dietary adaptations.**

I don't want to belabor the obvious, but let me give a specific point. [The Paleo solution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0982565844) can be regarded as another dietary fad, and it is certainly treated as such by some. But the core insight, which is more clarified than complemented, is that *Homo sapiens sapiens* functions better or best under conditions that approximate, or approximate the benefits of, the conditions *Homo sapiens sapiens* is adapted to. Put that way, it appears obvious to the point of not being interesting, but perhaps with low-carb or no-carb precursors, few before it have said, "*Wwwaaaaiiiitt a minute*... is the human race biologically adapted to consuming large volumes of carbohydrates?"

Features of the Paleo "lifestyle" (I use the terms with reservations as) include:

- **Diet:** Cut down the food groups substantially. Eat vegetables and fruits in that order and in volume; eat healthy amounts of meat; there are a few eggs and special cases, but that whole grain organic loaf of whole grain bread is, like its pre-domesticated ancestors, waging chemical warfare against its predators--specifically including **you**. Eating large amounts of largely flavorless seeds or grains is a dietary hack (the comparative lack of flavor being a red flag this is not something the digestive tract is optimized for), and it has *nasty* consequences.
- **Exercise:** To simplify slightly, don't focus on aerobic exercise three times per week. Try to build for strength, although walking and other non-weight-lifting activity can be very valuable.
- **Sleep:** Get well-rested, and if you can't wake up to sunlight, [spend a little extra on a light alarm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0093162RM) that's a whole lot better surrogate for a sunrise than a regular alarm clock in a pitchdark room, at o-dark-thirty.
- **Sunlight:** Sun*burn* is bad and probably carcinogenic. Sun*light* is necessary and good, and there's a reason doctors massively prescribe the sunlight surrogate of vitamin D to urban dwellers. At least on the "out of Africa" theory, there being others, the reason that some of us are fair-skinned, or for that matter much of any color than black, is that during the Ice Age people migrated from Africa to a Mediterranean that was then colder than much of the Arctic is now. Apart from the question of how much sunlight there is, migrant humans bundled up heavily, and had to adapt to vastly less vital sunlight. Skin that was dark to adapt to heavy sunlight became light to let in precious sunlight when there was little available (but can in most cases tan on exposure to sun). However, urban and suburban dwellers who do not frequent e.g. beaches, however fair-skinned, spend problematically much time indoors and sunlight-deprived, and are candidates for doctors' vitamin D prescriptions, a surrogate for real, honest sunlight. Vitamin D may be incomplete as far as surrogates go; people need exposure to sunlight, and merely addressing a chemical deficiency doesn't provide the whole of what sunlight provides. It is fairly known that sufficient light deprivation can be a factor in depression; it's better to be light-deprived and taking a vitamin D prescription than light-deprived and not taking a vitamin D prescription, but neither compares to real, honest sunlight.

And the question arises: what has that to do about computers?

I spent a lot of time trying something that was basically impossible in sitting outside with my [MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro). And, especially in the summer, there are two basic problems with extended use of a MacBook Pro in the summer sun:

1. Good sunlight, at least in direct exposure, makes a MacBook Pro hot, hot enough to be hard to touch and hot enough that the fans are swamped. Are you familiar with *[MechWarrior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MechWarrior)* games where one of the dangers you cope with is building up too much heat? *We're talking the same stuff here.*
2. Displays that are built to be very bright indoors can be dim enough outdoors so that reading becomes significantly harder. (Note: "Bright" by indoor standards usually means significantly less light, i.e., visible photons, than even a cloudy day outdoors.) I had substantial difficulties reading the screen on my MacBook Pro, even when with my unfair advantages as a webmaster I took advantage of usability features to compensate.

Now it perhaps isn't Paleo to be on a computer in the first place, but it may be better Paleo-wise to spend one's non-work, discretionary computer time outside. Some newer devices, such as iPads, are less painful in sunlight. I do not say that they are graceful, because they are still difficult to read in good sunlight, and prolonged use in direct sunlight shows they can overheat just as much as a Mac. (And for someone who heavily uses the Linux / Unix / Mac command line, my preferred way of getting work done is easier done using [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) under a decent version of Windows than with an iPad that hasn't been cracked.)

What I did find, after [a PaleoHacks.com question where I ended up doing most of the research](https://www.paleohacks.com/technology/how-can-i-get-a-laptop-that-works-well-with-paleo-sun-32311#answer_194167), is that there is in fact a well-established category of computers properly intended for outdoor use: "rugged" computers are not all created equal, but if you want a computer that will be sane under primarily outdoor conditions, you will do much better starting with [searching for rugged computers](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=rugged%20computers) than anything mainstream.

I personally purchased a GD8000 that had been maxed-out in hard drive space and memory; its 1024x768 screen may be an old-fashioned low-resolution, but it looks great in sunlight and I can see vastly more than on the brightest settings on a 1920x1200 MacBook Pro. (I'm not clear on how all their technologies work, but it's not just brighter; there has been significant engineering...

...**and I consider Stack Overflow to have given the computer to me, not because of [Paleo Hacks](http://paleohacks.com), [but because of a thread that happened to be on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/968488/is-there-any-way-to-squeeze-more-performance-out-of-a-vintage-itronix-gd8000-lap). I had upgraded from the provided Windows 7 to Windows 10, and under that was trying a virtualized [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)), and had not noticed that once-snappy response had slowed to the point that I couldn't get work done; I was easily waiting five seconds for an <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to pull another window. But something like fifteen minutes after reading [a first-class answer that explained my orders-of-magnitude problematic graphics processor](https://superuser.com/questions/968488/is-there-any-way-to-squeeze-more-performance-out-of-a-vintage-itronix-gd8000-lap#answer-968514) had me restoring Windows 7, turning off graphics-hungry features, and restoring [my favorite old Aqua-tinted Ubuntu Maverick VM](https://CJSHayward.com/aqua) as well as migrating from Cinnamon Mint to [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce), all of the sudden my rugged model works and is snappy again. And I can use it for almost everything I use my Mac for. Meaning a nice interface where I use the command line for Django, [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)), and other things where I wouldn't be where I am now. (I just published *[Reactive Programming with JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783558555)* this past week; it has an entirely appropriate two-star review for its first review, written by a very disappointed reader who was disappointed it covered React, but not Bacon.js--the editors overruled my request to put React, the only framework covered at any length, in the title, and I've said "We've started with a two-star review. Could we change the title?") All things considered, I am glad to Stack Overflow for helping me write a book that I hope will get better reviews when purchased by readers interested in React, and I am grateful to Stack Exchange / Super User for a computer that lets me work outside as much as I want, and without which my computer would be dead in the water. (Even if it's a marine model, and designed to tolerate a cup of water being poured over the keyboard.)

**For both Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, the question of how they've been helpful to me is the question of how oxygen has been helpful to me.** I haven't tried to pull out a single story of heroic answers on Stack Overflow proper, but they're better than I have any right for.

**Three cheers for Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange Umbrella!**

Comment: @PeterMortensen: This edit bumps up the worst scoring answer on a 6-year-old question to the frontpage of Meta, for what? Some wikipedia links? Imo, it'd be better to leave something this old alone.