# What is my first / last name?

Tags: support, 10m-questions-milestone

Today I received the long-awaited email:

[image]

I eagerly opened up the email, then followed the link to the form:

[image]

As I began to fill out the form, I got very confused. What does `Your First / Last name` mean? I filled out the logical answer: `FirstName / LastName`. Later I reflected on it... was I supposed to choose one *or* the other?

[image]

Comment: Seeing as the form is primarily to get your mailing address, it stands to reason that the desired format would be `John Doe`, as in "Your first and last name," as it would appear on a shipping label.

Comment: @Doorknob ... Well then. I may be getting a package labeled as `John / Doe` sometime. (not actually `John Doe`, but my name)

Comment: At first glance I thought I was on the Puzzling SE.

Comment: It must be for people who lack a last name! (Such people exist)

Comment: I hope that page can deal with people whose Last name is Zero...

Comment: @PM2Ring It will result in the package being sent to their NAN.

Comment: Good luck guys. My last name is **; DROP TABLE 'users';**

Comment: At first I expected this question to be related to [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).  It's not quite, but that article would still apply.

Comment: This question is making me check my inbox again and again in hope of getting a similar mail.. :D

Comment: @user2875404 I didn't know what the form was saying. What you see in this post was **exactly** what I thought. The expected answer didn't even enter into my head.

Comment: @KenWhite: it is a *very* odd way of asking for someone's name.  I'd probably just have put my name, but I'd have been concerned that it wasn't what they meant.  Why doesn't it just say "Your name" ?

Comment: @ajacian81 How has no one posted the [XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/327/) yet?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Ignore the slash; this form was created by a former Unix programmer, and those bastards love slashes.

[image]

Pretend it's a + or & or "and" and write your first *and* last names, like so:

> Justin Hacklefeather

Unless your first and last names are something else, in which case write those instead.

Comment: Darn... hopefully there's nothing wrong with the fact that I already submitted a `Justin / Hacklefeather`...

Comment: what if we  have middle name too

Comment: @shog9 I see OP received two mails. I did too. Why and what to do with them?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Probably because you posted one answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303045/3049655) and another [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303988/3049655)

Comment: I guess so, but is it sufficient to fill in one?

Comment: You could have just asked for "name". "First name / last name" is not only confusing but extremely Americentric.

Comment: Agreed, just say "Please enter your name (this is for the shipping label)" Then they can enter whatever they want to appear on the shipping label.

Comment: (A programmer should know better!!)

Comment: @PatrickHofman technically, you should fill both of them, as both the cases includes the t shirt size and one _may_ opt to have two different sizes (L and XL) for two shirts. [I did the same, btw].

Comment: @PatrickHofman seems [bluefeet says the same](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you#comment249171_303988) as my opinion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'd say "Eurocentric" as that's the naming tradition in Europe and places it has heavily influenced (e.g. the Americas)

Comment: @PCLuddite: Well I was going for the author's country of origin but, okay, Westerncentric then :)

Comment: The whole concept is nameocentric.  Those who followed in the footsteps of Prince and adopted symbols will be highly offended.

Comment: @PatrickHofman and SouravGhosh .. [TimPost confirmed it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey#comment249750_303045) ...

Comment: @PCLuddite: I'm from New Zealand (not technically in Europe, but influenced by it in pretty much the same way as the US) and I'd have been puzzled.  I suspect this really is an Americanism.

Comment: Do you know when the packages will be sent out? If not, will we be notified when the packages are sent?

Comment: @Justin [No notifications will be sent](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307016/is-it-possible-to-track-the-shipment-of-swag).

Comment: @GNKeshava I wasn't asking about tracking information; I was asking for a meta post / notification on SE inbox about it. The problem is that I have no idea if the swag has shipped yet; for all I know, it could have been stolen. Also, depending on how long it takes, I may change addresses before it arrives as I am a university student.

Comment: @Justin You are right... SE notification/mail also would've been nice...

Comment: It'd be nice if we had a better way of keeping folks informed of stuff like this, but... We don't. [I recommend finding a good friend to talk to while you wait](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/2010/04/19).

Comment: ... I finally realized that you may have made a pun on "slashes" so I google image searched the image.... Suddenly it makes a lot more sense why you put that image in here...

Answer (score 8):

That's just to go on the shipping label. Usually, stuff will still get to you even though the name is wrong. The postal system is designed to be flexible. You could probably put William Hackenschleimer on there and you would still get your "swag". The exception would be if it was sent using a courier, and proof of ID is required to receive your goods. But I doubt it.

Comment: I did this once. I used an internet alias for shipping and then I was out during delivery. I had to pick up the parcel from the post depot and when they asked for ID I was really in trouble. Can't even remember how I got around it in the end but I was lucky. Always use your real name.

Comment: Oh yeah the bloke let me have it because my address is on my driving licence (the ID I used). However, he shouldn't have done, because that address on that card is unverified. I was lucky, as previously mentioned.

Comment: Gotta agree with Lightness here; getting the address wrong may be OK, but getting the name wrong will likely result in the package being held in my experience.

Comment: I recently had an eBay package delayed as I used the incorrect name, and that was *before* they asked for ID! Always use your real name for post...

Comment: No such problems here. If there's a package for my wife, the delivery guy just says "package for Mrs Lister" and they don't even look at me in a funny way if I take it.

Comment: In the US, it's the opposite; names mean very little here, and addresses are the final decider. The form is pretty americentric indeed ;)

Comment: For delivery outside the US you have to provide a contact telephone number. Get that bit correct. I went to to the Postal Depot to collect countersigned photos for my new passport, arriving by registered post. The only ID I was able to show was my Passport. Which the guy noticed had expired... the entire reason for what I was trying to collect. I had to arrange to have it "redelivered".

Answer (score 6):

As implied before in other answers, the name really doesn't matter for the company; it is only a means for the receiving end to get the package to the right person.

Imagine if you let it be delivered at the office. The deliverer won't care where he delivers it, as long as it's the correct building, and so he leaves it at the desk. Then that is where the name actually comes into play, so make sure people know it's you when they read the name you put on it.

Comment: I once mailed to a campus address. (without knowing) I used the guy's company name. Usually worked fine, but sometimes it didn't. I've since started using his 'real name' instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a comment and a wish than an answer, but...

for non-native English speakers like me, first & last name might be confusing. Sometimes, when asked, I am mixing them (and gives my family name incorrectly as my first name in web forms).

I would suggest :

Your First & Last (i.e. family) name : (for example *Alan Turing*)

Comment: Your name doesn't strike me as causing confusion to what the first and what the last name is.

Comment: Really? What's confusing about first & last name? (and I'm not a native English speaker myself)

Comment: If your name is "John Francis Something", in spanish your first name is "John" and your last name is "Francis" while your family name would be "Something". If you talk about your full name, you say "John Francis" (your first & last name, "nombres" in spanish) "Something" (your family name, "apellido" in spanish). I don't think @Basile speaks spanish at all, just trying to show that this is not the same in every place in the world.

Comment: @Eric Martinez - This is true for many countries. the terms `Family name` and `Full name` or personal name , are much more correct . ( some people, like myself, have two personal names ( first and  Second = full ) and two Family names . Now I am in China , where the concept of first and last name is also very elusive... But in English-speaking countries that is not common .