# Revision history doesn't reflect the previous format

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

I recently made an [edit to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4096294/1793718). Before editing, it was displayed like this,

[image: Screenshot1]

After the edit, the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4096294/revisions) doesn't show the formatting difference,

[image: Screenshot_2]

<sub>Click to show enlarged image</sub>

You can see the revision history image above that the *before* and *after* content in the first post is not showing the unformatted links. Only the side-by-side markdown tab shows the content I changed. But why doesn't the  side-by-side tab and the original post show the unformatted links?

Comment: as explained in the answer you accepted, but with the addition that we don't store baked html in the post history, which would be required to see the difference in your case.

Comment: So... why isn't that a link only answer? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to edit direct links to posts on the same site if you post today:

[How to tell if an email from Stack Overflow is genuine?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306548/how-to-tell-if-an-email-from-stack-overflow-is-genuine)

because the post rendering engine detects that the url is from the same site the post is on and therefor renders the title automagicaly. In the preview the html is the same, so there are no differences.

Notice that this also works for links outside of the current site:

[How to write named queries with xml in Hibernate/JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051598/how-to-write-named-queries-with-xml-in-hibernate-jpa)

> ```
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051598/how-to-write-named-queries-with-xml-in-hibernate-jpa
> ```

But it doesn't work for links to posts of other SE sites:

https://superuser.com/questions/973265/how-to-run-the-awk-command-in-windows-7

To get that rendered nicely you have to fallback to

> ```
> [How to run the awk command in Windows 7?][1]
>
>  [1]: https://superuser.com/questions/973265/how-to-run-the-awk-command-in-windows-7
> ```

which renders as follows:

[How to run the awk command in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/973265/how-to-run-the-awk-command-in-windows-7)

The reason that answer you found didn't show the title is due to the age of the post: it was posted in 2010, probably before this friendly title link functionality was introduced. You could have made any 6 character edit to that post and after submitting the rendered html would have been fixed.

So, to summarize: you are editing the mark-up in the exact same manner as the automatic conversion will do. For that reason no difference is indicated in the side-by-side view because there is no difference in the html produced. You do see a difference if you select the *side-by-side-markdown* tab.

Comment: But why didn't the post automatically render the URL's properly before my edit? I wouldn't have edited the post if it had automagically rendered the title. (Both the post and URL belong to same SE site)

Comment: @Lucky Perhaps because the markdown->html conversion has changed in the five years since the previous revision of that post to include what rene describes, and that conversion is only run once for each revision.

Comment: @TZHX exactly that, and edited that in my answer.

Comment: @rene and TZHX thanks for the explanation