# Is this email spam, or is João the one in charge of swag distribution?

Tags: support, 10m-questions-milestone

I just received this email from someone called João. In the email, he says that I need to fill in a google form so that Stack Overflow can send the 10m questions swag to me.

This sounds really suspicious. The sender isn't someone well-known at all. I thought it would be Jeff Atwood or Tim Post but instead, someone I have never heard of sent this email to me.

Moreover, I have received my swag already, just a few weeks ago! How come there is another one?

But then I saw that the email address is joao[at]stackoverflow[dot]com. So I guess it *is* someone from stack overflow. But why is he sending me another form to fill in, I already got the swag!

Is it a spam/phishing email that wants my address? If it is not, who is this guy and why is stack overflow sending me another swag?

Comment: Bah, It is from this guy http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/208518/jnat. See this post [What happened to that contest swag I was promised?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623). That is why you should read the complete mail :P

Comment: Well, Jeff doesn't work for Stack Overflow any more, so I don't think he'll be in charge of mailing out swag...

Comment: Just happened to see this post again, after I became a moderator. That guy is perhaps the most useful contact for any site moderator (after Shog). :-)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It's not spam, it is from me!

I'm the one who's been handling the swags for a while now, so that's why you got it from me and not from someone better-known in the SO community.

The details for why you are getting more swag are in the e-mail I sent you, and there're also more details on [the Meta post I link to in the e-mail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623/208518).

For future reference, when in doubt, you can always check out [the team page](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team).

Comment: I also got an email for being mentioned in the [10 Million Questions - Let's Share Some Stories That the Number Doesn't Convey](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045) meta post which I am sure I have not been, and getting that mail 5 months after the usual 6 to 8 weeks period ended seemed weird too. Will I really get swag? A moderator notification on the inbox would help stopping people from thinking you are a scammer.

Comment: You are entitled to some swag, @nwp, yeah (I just checked). I know many of you may find this weird, especially because you are mostly passive winners, whose posts just happened to have helped someone else.

Comment: I was just reading [the management page](http://stackoverflow.com/company/management) and noticed the following under Jeff Atwood : "_He is one of the co-creators of [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/) and one of the co-founders of [Stack Overflow](http://stackexchange.com/)._".Is it really indented that the last link has text "Stack Overflow" even though it links to [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @CoolGuy One of the changes after the semi-recent round of venture capital was to return to the old company name of Stack Overflow, Inc.

Comment: @nwp [see this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623/294930) for insight on the timeline of delivery.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: that doesn't seem to have made its way into the footers yet, though?

Comment: The team page actually had me worried initially: the team page links to your profile page, and on your profile page you list your email address as jnat@, but you used a different one for the mail. Glad to see some confirmation here and thank you. (I forgot to comment when I first saw this question and answer, but I did see it before filling out the form. :))

Comment: I have not seen the email, so I don't know how credible it is, but the multiple bewildered / baffled reactions suggest to me that perhaps you should think some more about the delivery process.  Why are you using Google docs?  What are you doing to help recipients determine that the message is legit?  Having the link go to Stack Overflow instead of Google, even if it's just a redirect, would already help soothe users (though I would be suspicious of a redirect, too). Are you using SPF and DKIM to show that you are who you claim to be?

Comment: Have a look at Abby's answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306556/1328704), @tripleee. Long story short: this happens infrequently enough for us to not think it is worth implementing a new system, and not mind going through a few extra steps to let users make sure we're who we say we are.

Comment: Thank you JNat for going through the trouble to send me a T-shirt and a notebook, [they arrived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3OTl.jpg).

Comment: You're welcome, @nwp! I'm still working on getting the signed book copies, though (just mentioning that 'cause you're one of the 35 users whose name got drawn).