# Does Stack Exchange send emails related to swag?

Tags: support, email, swag

This email looks a little Phishy.   The link takes me to a google docs form.  How can I verify that this email is genuine?

It would be hard for me to verify much by the link, it's insecurly redirected through the same `.email` domain, starting with `http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/click?...`

[image]

Comment: Swat != swag...also I can think of some people who would be interested in being able to offer swat through email...

Comment: `stackoverflow.email` Lol. Showoffs. Looks fairly legitimate though

Comment: Although that's really a super cool phishing idea: send congratulatory E-Mails to people who just hit 20k, 50k, 100k... and link to a Google or Stack Overflow login form.

Comment: Heavily related, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321681/do-users-still-get-the-package-when-their-rep-reaches-100k, but 2 years old (however, there are a few answers from about a year ago indicating the swag was still being sent @ 100K)

Comment: @Pekka웃 It does require knowing their email, although not everyone has it private.

Comment: Related, though I'm not really seeing any tips that help you confirm this is your 100k bonus email, since it's from do not reply instead of an employee... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306548/how-to-tell-if-an-email-from-stack-overflow-is-genuine

Comment: As a note, the CMs **do** use Google forms to collect swag information from users. The whois for the domain looks fine, though https://www.godaddy.com/whois/results.aspx?domain=stackoverflow.email All of the info points to it being SE-owned

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338332/is-email-from-do-not-replystackoverflow-email-legit

Comment: It's not really quite a duplicate. That question doesn't have anything to do with swag.

Comment: @Catija:  But the email is coming from stackoverflow.email, which is emphasized in the OP.  The unspoken question then is, "is this email legit", which is answered in the dupe.

Comment: 100k rep and this is your first meta post haha! Anyway, congrats on your milestone - well done!

Comment: The only thing I found suspicious was the 4300+ emails in your inbox.

Comment: Worst "I hit 100k!" post ever! Seriously though, congrats, that's some achievement.

Answer (score 12):

First: Congratulations on reaching 100k!

The system sends an automated email when people reach that milestone and we are [sending automated emails via stackoverflow.email](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338334/1438) now. Your screenshot it looks like the email we send. I don't have access to the email logs at the moment, but I think you can safely try the link.

Other than the sketchy .email domain, is there anything we can change to make the offer less suspicious?

Comment: Maybe put in a secure link in the email, and better clarify that it was sent automatically, first? If possible, use an EV certificate for the form.

Comment: Email itself, and links within emails, are basically impossible to authenticate.  There's basically nothing you can put *in* the email that is convincing. If the form I had to fill out was obviously *controlled* by stackoverflow, (instead of google docs), I wouldn't have had this question.  If the form were hosted on stackoverflow, or if you could reach the correct form by following a link on the site, I wouldn't have any concerns.

Comment: An inbox notification saying, "Congrats on reaching 100K!  We'll be reaching out to you soon for something awesome," would probably make this less sketchy.  Well, it'd at least *pacify*...

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination We've wanted to switch to hosting the forms ourselves quite a few times since I've worked here. We *hate* using Google Forms with a passion but... it's what we're stuck with for now. Last time it was brought up, there was another plan in place that would make having a form obsolete altogether, but I'm not sure that plan is in place anymore. I'll bring it up again. I'd much rather have an inbox notification as Makoto suggests, and have it go directly to an on-site form, cutting out the email completely.

Comment: Seconding what @Makoto says because "you're killing it!" is also highly likely to be misunderstood outside the Anglo world...

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination  ever heard of cryptographic signatures? You send an e-mail with some well-known text encrypted with your private key, then publish your private key on your official website. Anyone who receives that message can then verify its authenticity by using your public key to decrypt that text. If the message is as expected, then you can be sure the sender was legitimate, because only he could encrypt it with his private key to match the public one. There's no way to forge that (as long as the encryption is strong enough).

Comment: @SasQ indeed, but it's not up to me to publish a publickey fingerprint if stackexchange wants to send me an email, they'd need to do so.  Also, i did get my swag :^)