# Is it possible to track the shipment of swag?

Tags: discussion, 10m-questions-milestone

Excited about [10m](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) related swags that I'm about to receive.
Most of the courier or shipment services provides on-line tracking of status of shipment.

It would be nice if we get the details of shipment so that we can track these awesome swag!

Comment: `Most of the courier or shipment services provides on-line tracking of status of shipment.` , then what?

Comment: @AvinashRaj We need a tracking number for that...

Comment: It will be good if they just send a notification when shipped .. like @animuson mentioned... But that FedEx delivery manager is not available in my country

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For bulk swag requests such as the ones needed for the 10m questions milestone, we won't be able to provide tracking information. It's just that the way the process works, the information never makes it anywhere meaningful and trying to get that information out to users is a lot of extra busy work for several different people. However, we generally use FedEx whenever possible (with USPS as our backup), so if you are a member of FedEx Delivery Manager (I don't know what countries this service is available in), you should receive a notification that a package is on its way to your home address with no need for the tracking number.