# What drives you to be active on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I am a team lead at an IT company with 5 years of experience.

Recently, me and my team have reached a maturity level where we all realize that we do not give back enough to the community. We are starting to make contributions (issues, pull requests, improvements) to open source projects or libraries that we use.

We (like most developers I guess) have gained huge benefits on the awesome community on Stack Overflow. But now, it's time to give back.

My questions are:

- What drives you to be active and not passive on Stack Overflow?
- How would you motivate/organize your team so that they would have the same drive?

I was thinking about organizing maybe workshops after work hours on certain days and stay as a team and answer questions. Or maybe see it as a constructive competition of who gathers the most points.

Comment: It is not that I don't like the question but at best we get a collection of answers similar to the [142 answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you?rq=1). Not sure how useful that would be.

Comment: I suspect that a *"constructive competition of who gathers most points"* would lead to actively *unhelpful* behaviour, answering low-quality questions quickly.

Comment: Maybe [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=intrinsic+motivation) has useful answers.

Comment: @rene apart from those 142 answers, I am hoping to get some concrete answers on how would one motivate their team to be active on Stack Overflow, not just general motivation advises. I hope that someone else achieved this with success and is willing to share the solution that worked

Comment: Nothing drives me, its a nice passing of time to take a break from work.

Comment: the constant flow of garbage questions/answers that need to be downvoted

Comment: One place I worked that consistently got folks to do volunteer work offered a separate bucket of PTO just for volunteer activities. Moshe's suggestion of allowing a block of time during the day should be equivalent for something like this.

Comment: Why would you want to get employees to use SO? i don't quite get it. I mean, some people like helping others, some don't. you can't really force that. and you certainly don't want to encourage them to come here and answer garbage questions/dupes just for points,

Comment: Because most of them want to do it, but they do not have an organized structure in which to do it and don't find the time to do it. And if you're thinking that "if they truly want it, they will do it on their own", from my experience I can state that it sounds good, but usually doesn't work. Most of the times people just need a nudge to get remarkable results.

Comment: Being bored at work motivates me to be active on Stack Overflow. Im not sure if you want to encourage that with your team.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Honestly, I live for the moments where a user comes here for help, makes it clear that they tried everything they could to solve it, writes a well thought out question, and I'm able to give them that "aha!" moment.

When I first started here, I had experienced developers giving me "aha" moments regularly, and I was driven to getting to the point where I could do the same for others and return the favour.

This site was instrumental in me learning what I know. Volunteering my time is the least I can do.

I can't answer the second part though, as I've never been active on here as a team member.

Answer (score 5):

> - What drives you to be active and not passive on Stack Overflow?

The growth opportunities.

I've used Stack Overflow to learn and teach for about as long as I've been developing for iOS. My motivations have evolved over time, but they went something like this:

1. This is new and pretty cool.
2. This is new and pretty cool and I can learn things by asking questions.
3. This isn't new anymore, but it's still pretty cool and I can learn things by asking ***and*** answering questions.

It's gratifying when I'm able to thoroughly and accurately answer a question about a technology that's relatively new to me. The badges and the points don't hurt either. :)

> - How would you motivate/organize your team so that they would have the same drive?

The way to make someone want to do something is to help them see the value in it. That of course depends on why you value that thing. If your value is "giving back," then you want to convince your team that answering questions on Stack Overflow is a good way to give back.

I don't know if I like the idea of an organized workshop *as a time for answering questions.* I'd think a specific block of time (45 minutes daily or weekly) for people to answer questions on their own would be a less pressurized way for individuals to contribute.

Another way to motivate your team may be to take advantage of the badging system for some motivation. I'm not sure how I feel about public awards, but depending on your team dynamic, you might let the team know when someone earns a gold or silver badge in a particular technology.

Answer (score 5):

I am very new to this developer community but during my computer science engineering days, I went through hurdles to finish my project. Only one thing made me go nuts is that moment when you gave all your breath to that one problem and just google for the answer and voila you hit the right Stack Overflow post with some random person posting the solution!

Now, I am currently working as a front-end developer and I feel I must help somebody as the law of karma says, what you give is what you get.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Stack Overflow for some time now. But just recently I understood that there are questions that I can also answer even though it may be a simple edit in an existing answer or a comment to improve an existing answer. While looking for answers I am now trying to share my knowledge and I am really enjoying it. Thank you community.

So the most important thing that drives me to come to Stack Overflow is to find answers when I am stuck with errors when coding. But now I also come to see if there are any questions that I can answer to help others. I am still learning so maybe there is not much that I can do at the moment. But I will try my best to help the community.

Comment: Ok. But your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60201890/11102282) it's just the same as other almost one year old answer with 17 positive net votes.

Comment: Well, I was actually doing some research on a method I found, and now I added more to my previous answer. Please check it and also if there is anything wrong please correct me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting that one answer amongst several was 'accepted' - I can't believe it covers everyone's motivation.

Mine was to find something interesting to do during pandemic-enforced lockdowns that at least had the potential to be slightly more useful and varied than doing crosswords. And feedback from people that they found an answer useful is definitely motivating (more so than the rather artificial points system).

And I still marvel at the international aspect - post your question as you go to bed and someone the other side of the world can answer it as you sleep.

Comment: Only one person has the ability to accept, an answer being accepted doesn't indicate everyone agrees with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is great satisfaction in giving back to a community and in knowing you helped someone. This is often complimented with some positive score, which although meaningless makes you feel good when you see positive numbers, and feel bad when you see negative numbers (for most people at least).

Where that satisfaction comes from is probably evolutionary to a degree, if you help your community you are less likely to be ostracised. Historically you needed a community to survive so your brain releases some feel good chemicals for being altruistic.I would guess the upvote downvote is also related to this, you have a live indicator of the communities opinion on your post/answer comment etc.

What drove me to start helping where I can is wanting to give back to the community when people went out of their way to help me for selfless reasons, I wanted to help back. Then the satisfaction of helping is what keeps me looking for ways to help

Answer (score -4):

100% honesty? I'm trying to get to 15 freaking reputation points so I can thank brilliant answers with an upvote! I've been hovering at 13 for a while.

**searches for shameless plug music**

Soon I'll be at the point where I can find a question asked that I can answer that someone else hasn't already.

Comment: talk about pity votes

Comment: It's perfectly okay to add another answer. As long as it adds something not said already – and ideally it must still answer the original question, not just "building upon" existing answers.

Comment: Pity downvotes. Everything I said in that message was honest. But at any rate, I'm able to be more active in the community