# Request for reopening the room "Android Era with Kotlin and Java"

Tags: discussion, support, chat

It's been a rough time for our chatroom for the last few weeks. We tried our best to stop it, but at the end it was not sufficient to keep the room alive.

But after discussing with [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) and my fellow ROs, we came up with some ideas which we want to implement.

First thing first: we will make the room gallery so that we will always have control over users and we can revoke access at any given time if a user is  causing problems.

Second thing, we have a listed of some users who have are responsible of most of these problems. We'll keep them banned forever so that they can cause no further trouble..

It's not like what we went through this the first time. Once our room got frozen because there were more non-English speaking users than English-speaking ones.  But we managed to restrict users to stop using other languages but English.

We just want one chance, and I am sure this time again it'll work out.

Please support!!

Comment: *We just want one chance* ... you want yet another chance ... right?

Comment: @rene Yes, because it'll work like before.

Comment: What might help is if you'd link to that discussion you had with Jon. The room was locked merely 2 hours ago. We'd love to see what you guys came up with to prevent that from happening again.

Comment: i believe access of people who found guilty should be taken instead of shutting down a "living" room

Comment: @Killer: It's the responsibility of the __room owners__ to keep the room clean. If the room owners _can't_ or _won't_ do that, the room is subject to closure. Apparently, that was the case. A chat room _never_ gets closed just because of one or two users.

Comment: i don't know what discussion with Jon and other mods who visited past week took place with RO's. But i am sure they didn't reveal the name of culprits

Comment: @cerbrus I asked the ROs to raise their case here... What I said to them was in a private chat.

Comment: @JonClements: Ah, fair enough. I got the impression the plan was in the chat, my bad :-)

Comment: I want to see a clear case of room moderation going on and plans to do so in future.

Comment: The room stays frozen until then. Provide an action plan and some guarantees I'll lift it.

Comment: @JonClements Whatever action plane we planned, I already mentioned. Let me know what else you want to know ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto please provide it as a collaborative answer from you and the rest of the RO team...

Comment: @JonClements Yes, this is from all RO's of "Android Era with Kotlin and Java". Making room Gallery will help us banning toxic users from the chat. Personally, due to some circumstances, I was not able to come online much from few weeks, but I will be active from now on. Strict actions will be taken for guilty users, and we will keep the chat clean.

Comment: Frankly, you're going to have to do a *lot* to convince me that this room should be reopened. In the last two weeks, we had to act on a user there who was posting disgusting racist and homophobic slurs, as well as multiple users posting pornographic content. As described in [this transcript](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6373430#6373430), I almost deleted your chatroom on the first incident, because not only were many of these slurs not flagged, it seemed like members of this room were encouraging this behavior. The porn posts came after that.

Comment: @BradLarson: What prevents these folks from simply starting a new chat room, perhaps called "Kotlin?"  What prevents the bad actors from re-appearing again?  Is this a systemic problem of chat?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - We can ban the problem users from chat (as was done, and we also deleted sock puppets that were then created to evade these bans), but the larger problem was that the room was seemingly fostering this behavior by not moderating it themselves. When I find that slurs were sitting there unflagged for months, and see other members seemingly supporting this behavior, I begin to question the culture of the room.

Comment: @BradLarson This is not our culture in the room. We always try our best to help the users with their queries (which is the very first purpose of the room). I agree we got lenient on some users, which we want to fix. Also some ROs (including me) were busy on their schedule, so were not able to be here most of the time. But we want to fix that by adding more active and strong ROs. This room is there for many years, and many people come there with their queries. We don't want to lose it, and we will do our very best to prevent such issues in future.

Comment: if RO do not have better ideas to make this up and why not MOD came out with ideas and tell RO to follow them, is not it makes them to break any rule ? nope i do not think so. JUST give us a one more chance. this time we  will not able to make our room clean feel free to talk to RO and take action. - i m not RO. i was on this room from last two yeas. it really hurts, SE runs with community and community always gives one more chance :D

Comment: @AshuKumar: Blindly re-opening the room with empty promises of _"we'll be good this time"_? That's not going to happen. _"community always gives one more chance"_ You forget that they've had their second chance already. The room was locked before.

Comment: you are right, i know no body can gonna do open closed room, what i just want to please discuss with RO and tell them what else they should do to prevent  future problem. RO came with ideas if their ideas are nor good at all or need some improvement than why not u guys help RO, Just talk with RO and improvement their work,  this is how community WORK. leaving someone in the middle of sea when they found their guilty will not gonna make SE good at all

Comment: This is true , sometimes persons have to behave well in all the cases. If there is no peace , room should be closed. I respect all the mods for this.

Comment: @JonClements Would you please let me know what else do you want us to do ? Whatever you told we did. Just tell us your decision. ^^

Comment: @JonClements it would be cool to get a decision, no matter in which direction. I just want to know in which direction I have to concentrate ;)

Comment: hey MOD, Please tell us ur decision. it will be good to move ahead. Hope room will open soon :D :)

Comment: @rekire no decision as yet - best to let a bit more time pass, certain things fade from memory, see how things in a less hectic situation evolve, then go from there...

Comment: @JonClements: I don't really see what _<X amount of time>_ is going to change about this issue...?

Comment: I would guess that this is to check the motivation of the ROs. How long we are still interested in reopening *our* room. I could also imagine to let the *toxic guys* forget the interest in our room. Trolls would just move on, well most I guess.

Comment: i think, 11 days are enough to gather info and analysis facts, can mod please tell us when they are going to give their decision. it will be good to tell their decision  in simple words, if they still want more info from RO, please talk with RO and came out with final words. Eagerly waiting for decision.  Thanks  :)

Comment: hey is there any news ?

Comment: @JonClements last ping from me: Any news? :-)

Comment: hey mod can u please let us know ur final words ? We all members of room are waiting since first day. come out ur decision. and Reactivate our room :D

Comment: hey @JonClements Morning, can u please come with your decision, it will be good to know what you came with our room. It will help us to take further steps, its been 25 days and still we are waiting to know ur decision.  thanks :)

Comment: @JonClements I was also one of the Room Owners. I could see that it has been a good amount of time since the room was frozen, but we still want that. Could you please breath live into that dying horse again? We will take utmost care to keep it clean.

Comment: Relevant: The machine learning room, of which a significant number of ROs  were also RO in this room, was [locked for a similar reason.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358818/should-a-reason-be-specified-when-closing-freezing-a-room#comment528702_358818)

Comment: @AshuKumar It's pretty obvious at this point that the room will not be unfrozen. It's time to move on.

Comment: @meagar - JonClements And it's pretty obvious **too** that you (*Moderators & SO*) will lose some users because of this decision as you know...But, the real question is: **Do you really care?**

Comment: @Mohsen Stack Overflow doesn't need or want that kind of content, and if those users can't contribute constructively, we can't have them either.

Comment: @meagar Of course, We don't need those contents & users either. But, Making a decision like the one which Jon did, Deserved a second chance by giving us (moderators) an another one. I personally spent too much time for it and now, I feel something is wrong here without that chatroom. We also, Gave you guys a solution but you really never cared how much time we spend or what the hell we've done not just for our learning stuff or etc also, For users which we served SO actually so, We expect some more than a normal user...

Comment: @meagar that sounds very generous. TBH you almost lost me as user as a result of my frustration (in fact I forgot already this question Mohsen informed me). I was more then 1k days consecutive online. Over the last 3 years I was in the top ten of winterbash now I have probably not a single hat. BTW I'm not interested in the room anymore I gave up.

Answer (score 36):

Let me offer some well meant advice. Some of the regulars sought refuge in a room on MSE where I happen to be a Room Owner; I share some observations but I admit I'm also biased because my attempt to steer that crowd a bit didn't land, at least not how I imagined.

It takes two to tango. It is an understandable response to be defensive when you feel how you are treated is not justified. However, it really helps, as a group and as individuals, if you become more self-reflective. That is, try to envision how you, as a person, contributed to the issues the room is facing.

Based on my limited interaction with some of the regulars I find it hard to decipher if they are genuinely trying to make the best out of the room or just don't care about the (or any) room or its rules at all. That might lead to all kind of misinterpretations, speculation and jokes lost in translation. Keep in mind that it is difficult to communicate, that requires a common language, sensitivity, an open mind, the will to really listen and trying to understand what the other party's message is. Yes, also from me. And that is hard to stick to, especially when things get heated.

There is a common misconception that chat rooms on the SE network are a safe harbor and exempt from any rules except the ones embraced by its regulars. Again, I'm not 100% sure if that idea lived among your regulars but based on some messages in the transcripts it is possible that outsiders interpreted it this way. The regulars have to decide what they want their room to be. If the outcome is: *anything should be allowed* then reconsider if running this room on SE servers and within the SE policies ("be nice") is the right thing to do.

As a group embrace [Toward a philosophy of Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat) and live up that. Make sure to leverage all options in [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat), keeping in mind that those options are not limited to the RO's. Everyone can moderate, given that everyone is open for being moderated.

Make sure you have a set of rules that are clear and enforceable. We had rules in SOCVR that were impossible to explain, impossible to verify, and therefore impossible to act on and if you did you were probably screwed as an RO. Rules needs to be changed/tuned/removed/updated over time and regularly. Have an insane set of rules so it becomes easy to refer to that instead relying on users' selective and failing memory.

Be open and transparent about how and when you moderate to enforce your rules. Explain why you take or refuse to take actions. That has value for everyone involved to better understand the reasoning behind certain measures. One important thing I learned over time is the SOCVR's *agree to disagree* rule. You can't possibly keep everyone happy all the time. But at least being clear about things you disagree on makes sure no one should feel left out or disrespected.

#### Finally

I'm by no means a model room owner or pretend to perfectly understand (room)culture and all the social and inter personal dynamics that are at play here. Nor do I fully grasp SE policy and mod policies and I certainly miss context. Nor do I pretend to tell you how y'll should live your online life or how to behave in and run your room. I'm just offering my biased observations, well meant but probably useless advice and maybe some food for thought.

I said this before in some room:

> There is a thin line somewhere, stay at the right side.

Go paint that line. Together. Have fun.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. in total I agree with out especially the point with the happiness, we need to make a cut for a better together. Regarding rules we need to keep them as simple as possible and we need to be agile to change them if required. We also need to make it to our philosophy, that everyone can moderate if you are a RO or not.

Comment: `Have an insane set of rules...` Did you really mean "insanely good?"  I'm not sure I agree with a policy of constantly changing the rules.  Chatrooms are not rocket science; some common sense (coupled with a degree of flexibility and fairness) really ought to be enough.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, I didn't mean insanely good, the choice of the word *insane* is correct IMO. I feel we have a lot of rules that I would call *common sense* or *covered by the be nice policy* while we still list them in our FAQ and they are stable but not cast in stone. But in practice we do what you suggest. Maybe not rocket science, but I find it hard to write down a good policy. The *insane* rules are also a [running joke](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39569301#39569301) ... after all you need to have some fun in your free time ...

Answer (score 4):

#### Here's another "Keep it closed" vote.

Aside from the issues / concerns raised in [Zoe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357790/1835379) and [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357755/1835379)'s answers, I have another concern:

The room owners of that room *don't learn* from a moderator's intervention.
Sure, they may behave for a couple of weeks, but so far, there has been no indication they even *understand* what the problem is, much less what they intend to do about it (and how).

In fact, they already [created a new room to replace the locked one.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/156902/android-kotlin-era)
They even explicitly state the intent to re-create the room in case it stays locked:

> I do think the same they are not going to open that again
> but at least they should tell us
> **so that we can create another room**
> <sub>([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39650162#39650162)) (Emphasis mine)</sub>

That's basically ban evasion...
**At time of writing**, 2/3 of the ROs in that new room are RO in the old one.

---

Furthermore, as you can see I've been quite active in here trying to point them in the right direction. Time and time again have I suggested ways to improve, but they actively refuse to take advice.

Comment: Dude that room hasn't created by any ROs but a regular user. The problem with you is you just bring up proofs which is completely not related. For example in earlier comments you had told about giving us a third chance while it's just second time. I can list down your all false proofs.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto: 2 out of 3 ROs in that new room are RO in the locked room...

Comment: Again consider doing a good RnD

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Be so fair to quote not those parts which are just supporting your view: *"really a new room? I would wait for a reply :/"* and the answer *"well its temporary"*. This room was no replacement and is in fact not in use anyway.

Comment: @rekire: If I'd get my account banned here, I would get in trouble for creating a "temporary" account. How is the room different?

Comment: @Cerbrus Read this: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39650145#39650145

Comment: @Cerbrus I was pointing out that already with *"I'm not sure if this temporally room is a good idea"*. However the usage of that room died shortly after my message, so this is no topic.

Comment: In the interest of full transparency, I still think this is a relevant "chain of events". Also, @rekire, stop editing my answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus that room is started by me and surely not started by any of the room owner and has got nothing to do with the room we are talking about in this question

Comment: _"and has got nothing to do with the room we are talking about in this question"_. Sure. It just happens to have a similar name, users, and the subject in there is the closed room...

Comment: @Cerbrus similar != same also your assumption doesn't make it real , the fact remains i started the room and not the RO's of that room , also looks i should rename to something else to avoid confusion

Comment: A cat named "dog" is still a cat. Renaming it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Cerbrus so if I would join a room related to Apple Development and I will become randomly RO this would be the same for you right? I guess your answer will be yes, that is ridiculous.

Comment: Eh, no, that's not what I'm saying. If you'd then change the _subject_ of that room to Android / Kotlin, then yes, that'd be the same. Note that a room's "subject' and "title" aren't the same thing.

Comment: conveniently ignoring the facts i see, not gonna debate anymore will just say it once its my room and please my room out of this discussion

Comment: @Cerbrus StackOverflow is a **free** and a managed Community **by people** who tries to teach & learn the programming languages and etc. I’m not agree with the part which you said we should get permission to create a chatroom or etc. Also, What’s your problem with that room? Do you know how much time we spent to keep it alive? Another point: The new created room is not the same and people are free to create rooms.

Comment: ^ Case in point about deflecting. I don't have a personal problem with the room, but as I stated before, it's basically ban evasion. Time spent keeping it alive? More like time spent _not moderating_. Not the same? I've already answered that a few times.

Comment: Well, There are always solutions. Like i said, We could make the room (gallery). This will help, I personally promiss will moderate the room if this solves your problem..

Comment: when i will be free, i will give good answer of ur points those u mentioned in your answer. @Cerbrus

Comment: I'm still awaiting an answer, @AshuKumar.

Comment: i was busy with work & forgot this. Here u go `In fact, they already created a new room to replace the locked one.`=>  Please check who created room if u r able to. `I do think the same they are not going to open that again` => RO Wrote on of the point, It is one of main thought(s). if u considered this as point than u might not be ever say u can not do that work & suddenly u r able to or did that work. `At time of writing, 2/3 of the ROs in that new room are RO in the old one.` => Please copy and paste all message FROM THAT ROOM WHICH IS SAID BY RO NOT JUST PIECE OF STATEMENT OF WHOLE CHAT

Comment: there are more answers for your points but i m not going to start again. Lets wait for mod reply :)

Comment: ... That's barely even English. Sorry, but I really can't make heads or tails of that comment.

Answer (score -18):

We really want to keep the room alive. For that reason, we will do whatever we can. We have been managing this chat room for a long time, and we have a good team who is always ready to help. This chat-room influenced lots of users for more than three years. Based on a few weeks analysis, please don't shut down this chat-room! Our room has existed since 2012-11-06 with altogether 2969 visitors.

What we have planned to do:

1. We will focus more on moderating chat by letting a window with chat be open on a second screen when we are on a computer. So we will see faster what is going on. E.g. rekire mostly reacted on pings, however in critical moments no pings were raised. So we need to sensibilise *our* users to inform us so that we can kick those users faster. Flagging should be done too. We see that handling that ourselves didn't work well.
2. Like we already mentioned in the question, the very first thing we
   will do is to make room gallery so that we can restrict unwanted
   users to post anything in chat.
3. Also we will try to keep the chat flow mostly on-topic. Cat content and context-less memes are at least temporally forbidden. Casual chats are fine as long as everyone follows the rule *be nice*. Homophobic and sexual content won't be tolerated and continuously flagged and the user will be kicked. As we all know the first strike won't take long, but it should be enough to raise the attention of the corresponding user.
   That we will also take care of.
4. We will always use timeouts to make clear statements if something goes out of our hand. Since we have already some focus by our moderating team we will be able to use future steps.

**We are hoping that will make our room great again. Yes, we can!**

Just some stats to see that there is not everything bad, here are some statistics for some interesting keywords:

- thank 1844
- thanks 7336
- good morning 7615
- gm 5152
- welcome 1850
- Links to answers or questions 9569

You can use the search to confirm these statistics. That means that every visitor on average said "thank you" 3.3 times. You should think about it.

Comment: 1 & 3: how? 4: What else can you do _before_ using mod flags? I think you can improve your plan by updating this answer a bit.

Comment: for 1 : we can make RO to those who are most active, fair and experienced at the same time. + different time zones so that people who are guilty can be identified and access should be taken immediately ps i am just a regular member no RO

Comment: @Cerbrus for 3, by restricting users from off-topic chat, especially when people are discussing on-topic things. We already prevented bot spams before, especially when users are having on-topic discussions.

Comment: for 3: we can put some restriction by setting up rules and regulation for the group so that the same situation we have today could not arise again. ps they are my sole reviews i hope RO's will figure out something better

Comment: for 4 only RO's can answer that i am sure there will be a solution to it. I request RO's @jon, you and other mods to contribute to positively to counteract with the problems.

Comment: The key point here is "1" - you haven't in the past - and that remains my concern. It's frustrating that someone has to point out to you that it's necessary to do so... (and not just once)

Comment: @JonClements I know its unfortunate. But we gonna fix it. We have some things in our mind regarding moderation.

1. Adding more active users as ROs and removing inactive ones.
2. Maintaining coordination between ROs by notifying each other about unusual activities.
3. Taking strict action against toxic users by revoking their access from the room (since we gonna make the room Gallery).
4. In case we face some issue, we will discuss on it together and take measures to prevent it.

Comment: I have a question about point 2.  Was it room regulars that were causing the problem or new people?  If it is regulars then that is a culture problem gallery mod doesn't really fix that (except you can perma-ban someone).  If the culture needs to be fixed you need strong RO's that will speak up when the line is crossed and not afraid to kick people to reinforce the point that bad behavior is not tolerated.

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree. And I admit we went wrong there by being lenient to some users and not taking necessary action. And this is what we want too fix. Few ROs (including me) were a bit busy on their schedule from few weeks, but we will make sure to have active and strong ROs.

Comment: @JonClements I extended the first action point to cover some more things. I don't like blaming, but in 2 I had to. Since I got some *feedback* from him which opened my eyes.

Comment: I have been in the chatroom since may, I have been there every single day (with few exceptions). What I saw in the time I was there was a lot of poor/non-existent moderating. What you got now is basically promises of a better future you can't keep. Now putting it in gallery mode may help you moderate it better, but that assumes you (the ROs) actually moderate the content. As already mentioned, I have been in that room for hours and before and while I was a RO, few of the other RO made any continuous efforts to moderate content. And a lot of the ROs weren't even there - at all.

Comment: @rekire you can mention this too https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/304059/2437655
This might be TLN's sama story so is mine and hope for many other.  To add to this it's the top voted answer on a popular question.

Comment: Those stats that were added are fine, but meaningless in the context of moderating a chat room. How old a room is and how many visitors it got is completely _irrelevant_. The other counts at the bottom of the answer say nothing about the context of those words. What matters here is how you guys plan to ___moderate___ the room. Padding this answer with stats to make the room “look good” really won’t have the effect you may want it to have.

Comment: In my 15-odd years of participating in online forums and chat rooms, this is the first time someone has tried to provide those stats to justify their chat room not being so cancerous. "Look, we greet and thank each other all the time, that means our room is well-moderated!" Please, toxic people greet and thank each other all the time too.

Comment: RO will come up with better idea to maintain clean chat room and focus on on Topic conversation. before came up with decision you guys must considered past thing that our room did help many people and answer questions and my self and other RO did help. can not you come up with other idea which will make ROOM to be open? is not it possible ?

Comment: the bad room management has been going on for a long time, it isn't something you can just turn over with the same base of ROs. They can try but it will inevitably fail. While they say they'll turn things around, the chances are very low for them to actually do it. They haven't in the past and they only think they need to change when the room is frozen? the room was frozen in the first place with good reason, the ROs can't moderate it. And if they can't now, why would they be able to in the future?

Comment: For myself I identified that I was less active just caused by the gifs. So they are the root of all evil out of my personal view. @AshuKumar the gallery is just temporally. It does not match to the idea of this chat room

Comment: @BoltClock if status are not considered as answer than why stats are considered as opportunity and achievement. our room performed well when room started since few weeks room had problem. i m agree MOD. it must do correct and RO must do something. closing ROOM is not going to anywhere. if mode need more reliable idea  to make our room open, please talk wiith RO and if conversation does not end with any solution than MOD do what is necessary to make things good on SE.

Comment: reopening the room would once again make the room susceptible to the same things that got it closed in the first place. If they manage to fix that during the first weeks of the room, there's no guarantee they'll keep the moderation efforts up

Comment: like this gov. should give up and country must run my peoples ? is this u r saying. if someone did mistake and realize what is wrong they must get chance to correct their past deed. and who is in this world do not making mistake again ?  even bots also do

Comment: They have already had a second chance; it's happened before. Why should they get a third chance for basically poor moderation? They didn't fix it last time, what makes you think now will be different? Things repeat themselves because things like this rarely change

Comment: _"Everybody deserves a second chance."_ Yes, (almost) everybody does. However, to be given a ___third___ chance, isn't that common. Since the room has _already_ shown to be unable to keep made promises and the room has already shown to be unable to moderate itself. This is why promises like _"we'll be better"_ aren't enough. This is why they want a ___plan___. Excuses like _"bots make mistakes"_ and _"we've been thanked a lot"_ only weaken your plan.

Comment: @Cerbrus yup, from my very first comment, i m saying yes we need  plan, a better plan to show MOD and  if they are agree then ROOM will open again. and i m dead sure RO will come up with better plan and talk with MOD to get this room up.

Comment: @Cerbrus well done! You did good job so far. Now do you mind letting mod decide ?

Comment: @Cerbrus  and zoe which ***third*** chance? When did we get the **second** chance??? Out of my view you both are trolling here. Still not sure why. However if and even **if** we get a second change I would ask to open the room **not before monday**.

Comment: @Zoe yup u r right. but saying `Why should they get a third chance for basically poor moderation` will not solve problem. and this problem is not limit to this room may be other room also faced this kind of problem - though i m not sure. there always a way to make thing correct. why not look for that path to make this room and make `Record` for other rooms owners

Comment: @JonClements Please correct me, but I see it like you might give us a chance if we have a plan and to make us more aware that we need to improve our work as RO. Can you confirm this theory?

Comment: @rekire: [The room has been frozen before](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/19132?m=17605955#17605955). Calling me a troll means you're clearly missing the point of my messages. I'm trying to explain _why_ this answer isn't enough. I'm trying to make you guys understand what's wrong. But if you don't want my help, that's fine. Just don't call me a troll, that's silly.

Comment: @Cerbrus I would guess that there way no timeout at the time. Just a way to get attention. That were just 3 minutes. That does not *count* as a chance! However other languages where never a topic again. So we did our job.

Comment: Did you miss how Shog warned the room to stick to English, or be deleted?

Comment: The english language is no topic anymore!

Comment: @Cerbrus langauge is not problem here. why not u ask MOD before sayng anything on comment ? i do not think u know why room is frozen :( stop making us down.  i m not getting why MOD not giving comment on this.

Comment: My point is that this room has had issues before, regardless of _what_ those were, calling on the _"Everyone deserves a second chance"_ sentiment isn't going to help you.

Comment: I agree with Cerbrus, especially when you failed on moderation once before. Not keeping the language in english was poor moderation on your end. Now is a different top-level problem but it all has a root in poor moderation. @AshuKumar the room has gotten its second chance already, now its frozen again for the essentially same root reason (poor moderation). There has to be huge changes for the room to be reopened, and even then there's the problem of following up on it

Comment: @Cerbrus yup i know, please read my message again, i also wrote, we will come up more and better idea and talk with MOD, while u r saying you can not,  you must not get chance, i do not think  by writing these kind of comment against some one will make you  good member on SE or MOD.

Comment: @Zoe dude, how can u say problem will follow in future u r neither GOD nor predictor, so why not ask RO what are you doing to make this ROOM clean this time ? or ask do u know ur fault or do u really want to make this ROOM open and if yes on which bases. I do not know what MOD are thinking. but MOD will think again.

Comment: @AshuKumar: I'm not saying you can not get another chance.I'm saying that you need to work harder for a third chance.

Comment: that's what i m saying :). yup we will do and RO will surely come with better plan soon.

Comment: @AshuKumar you can predict the most likely future based on the past. Based on the past and now a second freeze as a result of bad moderation you can predict that the same trend will continue. Right now the ROs are fighting desperately to keep it alive and using the most basic arguments like "everyone deserves a second chance" and "that means every user said 'thank you' about 3.3 times".  If the arguments had been better I'd agree the room should be reopened, but now it's a desperate cry for help and not a plan for the future

Comment: @Killer as it is clearly stated by mods , you should have some attention to the mods if anything goes wrong , but you had not. That's your mistake. Actually everyone is blaming on everyone. Mods are right here.

Comment: @Zoe it is my and only my opinion  "everyone deserves a second chance". For this u can say anything to RO, can u please tell me where i wrote in my comment it is RO suggestion ?

Comment: Let me close my discussion here. As I hope RO's can present a full future plan to reopen the room to the mods. And let the mods decide the outcome to make SE a better place. I just wanted to share the incident that occurred last month about Zoe's aka lunar watcher (my bad i didn't react on it at that time) which i already did

Comment: lets close discussion and let the RO and MOD do their work :) and get our ROOM up. :)

Comment: Guys, if anything, this calling out other users shows why the room should remain closed. This answer is supposed to be a plan to ___improve___. You're setting a __very bad example__, here.

Comment: I agree with Cerbrus. There is a lot in the room that is worth preserving, but the plan is terrible. Blaming it on others (users/bots) isn't a good idea. And @Killer stop blaming people. Saying "it's not our fault, it's [insert person/thing here]" isn't going to save the room. So far me, hans, chew, tcat, ashu, bots and gifs have been blamed for all the stuff that's been going on in the room. [rekire wrote this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6405844#6405844) in chat and it is the same in point 2 where instead of saying "we have a problem to fix" ... (1/3)

Comment: you blame it on users and things instead of trying to fix it. Sure, there's been kicks and room freezes in the past but they haven't been coordinated. The moderation efforts are sparse and most importantly inconsistent. And as Cerbrus said, the current plan blames a set of users and things instead of trying to improve what currently goes wrong in the room. ANd @Killer I'm not blaming that on poor moderation, that was a crappy decision on my end. But no one did anything to moderate that, and there were others who did the same (don't pin the blame for that on me alone. (2/3)

Comment: TheLittleNaruto was in fact the first one to post those types of links in that format. At this point what all of the AE guys have to realize is that there's no point in continuously digging up the past. If you look deep enough you'll find that mostly everyone has posted something they shouldn't have at some point. But instead of saying "it's all his/her fault for the freeze happening" focus on the moderation that's going to happen in the future. Make sure this stuff doesn't happen again. That is what your plan is lacking

Comment: I'm getting really sick when I see what you write here. tbh if you quote me you should also quote me when I'm saying what my faults are too: [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1144?m=6409444#6409444). And my most importent thing I wrote: *"In the end I still blame the gifs since that was the reason why I didn't kept the chat in a open window on a second screen. Since I was not interested in getting bad attention at my work when shitty blinking gifs where scrolling down continuesly on my screen."* **Yes I made faults**, but just by *allowing gifs*!

Comment: I also made a statistics regarding gifs:
3382 "gif"s
hans 766
OakBot 679
Caprica Six 895
other 1042
I just send **TWO** gifs which says a lot about quality.

Comment: @rekire: The problem isn't gifs. The problem is ___moderation___. The fact that you __insist__ on calling out a single user in a post meant to show us you guys are capable of __being better__ shows that you are not.

Comment: and the gifs stops me from moderation

Comment: As a room owner, you should just move those to a trash room. Those gifs don't stop you from moderating, they are your _responsibility_ to clean up, as room owner.

Comment: I still wonder that instead of suggesting some good things regarding what can be done in future, People are focussing more on keeping the room freezed. If you are spending too much time on thinking and questioning us "what you gonna do in future to moderate such things", why don't you simply make use of that time in suggesting what can be done. Now that's called help, that's called cooperation and that I can't see here from people of SE. They call themselves a team but when it comes to getting their teammates out of a serious damage, they would rather take interest in blaming them.

Comment: @MukeshRana: No, that's not called "help", that's called "spoon-feeding".

Comment: @Cerbrus If you think suggesting/recommending solutions is "spoon-feeding", then you have been doing "spoon-feeding" in all your SO career so far by helping users to gain repo for your personal interest. C'mon man, we are not asking you to moderate the room, that have to do by the RO's in any case but you can at least come up with an idea how that can be done instead of taking interest in questioning about how RO's gonna implement that.

Comment: Simple: Use the kick option to warn users. If you kick them 3 times, a mod will be consulted to deal with the situation automatically. That has never been done while I have been in the room as far as I remember

Comment: @rekire this is meta, a public platform. Whether or not you're interested in Cerb's opinion has little effect.

Comment: @MukeshRana The "focussing more on keeping the room freezed" is because people are utterly inconvinced that you guys are capable of changing. And as is, from what I've read this room gives all of chat.SO a bad name.

Comment: Common guys if one plan not working than why not creating other plan. and show in your answer. @rekire. I know our RO can. And mod will show interest to open room :)