# Should a reason be specified when closing / freezing a room?

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation

**Note:** The primary purpose of this question is the topic mentioned in the 
title. NOT a reopening request! I used this as example because it brought the question up for me. Please remember that when answering, commenting and voting.

Recently the ML room was frozen without any comment as to why that happened. My assumption as room owner who can read deleted messages that could be comments of one user towards another user in the room.

Supporting this assumption is the fact that the user got suspended for 3 days.

What speaks against this assumption are the following points:

1. I never saw any warning. That user has never before been an issue (afaik) and with that has not been warned.
2. If that is the first time he is suspended, why for 3 days?
3. I am a roomOwner in that room as well. I can read the messages, he deleted. I never saw them as offending. Maybe the issue is that you have a different view on that thing. I am very sure that that user is not out to cheat on their spouse with an unknown person from the other side of the world, tbh. Nothing is wrong with teasing people. For me that is normal human behaviour. Or is any fun on this platform now a reason to be suspended?
4. I asked the potentially offended user what their view on the comments by that user are. The response:

> im shocked :) i didn't feel at all offened by any of them :) half of them i didn't even get to see coz  would delete them straight away after posting :) BUT well, if these are the rules.. hmmm

Link to chat (contains names): https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39871034#39871034

While point 4 has not been available to the user who closed the room, he could easily have asked.
Further I asked a 10k regular user if he saw any flags raised. According to him, there were none he saw.

So with the points that speak against the user to be the reason it opposed to the ones speaking for it, it looks like it may not have been the case. With that regulars in the room as well as (maybe even more importantly) the room owners have no real reason as to why the room was closed.

Should manually freezing a room (meaning now through feeds) come with a forced input for a reason?

Rooms are not manually frozen every minute so the little time it would take to write a reason would not take multiple hours a day.

Comment: I didn't seen anything wrong in this room. what is the reason @jon-clements? why you froze this room without leaving any explanation?

Comment: @InsaneCat except that I don't see much Machines Learning there so we can conclude machine learning is a failed experiment, warranting the freezing of the room and now we can move on with our human lives.

Comment: @rene you have a human life?

Comment: @rene it takes a while to build a userbase. Longer than the time the room has been up

Comment: Exactly what Zoe mentioned. Every room with a broad topic takes time to attract enough users to keep up a constant on-topic conversation. And while that time has not come, there should be nothing wrong with keeping a friendly atmosphere alive to present the room as a nice and open community.

Comment: Machine learning is a broad topic, but so is having `Java` or `Python` as a chatroom topic. The difference is that machine learning spans different programming languages, meaning there's a variable there too. You can't have a lot of ML content when there aren't a lot of ML enthusiasts who join.

Comment: I'm not realy surprised. Rooms get shut down all the time with no reason. Thats how the mods work on this site.

Comment: Why couldn't they keep a friendly atmosphere alive *by sharing topic about machine learning*? What Machine Learning has to do with ["It's Friday" song](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39837677#39837677), [finding Android job](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39836325#39836325), [BitCoin mining](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39865341#39865341)? Reading yesterday (today?)'s transcript, I only found Feed (yeah, a bot), **trying hard** to make it on-topic, and nobody responded to that topic.

Comment: Has one to be focused on one single topic only? The Friday song is a meme in a few rooms, a lot of the people in there are as well interested in android, and BitCoin mining stands in connection to CUDA, which is used for machine learning as well. However I am not here to justify the room (which I still feel like I should do anyway) but discuss the topic in the question.

Comment: @AndrewT. honestly I feel embarrassed with what I post but labeling the room as **trying hard** seems offensive, when we have ideas we always start from scratch and do some try and error testing (same way as building the Machine Learning room), if we can only predict the future that ML will become a failure so why bother building the room in the first place? apart from that it will probably save us some time.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 certainly not, but if the main topic (ML) doesn't even take an average of 10% of the whole conversation, then I think there's a problem. But I agree, my comment is off-topic regarding this meta post.

Comment: I think it may have to do with being viewed of a continuation of the Android Era with Kotlin and Java room that was frozen a while ago for toxic behavior.

Comment: @Enzokie I didn't label the room as trying hard. I labeled *the Feed* as trying hard since it's the only "user" that posted about ML in the recent chat. "*if we can only predict the future that ML will become a failure so why bother building the room in the first place*" not sure what you meant. The ML itself, or the chat room? Anyway, as I've mentioned above, my comment is off-topic to this meta post. Disregard this.

Comment: @Magisch the room has been around for longer than since Android Era was closed. It started a while before, it's not a continuation

Comment: If the primary purpose of this question is the topic mentioned in the title why does it contain so much detail about the reasons behind your assumption? Wouldn't it be enough to say 'I assume it is blah but it would be better to have clarity'? Sounds like a thinly vailed soap box to me.

Comment: @Ryanfae Because I wanted to show an example and why I think that a reason should be given. If that is too much, I can throw that stuff out. But I would wait for more people to judge about that if that is fine for you.

Comment: "...half of them i didn't even get to see coz would delete them straight away after posting" -- This is troubling.  This could be a person who is impulsive and doesn't think before posting, or someone who is using deletion as a sort of "just kidding" to try to get away with statements they know are offensive.  In either case the messages were thought to be offensive by the person who posted them.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 of course you can! I'm always aware that it might just be my own pessimistic attitude making me see things in the worst way so by all means leave it as is, just be aware that there might be other people who think the same. Time will tell. :)

Comment: At what point was that room actually about machine learning and not just a stream of shitposts? I don't do much chat moderation, but I keep seeing the same names again, doing the same thing previous rooms have been removed for. As a room owner, what have you done to keep the room on topic and focused?

Comment: To Martijn's comment, the first posts I saw when I looked in on that room were an Islamophobic meme (deleted to avoid moderation) and someone saying "i think holocaust numbers are exxagarated" (again, deleted to hide from moderators). There wasn't a whole lot of actual machine learning discussion in there. Given that it was a list of the same members [of this closed room](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357749/request-for-reopening-the-room-android-era-with-kotlin-and-java#comment522106_357749), not surprised that the room was closed. I'll let Jon elaborate on what he found.

Comment: @Zoe I'm not saying that it's the reason ML was frozen, but the order of creations of the rooms is irrelevant. The same crew that used to hang out in the Android room moved to the ML room, regardless of the room creation dates.

Comment: Wait, why are you worried about invalidating *comments*? The *one* thing on the site which are subject to routine invalidation?  Just edit your post into what shape you need it to be in.

Comment: @Makoto Good point. I am also concerned about the votes. Currently there are 16/11. If I changed it, I doubt anything would really change. Actually I think I will not create a reopening request. The regulars of that room found a new platform. And with that I would invalidate not one or two but around 30 discussing comments. And as said, I think a good amount of the votes comd from the example used and the question seen as reopening request. I will change the top note.

Comment: ... Look. Edit your post so that it's clear what you want to accomplish. It derailed into a discussion about a specific room whereas the original premise was about in general.  If you don't want to discuss it further then save us the hand wringing over it and delete it.  I realize that sounds harsh, but either you're discussing something about one room or *all* rooms.

Comment: I will do that tomorrow. I learned from this but in the app I cannot delete a question, the connection to the site with my phone is super slow and I will not boot my computer for that one single thing. And now excuse me, I gotta take a nap. I will delete it as soon as I get up tomorrow

Answer (score 12):

I wasn't involved in this situation but can provide some insight:

> I never saw any warning. That user has never before been an issue (afaik) and with that has not been warned.

Rooms aren't frozen because of a single user. Chat bans are the action taken against a single user. This freeze wasn't because of a single user.

> If that is the first time he is suspended, why for 3 days?

Because they drew the attention of multiple mods and community managers. Honestly, three days seems lenient for that kind of attention.

> I am a roomOwner in that room as well. I can read the messages, he deleted. I never saw them as offending. Maybe the issue is that you have a different view on that thing. I am very sure that that user is not out to cheat on their spouse with an unknown person from the other side of the world, tbh. Nothing is wrong with teasing people. For me that is normal human behaviour. Or is any fun on this platform now a reason to be suspended?

"Fun" is not a reason to be suspended. Repeated sexual innuendoes and posting and deleting comments so only certain users can read them are two activities that will quickly get you a suspension though. On top of that, at least one room owner encouraged these behaviors in the last few days.

> I asked the potentially offended user what their view on the comments by that user are.

Huh. Must have missed the offended user that flagged then.

> Further I asked a 10k regular user if he saw any flags raised. According to him, there were none he saw.

Mod flags aren't shown to 10k users.

---

I don't know the history of the ML room. I do, however, know the [history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357749/request-for-reopening-the-room-android-era-with-kotlin-and-java) of several of the room owners you are associated with. That kind of history, especially with it being so recent, is not something that is simply forgotten. *You* were involved in some of those discussions barely a month ago.

---

Now, to the heart of your question:

> Should manually freezing a room (meaning now through feeds) come with a forced input for a reason?

Generally, I'd say yes. A moderator would discuss the situation with the room prior to freezing it.

*However*, this is not a general case. *Every* room owner of the ML room was involved in discussions about suspensions, chat tool abuse, and plans to escalate the abuse barely a month ago. [Some room owners did just that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357749/request-for-reopening-the-room-android-era-with-kotlin-and-java#comment522362_357790). The exploits that were being performed by your team caused the Stack Exchange development team to step in and eliminate a feature other room owners had utilized for legitimate reasons.

In short, you already had your discussion. You had your warning. Your team couldn't keep their head down and build a chat community. Your team couldn't keep the room clean for even a month before the users started posting inappropriate messages and were encouraged to do so by the room's leadership.

So, no. You didn't get a second warning.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What feature was removed?

Comment: I assume that would be being able to remove messages by ID as RO by issuing a command in the browser console. @Cerbrus

Comment: That seems like an exploit in the first place.