# Will Stack Overflow celebrate the 20 million questions milestone?

Tags: discussion, questions

Stack Overflow is going to reach 20 million questions in a few days. Will there be any celebrations, like for [10m questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you)?

Comment: They won't be giving anything away. You can celebrate by [helping to review some of those 20 million questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close).

Comment: We have 27,652,028 all-time questions, only ~20m are visible.

Comment: Ideally we're all about quality, not quantity.

Comment: Also, big milestones, in general, are commonly set to increase by a factor of 10 (1m > 10m > 100m, etc.), not by a factor of 2. Otherwise, they're not special anymore.

Comment: If it were 20 million questions with a positive score and at least one positively scored answer..

Comment: @41686d6564 so once you got through the 10 year wedding anniversary then it's all smooth sailing?

Comment: [*19,992,364* questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) as of *2020-08-16T152731Z*. So it is about 24 hours away as I write this.

Comment: @41686d6564: [YouTubers celebrate anything with a single digit different from 0 in the number of subscribers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EShV7kNktZM&lc=UgyAh6NJQDQaGps_hit4AaABAg). And 1/4, 1/2, and 3/4. *100,000*, *200,000*, *250,000*, *300,000*, *400,000*, *500,000*, *600,000*, *700,000*, *750,000*, *800,000*, *900,000*, *1,000,000*, *1,250,000*, *1,500,000*, *1,750,000*, *2,000,000*, etc. subscribers.

Answer (score 5):

The 20 million questions milestone has passed and it looks like no official celebration took place.

5 years ago, the [10 million question mark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey) was a comparatively large event with its own dedicated page at [https://stackoverflow.com/10m](https://web.archive.org/web/20160415145359/https://stackoverflow.com/10m) with a live counter, stories collected and [swag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303988/how-did-stack-overflow-help-you) being sent out. The community received the 10 million questions point quite positively with many upvotes.

Now in 2020 it seems that the mood for celebration is significantly lower than in 2015. It might be that the community management team is busy with other stuff or that the current pandemic plays a role. Or simply the perception is now that the increased quantity of questions on StackOverflow is not accompanied by a corresponding quality. A single number could not accurately reflect the state of StackOverflow anyway without lots of context.

That leads me to:
How much reason to celebrate 20 million question would there be now?

Please let me eleborate a bit.

The data explorer (is slightly behind the actual values) says there are **20,049,784 non-deleted questions** on StackOverflow now. However, there have been **27,708343 questions asked** in total, but 7,683,490 or **slightly more than every fourth question was deleted** (manually and automatically by the [Roomba script](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)) because it was badly received or didn't have answers and not many visitors.

Not all questions on StackOverflow are accepting answers. Currently **19,111,276 questions are not-closed and not-deleted**.

How many of these questions are good questions? A positive score is a sign of a good question. **9,098,446 question are not-closed, not-deleted and have a positive score**.

To be useful, questions also need good answers. **6,708,087 questions are not-closed, not-deleted, have a positive score and at least one positively scoring answer.**

And we still get those. Between 26th of August 2019 to 2020, **341,588 such questions with a positive score and a positively scored answer** were created, that's about 5.1% of all such questions, a bit below average for the total lifetime of the network of about 12 years.

Now, **all the 20 million questions on StackOverflow together have currently 48,463,163,622 visits** (viewcounts), that's roughly 48.5 billion (compare this to 7.5 billion viewcounts in 2015 when there were only 10 million questions). The impact of the existing content on the public has increased a lot in the last years. That is indeed a reason to celebrate!

But not all questions contribute equally to this impact. The **275,700 most visited questions account for nearly half (24.2 billion) visits**. That's only a tiny fraction (~1.4%) of all questions. The 1,979,200 most visit questions account for 80% (38.8 billion) of the visits. The remaining ~18 million questions or ~90% of all questions account for only ~20% of the traffic.

What does it all mean?

Of course no metric is ever perfect, neither the score nor the visits tell you how much quality and quantity and knowledge there really is, but it might be fair to say that there are

- a couple of 100,000s of really good Q&As (more than I could ever read)
- a couple of millions quite good Q&As
- a couple of millions more promising Q&As
- roughly 5-15 million relatively low quality or not very useful Q&As (the long tail)

And this long tail requires a lot of effort to maintain. Finding good content to answer, voting on content, editing and improving content all has become more difficult with more and more questions being asked, especially because the question quality has not increased. The concern is that a large amount of low quality questions may just lower the signal to noise ratio and generally inhibit the creation of a collection high quality Q&A collection by lowering the efficiency. Another recent concern is that the company in the last years may have concentrated more on quantity than on quality and that guidance and expectation management as well as messaging or reviewing tools could be better.

Who is celebrating the **10th or 20th million question that is not being asked** because the user searched thoroughly before and tried lots of things themselves??

Who is celebrating all those reviewers work or the countless edits that improve content or remove bad content (you don't even get rep for it)?

I hope I could convince you that quantity isn't everything and 20 million questions doesn't really say much about the quality and the amount of knowledge that is in these 20 million questions.

But StackOverflow is still up and running in 2020 and there are still useful questions being asked and there were a lot of promising developments from the company lately and there are more visitors than ever using this knowledge library, so with a little bit of optimism, there is also reason to celebrate the [hard and collaborative work of StackOverflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400506/congratulations-for-reaching-a-million-gordon-linoff).